# Синоним метки ms → microsoft

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

По-моему, нужно сделать метку [ms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms) синонимом для [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft).

Чтобы происходило преобразование:

```
ms → microsoft
```

Comment: ms на мой вкус слишком коротко для метки, может, превратить в синоним и удалить?

Comment: @VladD, я, наверно, неудачно написал в вопросе. подразумевалось: заменить все метки ms на метку microsoft, и производить такую замену и дальше автоматически.

Comment: @VladD, по поводу «удалить» я затрудняюсь что-либо сказать: вероятно, не хватает понимания работы меток вообще и синонимов в частности.

Comment: Ну, если я правильно понимаю, синонимы означают что вводите [tag:перевод], получаете [tag:локализация]. Но кажется при этом метка-синоним не удаляется. (Если удаляется, то значит это я неправильно понял работу синонимов.)

Comment: @VladD, Удалять метки не следует, лучше делать синонимы. Иначе удалённую метку обязательно какой-нибудь "добрый человек" добавит вновь

Comment: А для чего вообще нужна мета-метка microsoft?

Comment: @KromStern, а что такое *мета-метка* и чем она отличается от просто *метки*?

Comment: Мета-метка не несет в себе смысла сама по себе. Ее нельзя использовать без других меток. Нет вопросов, которые бы можно было задать в рамках сайта про [микрософт]. Дополнительно: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @KromStern, спасибо. надеюсь, по моему вопросу вы поняли, что я не смогу ответить на вопрос «а для чего вообще нужна мета-метка microsoft». кстати, а microsoft — действительно мета-метка?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: скорее, просто слишком общая метка. Специалисты по "microsoft" невозможны, это абсурд. Поэтому и метка не нужна.

Comment: Сегодня был один вопрос про [tag:ms], 20 про [tag:microsoft]. Объединил их.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пожалуйста, если вы видите неправильную метку, которая используется меньше 10 раз, то просто исправляйте метку, а не пишите на Мету. У вас для этого достаточно репутации. Это гораздо быстрее и эффективнее.

Удалил все метки [ms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms):

- [ms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms) + [access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) → [access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access)
- [ms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms) + [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) → [sql-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)

Самая метка [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) должна быть удалена и заменена на более точные метки (30 использований).

Comment: я пока плохо знаком с механизмом функционирования меток, синонимом, обязательных меток, но подозреваю, что если неправильную метку просто удалить, то ведь её создадут вновь.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Если метка удалена из всех вопросов, она сама тоже будет удалена (происходит раз в сутки, вроде). Для пересоздания метки нужна репутация. Пока в бете, порог довольно низкий. Бороться с этим бесполезно. Проблема не в метках, которые используются меньше 10 раз, а в популярных неправильных метках — вот с ними надо активно воевать, потому что выход из беты от них не спасёт.

Comment: понял. тогда, может быть, данный `feature-request`, вероятно, надо как-то «отклонить»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Системную метку "status-*" могут поставить только модераторы (вроде, с расстановкой этих меток не очень-то заморачиваются). У вас, как у автора вопроса, есть выбор только среди плюс-минус-принять.

Comment: удалил существенную часть [microsoft]ов