# Как помочь участнику использовать конкретные метки вместо обобщенных

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

**Проблема:**
Участники RU.SO продолжают использовать обобщенные метки и вместо них не используют конкретные и осмысленные.

1. Метки о проблеме: [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0),  [проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0)
2. О программировании: [скрипт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82), [код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4), [программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), [программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b), [api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api), [переменные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5), [язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba), [текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82),  [настройка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0)
3. О веб-разработке: [сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82), [интернет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82), [web-разработка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0)
4. Об обобщщенных компаниях вместо конкретных разработанных ими продуктов: [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google), [yandex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex), [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81), [вконтакте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5), [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft)

Почти эти метки имеют краткое описание с пометкой «НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ». Похоже, не все пользователи его читают.

**Как помочь пользователям сразу выбрать нужные конкретные метки?**

Связанные вопросы:

[Ритуал массового сожжения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320/181472)
[Синоним метки ms → microsoft](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/588/181472)

Comment: Более того, модераторы сразу потрут такую метку. Отличное предолжение

Comment: @ixSci если пользователь настолько упорный, что опубликует с этой меткой, то потрут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя городить костыли только из-за того, что на сайте накопился мусор. Вместо того, чтобы разводить зоопарк синонимов и **делать ещё хуже**, надо взять и вычистить все неправильные метки. Все эти "интернеты" и "программирования" давно следовало уничтожить и больше никогда про них не вспоминать.

После вычистки необходимо добавить эти метки в страшный и ужасный **Чёрный Список Меток**, тогда даже пользователи с высокой репутацией не смогут их пересоздать. **Инструмент уже существует**, он эффективен. Давайте им пользоваться, а не засорять метки очередным слоем мусора, чтобы прикрыть старый слой.

Хватит ссылаться на лень. Отредактировать метки в нескольких сотнях вопросов — это посильная для любого задача. Это говорю я, у кого счётчик исправлений давно четырёхзначный. Надо выбрасывать мусор, а не запихивать его под ковёр.

Немного усложняет задачу, что сайт сейчас в стадии беты, поэтому метки может добавлять кто угодно. Но это временная проблема.

---

А теперь, почему **категорически нельзя** это делать. Если переименовывать с заменой, как могут модераторы, то **уничтожится полезная информация**. Если переименовывать без замены, то движок будет **при любой правке** менять метки на синонимы, и снова **уничтожится полезная информация**.

Этот костыль значительно усложнит правильную вычистку мусора. Исправляя метки, мне придётся лезть в историю правок, чтобы убедиться, что из-за костыля не пропали какие-то важные метки, которые надо заменить на корректные. Исправление меток, котороё занимает десяток секунд, это превратит в минутный квест.

И если кому-то просто хочется избавиться от неправильных меток, то мне хочется, чтобы вместо неправильных были правильные. Тег "google" должен быть не удалён, он должен быть заменён на "google-*-api".

Поэтому — **категорическое нет**.

Comment: Ок, я поддерживаю черный список.

Comment: Решение приняли давно, теперь непонятно, как запустить его в действие.

Comment: Не согласен с тем, что [tag:интернет] следует удалить. Во всяком случае, не согласен с таким обоснованием. Вполне себе легитимная тема для вопроса, скажем, про косяки в таблице маршрутизации у какого-нибудь трансконтинентального оператора связи.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Для этого есть тег "маршрутизация".

Comment: Ыы… я был уверен, что кто-нибудь это скажет. Верно, это был бы вопрос по маршрутизации, но не где-нибудь в SOHO-сети, а в Интернете. Т.е. **и** маршрутизация, **и** Интернет. Вопрос по настройке пластмассовой коробочки, устанавливаемой в квартиру, будет вопросом по маршрутизации, но не по Интернету. А вопрос про пандемию очередного Windows-червя — вопросом по Интернету, но не по маршрутизации.

Возражение против метки Интернет можно выдвинуть на другом основании: тут есть специалисты по языкам, по сетям, по операционкам, и по ПО, а вот где спецы по Интернету? Прямо так сидят читают этот сайт?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi На сайте 27 вопросов по маршрутизации. Ради одного вопроса по маршрутизации добавлять тег о маршрутизации в глобальной сети — жирно будет. Не говоря о том, что не факт, что подобный широкий вопрос будет на сайте уместен. С червями аналогично. / Проблема в том, что "специалистов по Интернету" не существует. Под эту метку попадает очень большая часть вопросов сайта, потому что нынче очень многое завязано на глобальную сеть. Наличие метки ничего не говорит о вопросе.

Answer (score -2):

**Решение:**

Предлагаю ввести метку [не-используйте-эту-метку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83). На нее синонимизировать все метки, которые бесполезны и нежелательны.

Когда пользователь введет название нежелательной метки, оно автозаменится на «не-используйте-эту-метку». Поскольку это уже совсем не та, метка, которую пользователь добавлял, то он, скорее всего, её заметит.

В [кратком описании](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83/info) будет информация, почему ее не нужно использовать:

> Вы использовали слишком общую метку. Такие метки не добавляют информативности к вопросу. Выберите метку, соответствующую конкретному языку или используемой технологии. Детальные инструкции вы можете найти в полном описании метки.

В полном описании - конкретные указания по меткам, которые можно перенести из разных [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google), [скрипт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82) и т.п.

**Вопрос**: какие метки синонимизировать к этой, а какие к другим или вообще оставить как есть?

Например, [вконтакте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5) это уже очень близко к желательному [vkontakte-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte-api). Может, туда и поставить синоним? Или про VK могут быть вопросы, не касающиеся API?

**Дополнительная проблема:**

После синонимизации появится несколько сотен уже существующих вопросов с этой меткой. Думаю, они не станут от этого хуже, чем с меткой [интернет], например. Но хорошо бы её и оттуда вычистить. Как?

Идея родилась вот в этом обсуждении: [Большая [ошибка] в названии метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/549/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment1462_551)

Comment: восстановил ради исторической справедливости.