# Какие изменения необходимы Stack Overflow на русском?

Tags: обсуждение, faq

В последнее время можно было заметить некоторые разногласия среди участников сообщества в организационных вопросах. По большей части это происходит по нашей вине. Запуская сообщество Stack Overflow на русском, мы, компания, допустили грубейшую ошибку - скопировали правила одного сообщества в другое. Это в корне неверно.

Сейчас Мир видит Stack Overflow как незаменимый инструмент в жизни каждого современного разработчика, а правила общения в сообществе лучшими, какие можно придумать для проекта такого формата и масштаба. Со стороны может казаться, что все это произошло само собой, но это не так.

Stack Overflow на английском - зрелое, сформировавшееся сообщество, а действующие там правила были созданы в процессе эволюции - сталкиваясь с какой-либо организационной проблемой, пользователи обсуждали, как им двигаться дальше, не теряя того самого, ради чего они принимают участие в проекте. Чтобы сформировать свод правил, которые действуют на Stack Overflow на английском, потребовался не один год!

Планируя запуск Stack Overflow на русском, мы, Stack Exchange, предались иллюзии, что, взяв передовой движок, выработанные годами правила общения в международном сообществе и пригласив знатоков, русскоязычный остров знаний засияет. Мы ошиблись.

#### Что же не так?

Обдумывая обсуждения на Мете, можно прийти к выводу, что мы, сообщество, пытаемся создать что-то абстрактное, отдаленное от реальности: не то Хэш Overflow, не то Stack Код. Но мы уже не ХэшКод, а до Stack Overflow на английском нам еще идти и идти.

**Более не ХэшКод**. Функционал нового движка, а как результат, и окружение, в котором взаимодействует сообщество, кардинально отличается. Например, раньше мы всем сообществом обсуждали и выбирали лучшие, на наш взгляд, правила общения; но гарантом их выполнения были по большей части модераторы. Сейчас все по-другому: хоть модераторы и могут влиять на решения, но в подавляющем большинстве случаев последнее слово остается за сообществом.

**Но и не Stack Overflow на английском**. Текущие правила общения на Stack Overflow на английском определяются условиями, в которых существует сообщество, например, большим количеством новых вопросов, порядка восьми тысяч в день, а также количеством пользователей, почти четыре с половиной миллиона зарегистрированных участников.

#### Как сделать лучше?

Как говорится, “в споре рождается истина”. Разногласия среди участников сообщества говорят о том, что мы, Stack Overflow на русском:

1. имеем большое количество талантливых интересных Личностей, которые готовы и хотят делиться своими идеями с сообществом;
2. нам небезразлична судьба нынешних и будущих русскоязычных разработчиков программного обеспечения, мы хотим изменить проект да и всю индустрию в лучшую сторону.

Уверен, цель любого, кто принимает участие в дискуссиях на Мете, сделать Stack Overflow на русском лучше, так, чтобы его было приятно использовать, а сформированная база прикладных знаний проекта приносила большую пользу сообществу!

Для этого нам необходимо создать свод правил, которые будут просты и удобны в использовании, **удобны именно для нас, текущих участников сообщества Stack Overflow на русском!**

> Если вы считаете, что то или иное правило организации сообщества необходимо улучшить, пожалуйста, задайте вопрос на Мете, добавив ссылку на него в ответе к этой публикации.

При публикации заявки на улучшение, пожалуйста, помните:

- *Stack Overflow - это сайт вопросов и ответов*. Существует ряд основополагающих правил, которые не изменятся, например, мы никогда не станем дискуссионным форумом. В случае если вы опубликуете запрос на улучшение того, что по умолчанию не может быть улучшено, я постараюсь явно отписаться об этом в кратчайшие сроки.
- Публикуемый вопрос должен содержать четкое описание проблемы, с которой вы столкнулись.
- Если у вас есть замечательная идея решения проблемы, следует опубликовать ее отдельным ответом, то есть так, чтобы она могла участвовать в голосовании, либо предложите автору существующей улучшение в комментариях.
- На обсуждение одного улучшения предлагаю отвести две недели. Таким образом, автору вопроса следует принять ответ, к которому склоняется большинство участников обсуждения не позже чем через две недели после публикации вопроса.

**Коллеги, давайте вместе создадим такое сообщество Stack Overflow на русском, в котором нам всем будет приятно и полезно общаться!**

Comment: В вопросе не хватает объективных метрик, чтобы понять есть ли проблема и оценить её количественно, например, интересно посмотерь как [цифры c area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) от месяца к месяцу меняются (исключить старые вопросы/ответы, прошлую репутацию)

Comment: @jfs Если у вас есть идеи каких-либо интересных метрик, вы можете предложить их в ответе к этому вопросу. Более того, вы сразу же можете предложить и их реализацию через [обозреватель базы данных Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Мне тут не нравится "Но еще не Stack Overflow на английском". Как будто при должной доработке он станет Stack Overflow на английском, а пока что не дотягивает. На самом деле это не так.

Comment: Согласен про корректность утверждения. Поправил. Хотя какого-то контекста не подразумевалось. Это была игра слов.

Answer (score 12):

На мой взгляд, многие декларируемые проблемы преувеличиваются в своей значимости, нежели то, что они представляют из себя на самом деле. Я бы вообще обозначил их как рабочий процесс и не более. В целом с ресурсом всё замечательно, а вездесущая неудовлетворённость отдельных участников не может быть ликвидирована в принципе, поскольку она субъективна. Но это на самом деле и здорово, так как в обратном случае ресурс загнётся просто по причине того, что если тебя абсолютно всё устраивает, то ты либо счастливый идиот, либо равнодушен. И тот и другой - пассажиры временные, а значит массовое и субъективное недовольство - это отличный знак.

*Предложение*. Создание квалифицированных ответов по различным технологиям с меткой `*-faq`.

*Ссылка на обсуждение*: "[Создание общих вопросов по базовым технологиям c меткой faq](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/693/)".

Comment: В такой форме на ваше предложение невозможно дать ответ, тем более - несколько ответов. Предлагаю оформить его отдельным вопросом. Я проголосую «за».

Comment: Про карму: неа, не взлетит. По моему опыту, это самый медленный способ набирать репутацию. Пятиминутные вопросы "google it for me" - гораздо более быстрый источник.

Comment: @NickVolynkin , да тут наверное особо нечего обсуждать. Оно сугубо по желанию каждого из участников и не требует низкого старта. Однако при соблюдении хотя бы некоторой регулярности, я уверен, профит для ресурса не заставит себя ждать.

Comment: Меня вообще удивляют разведение соплей, пафосные речи про "грубейшие ошибки" и "срочные меры" и прочая чехарда. У большого СО тоже огромные проблемы, и они в большой мере общие для всех сайтов сети SE. Ничего уникального в низкокачественных вопросах, невнимательных ревьюерах, отсутствии исправлений закрытых вопросов и прочем нет — это давно известные проблемы.

Comment: @Discord, просто раньше ныли только про *"ХэшКод уже не тот"*, а теперь добавилось нытье про *"RU.SO не такой как SO"*.

Comment: @alexis031182 Вынес ваше предложение в отдельный вопрос для возможности обсуждения и принятия решений. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте, если что-то не так.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky , спасибо. Редактировать нет нужды, пусть будет, если считаете, что имеет смысл обсудить. Я экспериментально сделал метку `opencv-faq`, тема мне интересна, по мере возможности буду участвовать.

Comment: @alexis031182: почитал ваши Q&A. Понял немного, но стиль изложения мне очень нравится. За вопрос, как обещал, проголосовал.

Comment: @NickVolynkin , спасибо. Я смотрю по javascript тоже faq сделали, хотя может быть он уже давно, не знаю.

Comment: @alexis031182: свежие вопросы по джаваскрипту вижу. Ну а я про Git уже столько меток создал, что за git-faq меня, наверное, не похвалят )))

Comment: @NickVolynkin , Вы смотрите сами, как лучше. Может быть имеет смысл объединить несколько меток в одну мейнстримовую. Одно мне кажется, для метки `*-faq` нужно соблюдать правило: сам задал вопрос, и свой ответ должен быть в обязательном порядке.

Answer (score 11):

*Проблема*. Закрытые вопросы редко получают улучшающую правку от авторов (то есть открываются повторно). На мой взгляд, это связанно с недопониманием того, почему вопрос был закрыт, и что сделать, чтобы он был открыт повторно.

*Предлагаемое решение*. Изменить формулировки причин закрытия вопросов.

Ссылка на обсуждение: "[Как должны выглядеть сообщения о закрытии вопроса?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/545/)".

Comment: *это связано с недопониманием того, почему вопрос был закрыт* — в первую очередь — скорее, с незнанием: в интерфейсе «повторного открытия», насколько помню, вообще нет упоминаний о причине закрытия. т.е., чтобы узнать причину (что обычно необходимо для понимания ситуации и принятия взвешенного решения), приходится открывать вопрос в отдельной вкладке.

Answer (score 11):

**Проблема**: Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в персональный консультационный пункт новичков, цели ресурса не выполняются.

**Решение**: Я не вижу решения этой проблемы.

Ссылка [на обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/616/177345).

Comment: возможно, решением можно будет считать накопление багажа «умных» ответов на «примитивные» вопросы.

Comment: Решение - ждать. Stack Overflow тоже далеко не сразу вырос в мастодонта. Накопление хороших ответов на хоть какие вопросы с возможной последующей систематизацией через задание уже специалистом "канонического" вопроса (канонической формы, такого, который, вероятно, люди будут задавать поисковику) с созданием, возможно совместным, канонического же ответа (владелец Community, чтобы не париться о репутации того, кто будет ответ постить).

Comment: мне одному показалось или все ощутили, как начался учебный год число народу прибаивилось, а вопросы на уровне первая ссылка в гугле? не совсем понятно как реашть этот вопрос. мне всетаки кажеться что SOru это база знаний по широкому кругу проблем, а не лакальный фелиал cyberforum.ru . Может как-то фильтрацию настроить, очень хочеться качественного контента.

Comment: и вот еще существует на SO возможность закрипить ссылку на вопросы в духе что пичитать какие тесты есть, в профиле или в отдельной вкладке.?

Answer (score 11):

*Проблема*. На данный момент на Stack Overflow на русском действуют сильные ограничение на форматы и типы задаваемых вопросов. Некоторым участникам сообщества могли бы быть интересны форматы и типы вопросов, которые на на данный момент являются не тематическими.

*Решение*. А что если **разрешить**

> Вопросы с просьбами предоставить рекомендации или найти книги,
>   инструменты, библиотеки, материалы для обучения или любые другие
>   внешние ресурсы

а также не требовать **однозначного ответа** от вопроса, сайт станет действительно хуже?

Ссылка на обсуждение: "[А что если разрешить?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/623/)".

---

[Ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/604/6) @avp, перенесен из [другого вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/545/).

Answer (score 10):

*Проблема*: под наплывом некачественных вопросов пользователи начинают проявлять агрессию, если им кажется, что участник приложил недостаточно усилий к самостоятельному решению проблемы.

*Предлагаемое решение*: к сожалению, подобную проблему сложно решить прямым путем, за счет изменения качества приходящих вопросов. Предлагается проработать личное отношение к новичкам и их вопросам, поставить себя на место человека, который еще не научился самостоятельно искать информацию и дистанцироваться от личного восприятия вопроса.

Ссылка на обсуждение: [Что делать, если вопрос вызывает злость?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/535/16095)

Comment: Нужно разрешить анонимный постинг в ответах на вопросы от людей с кармой меньше 200 и сделать специального юзера на которого будет сливаться вся полученная за анонимные ответы карма. Вот будет веселье.

Answer (score 7):

**проблема:** довольно часто автор вопроса самостоятельно находит решение, и даже возвращается к вопросу, **но** приводит решение **не** в виде ответа, а редактируя и дополняя вопрос.

**решение1:** если со времени последней правки вопроса **автором** прошло больше *энного* количества времени, то при нажатии автором кнопки *править* настойчиво напомнить ему, что «если вдруг» у него есть решение, то лучше оформить его в виде ответа (и сразу ссылку на создание ответа приложить), и заинтересовать дополнительными баллами репутации и «медальками».

**решение2: (альтернативное или дополнительное)** в той же самой ситуации, если автор всё-таки вносит правку в вопрос, поставить вопрос в какую-нибудь из «проверочных» очередей (может быть, движок позволяет новые очереди создавть без «внутреннего» вмешательства?).

**обсуждение**: [*как заинтересовать автора вопроса публиковать найденное им решение в виде ответа?*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/696/178576)

Comment: Больое спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Проблема: пользователи дают краткий, но удовлетворительный ответ в комментарии (который получает голоса). Вопрос висит в неотвеченных, хотя уже давно отвечен в комментарии.

Решение:

- средство для превращения комментариев в ответ (счётчик голосов на ответ может зависеть от счётчика голосов при комментарии),
- или средство пометки комментария как ответ на вопрос,
- или средство пометки вопроса как решённого даже без ответов.

Comment: не нужно. вы сейчас можете руками скопировать текст из комментария в свой ответ.

Comment: В свое время уже было предложено и отвергнуто: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555 . Если коротко: автору виднее, хочет ли он оставить комментарий или ответ. Всегда можно попросить автора оформить ответом. Или самому скопировать в ответ и для честности сделать ответ "общим".

Comment: Это много действий. Может, если бы была одна кнопка "подтвердить комментарий как ответ", которая бы сама копировала коментарий в ответ + указывала авторство + подтверждала бы его, то это было бы чаще.

Comment: Да, в формате двух кнопок: "предложить преобразовать в ответ" и "подтвердить" - возможно взлетело бы.

Comment: Я против и вот почему: комментарии вообще не предназначены для ответов. Нельзя поощрять таким образом пубикацию ответов в комментарии. Если уж такое случилось, любой может взять текст, доработать и опубликовать как ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, А что делать, с короткой фразой-подсказкой, в которой ты не уверен и которая явно не тянет на полноценный ответ? Иногда ответы автоматически преобразуются в комментарии кстати.

Comment: @_Vi: если есть время и знания, чтобы преобразовать в ответ - сделать это и получить заслуженную репутацию. Если нет времени, то плюсануть. Если не хватает знаний и уверенности в решении - не трогать. Ещё можно написать автору: "Не могли бы вы доработать это и опубликовать как ответ? Похоже, что ваше решение верное".

Comment: @Nofate: *автору виднее, хочет ли он оставить комментарий или ответ* — даже с учётом того, что, оставляя комментарий, автор уступает все права в пользу [se]?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, мопед не мой, просто пересказываю содержание прошлых серий. Кстати, автор не уступает права, а лицензирует SE на использование своего контента.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я как раз скорее за эту фичу. Раньше на ХэшКоде такая опция была и ей активно пользовались, например.

Answer (score 4):

> Если у вас есть идеи каких-либо интересных метрик, вы можете предложить их в ответе к этому вопросу.

Ссылка на обсуждение: [Есть ли тенденция снижения активности и использования сайта?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/875/).

Comment: Интересно, почему падает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, элементарно, Ватсон. Лето же, студенты отдыхают. Пик посещаемости любых программистских ресурсов приходится на сессию когда наваливается массовка студентов разной степени добросовестности. Во время учебного года ботаны тоже заходят

Comment: @NickVolynkin, плюс, _возможно_, есть некоторая связь с отношением к оффтоп-вопросам и всяким опросникам. Но даже если действительно есть, сезонность ее съедает

Comment: предпоследняя ссылка (про 74%) ведет просто на страницу выбора сайта.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: 1. добавил картинку с трафиком прямо в ответ, чтобы было ясно что сессия здесь ни при чём. 2. ссылка ведёт на страницу со статистикой для всех сайтов (в строчке с Stack Overflow на русском написано: answered 74%), можно ту же цифру получить, если зайти по следующей ссылке на data.SE и указать большое кол-во месяцев.

Comment: @jsf, мне по прежнему не ясно что "сессия не причем". Видим спад, спад приходится на лето, что объяснимо студентами и сезоном отпусков, на более длинных дистанциях посмотреть толком не можем, потому что переезд с хешкода на со все основательно перетряхнул. Где моя гипотеза дает сбой?

Comment: @MakarovAV: сбой в том, что апрель май -- это не лето

Comment: @jsf, ок, убедительно) А ru.so в открытый доступ не в апреле ли выехал? Тогда можно списать на повышенное внимание зарубежного коммьюнити в первое время

Comment: Опубликовал в виде вопроса, чтобы можно было дать развернутый ответ всем желающим.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: моё намерение привести метрики, которые *объективно* (а не на уровне анекдотов, ощущений в животе) могут что-то про сайт сказать. Это просто совпадение, что они могут создать впечатление о снижении  активности и использования сайта. Просто ни один из вопросов/ответов к [Какие изменения необходимы Stack Overflow на русском?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594/23044) даже не пытался цифры привести. Измерения панацеей не являются, но плохо когда решения принимаются совсем без них

Comment: @jfs Да, я прекрасно вас понимаю. К сожалению, в случае ответа в этом вопросе, я, как и многие другие участники, не могу выразить свои мысли, формат комментариев не позволяет. Вынес в отдельный вопрос исключительно для продолжения дискуссии.

Answer (score 3):

**Проблема:** Пользователи (особенно новые) иногда используют бессмысленные обобщенные метки и вместо них не используют конкретные и осмысленные.

**[Решение 1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/598/181472):** Ввести метку [не-используйте-эту-метку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83) как главный синоним ко всем обобщенным меткам и мета-меткам. В описании метки дать объяснения и инструкции.

**[Решение 2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/600/181472):** Вычистить все нежелательные метки из вопросов и добавить их в черный список.

**Ссылка на обсуждение:** [Как помочь участнику использовать конкретные метки вместо обобщенных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/593/)

Comment: Мне кажется, выбор меток это проблема не только новичков. Это же предложение только усугубит неразбериху. Думаю, что решением проблемы был бы переход к иерерхии меток (с навигацией при выборе метки и возможностью добавить в это дерево свою метку), но к сожалению,  это потребует изменения движка, поэтому в наших обстоятельтвах нереализуемо.

Comment: @avp ну вот там есть второе жесткое решение от Discord, можете за него проголосовать.

Comment: Можно и вычистить, а можно и просто оставить как есть. Хуже не будет. Весь этот огород с метками -- просто какая-то мышиная возня непонятно ради какой идеи.

Comment: @avp Скорее всего, идея - каталогизация знаний.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, в рамках "plain" модели (без "метаметок") вряд ли корректно реализуемо.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема: много простых, "новичковых" вопросов;

Решение: голосовалка за категорию вопроса (лёгкий, средний, сложный). Категория ≠ качество. По категории можно фильтровать, на главной странице квоты сколько вопросов из какой категории показывать.

Таким образов, "консультационный пункт новичков" (лёгкая категория), "база знаний" (средняя категория) и "мини-исследования" (сложная категория) будут сосуществовать, не мешая друг другу.

*Ссылка на обсуждение:* [Голосовалки за сложность вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/705/)

Comment: Это могло бы действительно все здорово изменить в лучшую сторону. А проблема в общем-то одна -- **меняется архитектура сайта** (не думаю, что Ваше предложение пройдет, а жаль...)

Comment: Пожалуйста, публикуйте отдельное обсуждение для каждой проблемы, которую вы видите. Затем добавляйте ответ в этот вопрос со ссылкой на обсуждение. В текущем виде другие участники физически не могут дать полноценный развернутый ответ отражающий их мнение, а также голосовать за то или иное решение. Главная задача не просто назвать проблемы, а выработать решения!

Comment: Я думаю, что из этого ничего не выйдет. Сложность вопроса это очень субъективно

Comment: @avp А если не меняя архитектуру просто-напросто ввести тэг "Вопрос от новичка" или там "Difficulty level: n00b" :) "Отцы" смогут такие вопросы "развидеть", а те, кто хочет набивать карму и кому такие вопросы не обрыдли, будут помогать новичкам (и, стоит признать, лентяям).

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, может быть. А Вы это предложение и технологию его использования обмозгуйте, да и опубликуйте, как отдельную тему на Мете, чтобы все могли его обсудить.

Comment: @_Vi Пожалуйста, уточните описание проблемы и перенесите в отдельный вопрос так, чтобы все участники сообщества могли предложить альтернативные варианты решения проблемы. В текущей формулировке лично я не вижу проблемы, как результат не могу перенести обсуждение в отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0

Answer (score 3):

*Проблема*. Модель вопросов и ответов Stack Exchange сильно отличается от идеологии стандартного форума. В дополнение, весе содержимое сайта следует адаптировать для читающего. Как результат, может возникнуть недопонимание того, каким образом эффективно использовать сайт.

*Предлагаемое решение*. Создать страницу документации содержащую правила использования, а также объяснение того, почему это происходит именно так, а не иначе.

*Ссылка на обсуждение*: "[Как правильно использовать модель вопросов и ответов Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/643/)".

Comment: Эх. Документацию обычно не читает никто. Ни новички (они не знают о документации), ни опытные пользователи (они-то точно уверены, что всё уже знают и так).

Comment: @VladD: верно, подавляющее большинство не будет читать, но будущие активные участники могут и прочитать. Вот приятная картинка из изначального видения [вики ∩ форум  ∩ блог ∩ programming reddit](http://blog.codinghorror.com/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us/)

Answer (score 3):

*Проблема*. На Stack Overflow на английском и португальском языках на Мете используются локализованные метки, на Stack Overflow на русском нет.

*Решение*. Подготовить перевод меток.

*Ссылка на обсуждение*: [Как можно перевести системные метки на Мете?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/866/)

Comment: Мета - мелочи, вопрос касается проблем на основной части сайта. Но да, перевести спецметки имеет смысл.

Answer (score 3):

*Проблема*. У сообщества Stack Overflow на русском нет уникальных сувениров, которыми бы мы могли радовать себя время от времени.

*Решение*. Сделать их!

*Ссылка на обсуждение*: [Какие подарки и сувениры мы бы хотели?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/879/)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема: код в вопросах (а иногда в ответах) часто не выравнен из-за присутствия табуляции и лишних или отсутствующих пробелов.

Решение: автоматически или по команде редактора заменять табуляцию пробелами, добавлять/удалять пробелы так, чтобы получалось общепринятое форматирование кода с отступами; по возможности учитывать синтаксис языка.

Comment: Мы тут больше об общественных проблемах, а не о технических. Рекомендую запостить в отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Угу, это был бы feature request для команды, занимающейся движком. Auto-pretty-printer.

Comment: Действительно, а то надоело уже *M-x untabify* в Emacs-е выполнять.

Comment: И бить током ОП, когда он неформатированный код публикует.

Comment: @avp, точную тему уже не найду, но на подобные вопросы наверху говорят "мы используем готовый редактор, все вопросы - к авторам".

Comment: не надо этого. makefile не работает потому что SO заменяет табы на пробелы

Answer (score -3):

Проблема: Часто ответы дублируются! Много нытья про то, что вопросы некачественные, а вот про ответы некачественные плачут очень мало.

Решение: Принять за правило, что каждый новый ответ — это отдельный вариант решения проблемы. Поощрять репутацией всех соавторов не только за отдельные правки, но и за повышение рейтинга ответа после того, как правки были приняты. Авторский стиль не наша тема.

Comment: Часто два человека одновременно начинают отвечать на вопрос. Как им определить, кто должен удалить свой ответ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, публикуйте отдельное обсуждение для каждой проблемы, которую вы видите. Затем добавляйте ответ в этот вопрос со ссылкой на обсуждение. В текущем виде другие участники физически не могут дать полноценный развернутый ответ отражающий их мнение, а также голосовать за то или иное решение. Главная задача не просто назвать проблемы, а выработать решения!

Comment: Это точно не пройдёт. Ответы не на 100% дублируются. Пусть автор выбирает тот, что ему больше нравится

Comment: А про некачественные ответы и не надо плакать. Их надо минусовать и удалять.