# Создание общих вопросов по базовым технологиям c меткой faq

Tags: обсуждение, метки, правила, мета-метки

Хотел бы предложить на рассмотрение не проблему, а улучшение. Оно уже существует, но не было принято во внимание многими профессиональными в своих областях участниками. Речь о метках с суффиксом `*-faq`. Для `С++` таковая существует, и, если не ошибаюсь, была внедрена участником [@Abyx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177684/). На мой взгляд, иногда имеет смысл не ждать у моря погоды, а взять инициативу в свои руки: берётся некий вопрос и тут же создаётся под него квалифицированный ответ в определённой области с раскрытием каких-либо хитростей.

Уверен, что многие с учётом собственного опыта могут предложить множество интересностей, но в виду общей практики ожидания вопроса, а не действия на опережение, так и не раскроют собственный потенциал в этом самом ожидании. Конечно, карма от такого вида деятельности резко не взлетит, но вряд ли найдётся много отвечающих на вопросы участников, что чрезмерно гонятся за ней.

---

Обсуждение создано из [ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/618/6) участника [@alexis031182](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177227/).

Comment: Метка `javascript-faq`, кстати, тоже существует.

Answer (score 6):

выношу предложение, [озвученное Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/693/?cb=1#comment1823_694):

использовать одну метку [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq), и с нею вместе — тематические `метки`.

преимущества и ответ на возможное возражение:

1. часто в вопросе затрагиваются несколько тем/технологий, для которых существуют отдельные метки, которые желательно сохранить, не «уперевшись» в ограничение движка: «не более пяти меток на вопрос».
2. поиск можно осуществлять запросом: `[метка] [faq]`. например:

   ```
   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20faq
   ```

   [[c++] [faq]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20faq)

Answer (score 5):

Поясню насчет [c++-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq).

[Такой тег](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) есть на английском SO. Ссылка на этот тег есть на [вики-странице](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) тега `c++`. За тегом активно следят участники чата `Lounge<C++>`, так что туда не попадает ничего лишнего. Могу ошибаться, но вроде именно `Lounge<C++>` и пролоббировало этот тег. (Хотя возможно что он существовал раньше). Также, кажется что это единственный `*-faq` тег на английском SO.

Зачем этот тег нужен?

Считается, что начинающий пользователь может зайти на вики-страницу тега [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), увидеть там ссылку на список вопросов тега [c++-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq), начать их читать и просвещаться.

С другой стороны, этот тег помогает закрывателям вопросов находить каноничные дубликаты вопросов.

---

Тем не менее, даже без использования `*-faq` тегов, надо создавать вопросы с само-ответами. Чем больше будет хорошего, качественного контента - тем лучше.

Comment: Почему бы не использовать просто [tag:faq]? В этом случае отслеживать подобные вопросы проще. Например, можно будет посмотреть как все вопросы с меткой [tag:faq], так и конкретные ([tag:faq+c++] или [tag:faq+java]).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, мне кажется, в таком случае (если использовать и `faq`, и `метка-faq`, и `метка`) довольно часто можно будет «упереться» в ограничение движка «не больше пяти меток у вопроса».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я имел в виду использовать `faq` вместо `c++-faq`. В этом случае, например, если вопрос про интеграцию с++ и java, то метки будут `c++`, `java`, `faq`.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, это тоже весьма неплохой вариант. ведь, например, вопрос, заслуживающий отметки «часто задаваемый», может одновременно касаться далеко не одной тематической *метки*. может быть, имеет смысл вынести это предложение на публичное обсуждение?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не могу представить себе ситуации, когда кто-то захочет посмотреть все вопросы с тегом faq. Они настолько будут разные, что я не знаю, кем надо быть, чтобы такое было нужно.

Comment: @ixSci Почему же. На мой взгляд, вполне нормальное желание. Например, когда ничего не знаешь и не хочешь издеваться над будущими коллегами вопросами типа "Что почитать начинающему программисту-студенту?".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, это какой-то патологический случай. В любом случае человек хоть что-то имеет на уме. Просто faq, на мой взгляд, совершенно не имеет смысла. FAQ бывает почему-то. а не по всему сразу.

Comment: @ixSci Для этого можно использовать другие метки. [Подобный вопрос уже обсуждался](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/321/6). Коротко: зачем объединять несколько меток в одну, создавая новую, если уже есть несколько? То есть зачем метка [tag:c++-faq], если есть [tag:c++] и [tag:faq]?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, затем что тыкнув в c++-faq, я сразу получу все вопросы с этим тегом. А как искать по двум тегам я даже не знаю.

Comment: @ixSci Это уже аргумент, если опытные участники на знают про такой функционал. P. S. Для этого надо навигироваться по выбранной метке, затем, на странице выборки, в боковой панели выбрать нужную связанную метку и нажать на нее. В результате будет сформирован список вопросов отмеченных обеими метками.

Answer (score 4):

Не создавать метки [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) и `*-faq`.

1. Это мета-метка. Сейчас происходит активное удаление мета-меток с сайта. Исключений, кроме этой метки, пока мне неизвестно.
   Если решение оставить некоторые мета-метки будет принято, то лучше завести список исключений со ссылками на соответствующие обсуждения на мете.
2. Вопросы формата faq вполне можно вносить в описание метки. Их не может быть много, а в описании метки будет вполне удобный список для ознакомления. Можно даже краткую аннотацию указывать.
3. На английском enSO вообще нет метки [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq), и метками вида `*-faq` помечено только порядка 250 вопросов, что крайне мало для enSO (из них примерно 150 на [c++-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) и 100 на [r-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq)). Странно такое выделение этих двух технологий относительно остальных.