# должны ли у вопроса присутствовать одновременно [метка] и [метка-faq]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

в процессе реализации этого предложения: [*Создание общих вопросов по базовым технологиям c меткой faq*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/693/178576*) — я уже нескольким вопросам присвоил метки, содержащие суффикс `-faq`.

в ответе к [этому универсальному (автор не указал используемый *http-сервер*) вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434915/178576) упомянуты и *apache* и *nginx*. сейчас я оставил только две метки: `apache-faq` и `nginx-faq`.

**частный** вопрос: стоит ли дополнять упомянутый вопрос метками `apache` и `nginx`?

**общий** вопрос: следует ли после присвоения `метки-faq` удалять саму `метку`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, обе метки нужно оставлять. По faq мало кто фильтрует, я полагаю.

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю добавление меток в соответствии с затрагиваемыми в вопросе и ответе темами для категории `faq`.

Единственная, может быть, просьба ко всем участникам - это формулирование вопросов по возможности самостоятельно, поскольку наличие набранных изначально минусов у вопроса (часто вполне заслуженно) может несколько снизить уровень доверия к качеству содержимого у рассматриваемого типа меток.

Comment: *Поддерживаю добавление* — то есть, вы считаете, что должны присутствовать **обе** метки: и `[метка]`, и `[метка-faq]`?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , да, конечно. С одной стороны в вопросе и ответе прямо затрагиваются темы `apache` и `nginx`, а с другой - метками с суфиксом `*-faq` отмечается востребованность конкретики, раскрытой в данных вопросе и ответе.

Comment: А что делать с дублированием в таком случае?

Comment: @NickVolynkin , не вполне понял. О каком дублировании речь?

Comment: @alexis031182: про «формулирование вопросов самостоятельно». Вот есть очень криво заданный вопрос по хорошей теме. К нему есть один-два ответа, возможно неполных. Сам вопрос заминусован. Хорошо бы самостоятельно сформулировать и ответить, но строго говоря это будет дубль. Что делать? Я пока что не придумал.

Comment: @NickVolynkin , тут как бы два варианта: либо править текст исходного вопроса в соответствии с собственным виденьем того, как последний должен быть представлен конечному потребителю, либо создавать новый. Тогда, на мой взгляд, здесь нет никакого дублирования. Даже если будет создан новый вопрос, он будет соответствовать высокой планке в значительно большей степени. Фактически, речь идёт лишь о том, чтобы в "*-faq" не попадало всё подряд, не прошедшее должной проверки, а в случае необходимости - правки.