# Необходимость меток [xxx-faq]

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

У нас есть куча меток вида [xxx-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xxx-faq). Нужны ли они все? Или достаточно одной [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq)? Все равно такие вопросы идут с уточняющей меткой или метками.

Пример: [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

На этом вопросе весят метки [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [mysqli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli), [mysql-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-faq), [php-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-faq). Я предлагаю сделать так [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [mysqli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli), [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq). Потому что иначе напрашивается еще и метка [mysqli-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli-faq)

Comment: Мне сложно сказать, как часто стоит менять тот или иной выбор, чтобы не скатываться в постоянные изменения и не оказаться скованным неправильным выбором (и я не предлагаю закрыть вопрос, например дубликатом), но хочу напомнить, что эта тема обсуждалась, ссылки на смежные вопросы для тех кто не в курсе: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2139/213987 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/735/213987 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/693/213987 Метки были созданы в 2015, через пару лет был поднят вопрос о ревизии

Comment: @AK Вот ответ, набравший максимальное число голосов https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/835/221228 Но, как я понимаю, тогда никакого решения так и не приняли и все осталось как есть. И таки вторая твоя ссылка - это полный дубликат моего вопроса. Так, что можно мой вопрос закрыть дубликатом. Вот только решения так и нет

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое "решение". По любой теме и в момент голосования будут разные мнения, а спустя полгода баланс может поменяться в ту или иную сторону, а чаще — просто новый участник вновь подымет тему и в общем-то все снова повторят свои аргументы и останутся при своём мнении. Поэтому если у вас был вопрос и он снят — можете как автор закрыть дубликатом, а вот если у вас предложение и вы тщательно обдумав готовы предложить поменять текущий консенсус — тогда закрывать не стоит. Лично я не вижу, что любое изменение сделает кардинально лучше, но скорее просто воздержусь в этом вопросе.

Comment: @AK "решение" это правило "делаем так". У меня есть предложение, но оно уже было озвучено и ни к каким изменением не привело