# Метки типа faq и tutorial

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Это пост - голосование на тему дальнейшего пути меток *-faq

На данный момент на сайте существуют метки типа [c++-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq), которые, по утверждению людей в чатике, нужны (меня за них аж в правках забанили, двумя голосами, против одного, кошмар!), и применяются для теоретических вопросов. На деле, указанную метку не использует никто, кроме участника @Abyx, что демонстрирует, что она, как минимум, не работает. По этому поводу у меня есть несколько предложений:

1. Простое: Снести эти метки к чертям собачим и забыть, как страшный сон. В конечном итоге, поиск по метке маловероятен, скорее пользователь будет искать информацию в похожих вопросах или простым текстовым поиском (если вообще будет).
2. Сложное, но однозначно реализуемое:

   - Создать аналогичные метки для всех языков программирования, явно указав в описании, что при задавании вопроса без автоответа её использовать **не надо**.
   - Вменить в обязанность модераторам и опытным участникам вешать эти метки только на вопросы по теории языка, с **принятыми ответами**.
   - Создать под каждый из языков страницу в справке, на которой поддерживать список таких вопросов, разбитый по категориям, для удобства пользователей.
   - Создать для каждого языка тег типа tutorial, куда складывать гайды для профи, а в faq оставить **часто задаваемые** вопросы по основам языка (опционально, голосующих за второй вариант прошу ответить, надо ли оно).
3. Самое сложное, без гарантии на успех, но решающее, ИМХО, проблему на корню: Вернуть исследования. Для этого придётся, очевидно, переписывать движок SO, в контакте с его разработчиками, для начала убедив их, что это надо. Но если удастся - все подобные вопросы можно будет организовать в исследования, а метки спалить нафиг.

Прошу высказываться.

Comment: Что есть "исследования"? Это из ХК?

Comment: @tutankhamun да. Специальный формат, в котором начинающий исследование задаёт тему, а уже к исследованию задаются/прикрепляются вопросы на эту тему.

Comment: На самом деле **самое простое решение** -- оставить как есть, т.е. просто не трогать эту метку. Ее наличие (впрочем, как и отсутствие) *практически* ни на что не влияет и поэтому непонятно, чем же она Вам мешает.

Answer (score 7):

Метки *-faq уже обсуждались в вопросе [Создание общих вопросов по базовым технологиям c меткой faq](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/693/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-c-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-faq) .

Конкретно метка c++-faq - это аналог [метки на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq). Там эта метка предназначена для FAQ (спосок вопросов, который можно показать новичкам) и для более удобного поиска дубликатов вопросов (для пользователей с 3к+ репы).

Применение это метки на русском SO возможно оказалось неудачным. В конце концов, у нас нет кучи вопросов с 1000+ или 100+ баллов, у нас нет столько посетителей, чтобы эти вопросы задавались *часто*. Большого коммьюнити, которое следило бы за меткой, у нас тоже нет.

Однако, я не вижу вреда от существования метки c++-faq, и других аналогичных меток.

Answer (score 5):

Я ближе к варианту 2. Но для начала вспомним причину появления этой метки:

Идея была в том, что некоторые вопросы типа сравнения строк в Java настолько часто задаются, что для них можно оформить **каноничный ответ**. Каноничные ответы стали отмечать меткой faq. Потом @Abyx убедил сообщество, что удобнее искать не по меткам [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) + [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq), а по одной метке [c++-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq). В пользу этого говорило и существование метки на большом SO.

На мой взгляд метка в большей степени нужна не спрашивающим, а отвечающим. Она позволяет быстро найти каноничный ответ, чтобы закрыть вопрос как дубликат. Ее можно указывать непосредственно в окне поиска при закрытии дубликата. Ее можно кидать в комментариях, где это допустимо и в чатах.

Касательно создания таких меток для всех языков: у нас еще есть [javascript-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-faq), [python-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-faq), [java-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-faq), [c#-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-faq) и некоторые другие. По ним мало активности, но эту ситуацию вполне можно улучшить, указав в описании метки правила ее использования и помечая ей каноничные ответы. Да, хорошо бы чтобы кто-то из активных экспертов присматривал за тематическими faq-метками.

---

Моё резюме: инструмент уже существует, он незаслуженно забыт, надо возрождать его применение.

Comment: Мета-знания, мета-метки, мета-эксперты .. не многовато ли мет?

Answer (score 3):

Спорная метка. Я, конечно, понимаю цель, которую преследовал @Abyx.

Но по факту:

1) Необходимо, чтоб кто-то следил за правильным назначением таких меток. Если всё же решим для всех языков такое делать, то для каждого языка назначить надсмотрщика или что-то такое. Я б мог следить за [java-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-faq).

2) Если решили всё-таки, что такие faq-метки - это хорошая практика, то делать только по языкам? Почему? Скажем, вполне мне видится разумным сделать метку [android-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-faq). Как мы будем определять по каким языкам/технологиям делать такую метку?

3) Самое главное - какие вопросы помечать такой меткой? Только общие вопросы аля ["Чем class отличается от struct"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420635/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-class-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-struct)? Есть много интересных вопросов/ответов, которые выходят за рамки общих вопросов, но имеют, скажем, большу́ю практическую ценность или же там сложное/интересное исследование.

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что обязательно ограничиваться языками, просто предлагаю с них начинать (или не начинать).

Comment: @Risto давайте тогда по каждой метке FAQ запилим, и по faq тоже FAQ нужен. Не так ли?

Comment: @KromStern вы за то, чтобы выпилить, я так понимаю?

Comment: @Risto однозначно выпилить.

Comment: 3) Очевидно, часто задаваемые.

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не создать один вопрос, типо "FAQ по C++" и там в ответе будет список с ссылками на все подобные каноничные вопросы? Ссылку в метку языка добавить, а faq-метку удалить?

Что-то такое же сделали со списком книг.

Comment: Из минусов: поиск из диалога закрытия как дубликата работать не будет. Правда там поиск настолько ущербный, что я им никогда не пользуюсь, только полные ссылки ввожу...

Comment: @Discord с поиском будет проблема, да. Но вроде эти faq-метки делали именно для активных юзеров. Проще до таких юзеров донести, что список есть в описании метки, тогда и поиск не нужен будет вовсе.

Answer (score 0):

Метка нужна и используется: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/413075

Эта метка есть не только по си++, но и по другим языкам.
По ней удобно искать нужные ответы, которые уже видел или сам написал.

Comment: В табличке указаны овнеры, так? А теперь статистику по тому, кто добавил эту метку к постам. Не знаю, что там с другими метками, но **все** посты в [tag:c++-faq] перемечены @Abyx. Не передёргивайте.

Comment: @Risto, я лично создавал [пост](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432369/178988) с [tag:javascript-faq]. И вообще, не важно, кто добавил метку, важно, что она нужна для поиска.

Comment: вопрос в том, удобна ли она для поиска. Я считаю что нет. Вы таки за второй вариант, или оставить "как росло"?

Comment: @Risto, я за то, что она удобна для поиска.

Comment: Ещё раз. Тут три варианта ответа:

 1. Метка не нужна.
 2. Метки нужны и должны грамотно продвигаться сообществом для всх ЯП.
 3. Нужно техническое решение.

Comment: @Risto, меня не было на хешкоде, поэтому вариант по исследованиям я оценить не могу. Из первых двух выбираю второй, посколько пользуюсь поиском по faq-меткам.

Comment: Ну вот и договорились. Меня не интересует, используется ли метка, меня интересует отсутствие чёткой системы. Именно для её выработки и создано это обсуждение, а не с целью что-то выпилить.

Comment: @Risto, а что не так с системой? Если имеется хороший ответ по какой-то возможности или особенности языка, или, что ещё лучше, задаётся с целью поделиться знаниями, т. е. флажком об ответе на собственный вопрос, то с вероятностью 90% у него должна быть faq-метка. Как-то так.

Comment: Когда эту метку будут использовать не полтора землекопа, а сто человек, - вы поймёте, что не так с системой, но разгребать этот завал будет уже поздно. Если мы делаем метку - нужна и инфраструктура под неё, для быстрого обнаружения **конкретного** поста. Именно в её создании я и вижу альтернативу удалению.

Comment: @Risto, ну так предлагай...

Comment: Так я предложил. Прочитайте пост.

Comment: Которые сам написал: `user:mine`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не понял, к чему относится этот комментарий.

Comment: @Qwertiy: чтобы искать ответы, которые вы сами написали, добавьте к строке поиска `user:mine is:answer`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, но ведь faq ищут не только те, кто его написал ;)

Answer (score -1):

ruSO - сайт для конкретный вопросов и ответов. Есть проблема - SO даст решение.

Если мне нужно перевернуть массив на C++, не буду я по всем C++-faq меткам шариться, а найду через Google. И найдя, не стану просматривать C++-faq в поисках решения к проблеме которой у меня еще нет.

Мета-метки -faq избыточны и не несут полезной информации.

Не будем же мы на каждую метку заводить метку-faq? А что дальше, faq-faq заведем?

*P.S. Это же мнение относится к другим подобным составным мета-меткам.*
*P.P.S. Что ткаое мета-метки и почему их тут не место: [Что-такое мета-метки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160)*

Comment: А если я хочу показать конкретное решение, я открываю сайт и его поиском ищу нужный вопрос. И в этот момент faq-метка замечательно помогает, потому что поиск у сайта отвратный. Метки нужны. Кстати, есть вариант сделать одну метку [tag:faq] вместо дополнительной метки по каждому языку, но это имеет смысл обсудить отдельно, а то там могут некоторые побочные эффекты вылезти.

Comment: Показать конкретное решение кому? А еще вопрос, чем наличие метки faq отличается от ее отсутствия по-вашему? Не-faq вопрос имеет неконкретное решение?

Comment: "Конкретное" не в смысле точности, а в смысле что я помню, что вот тут был вот такой вопрос и мне нужно конкретно его показать. Например, с этой целью я и написал тот ответ про сортировку. Для этого я введу в поиск faq-метку и какое-нибудь одно слово, которое поможет найти нужный вопрос, а не буду просматривать все вопросы, у кого что бывает не так с сортировкой. Если я знаю, что я ищу, то хочу найти это быстро.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ставьте метку favorite на вопрос. По ней можно искать. А схожие вопросы надо отмечать дубликатами.

Comment: [113 результатов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+сортировк*), [3 результата](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript-faq%5D+сортировк*). Что там дубликатами объявить? Если дописать в запрос `is:question` (а ведь лень), то получится 65 и 2 - вроде весьма ощутимая разница.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ставьте себе метку favorite на вопрос. По ней можно искать. А схожие вопросы надо отмечать дубликатами. А если эти 65 разные, то который из них достоит стать faq ?

Comment: @KromStern, тот который специально для этого подготовили, дав развернутый ответ

Comment: Ну очевидно же, что не каждый вопрос достоин стать faq. faq - это тольок те вопросы, которые полезны сами по себе и предоставляют хорошее решение распространённых задач.

Comment: А что, есть вопросы неполезные сами по себе? Давайте стремиться к тому, чтобы таких небыло, чтобы все были полезными - тогда и мета-метка будет не нужна! ;-)

Comment: Нет, не так. Часть вопросов полезны только при возникновении какой-то проблемы. А другая часть полезны сами по себе, т. е. если ты сейчас прочитаешь вопрос, весьма вероятно, что сведения из него будут тебе полезны даже если с этой проблемой ты ещё не столкнулся. Вот это и есть faq.