# Как заинтересовать автора вопроса публиковать найденное им решение в виде ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

**Проблема:** довольно часто автор вопроса самостоятельно находит решение, и даже возвращается к вопросу, **но** приводит решение **не** в виде ответа, а редактируя и дополняя вопрос.

**Решение1:** если со времени последней правки вопроса **автором** прошло больше *энного* количества времени, то при нажатии автором кнопки *править* настойчиво напомнить ему, что «если вдруг» у него есть решение, то лучше оформить его в виде ответа (и сразу ссылку на создание ответа приложить), и заинтересовать дополнительными баллами репутации и «медальками».

**Решение2: (альтернативное или дополнительное)** в той же самой ситуации, если автор всё-таки вносит правку в вопрос, поставить вопрос в какую-нибудь из «проверочных» очередей (может быть, движок позволяет новые очереди создавть без «внутреннего» вмешательства?).

Comment: Реально -- никак. Если у автора нет внутреннего побуждения представить свое решение. А с чего бы оно появилось, если этот сайт не место для дискуссий? Т.е. сейчас, по большому счету, это имеет почти такой же смысл, как разговор с зеркалом (или публикация своих заметок в пастебине).

Comment: @avp Я стараюсь оставлять комментарий вида "По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам." В некоторых случаях автор действительно размещает достаточно толковый ответ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, спасибо, возьму на заметку.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, это верно. Но вряд ли именно такой комментарий *заставляет* ТС делать еще и ответ. Вы ему просто подсказываете, что такая возможность есть (в любом случае хорошо), а на публикацию своих изысканий он уже изначально нацелен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**решение1:** если со времени последней правки вопроса **автором** прошло больше *энного* количества времени, то при нажатии автором кнопки *править* настойчиво напомнить ему, что «если вдруг» у него есть решение, то лучше оформить его в виде ответа (и сразу ссылку на создание ответа приложить), и заинтересовать дополнительными баллами репутации и «медальками» (хотя бы напомнить о знаке [*самоучка*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) и о том, что за принятый ответ начисляется 15 баллов (**upd** оказывается, за ответ на свой вопрос — не начисляется, как подсказывают в комментариях)).

Comment: Плюшка уже есть, медалька "self-learner". Репутацию за это давать - потенциально открывать путь к накрутке рейтинга, хотя одноразовые +5 в случае выхода ответа в плюс - возможный вариант.

Comment: @Vesper, я в курсе. видимо, надо переформулировать решение: я-то имел ввиду — **напомнить** о «плюшках и печеньках».

Comment: Кстати, за принятый ответ баллы не идут, если сам свой принимаешь. Проверял на serverfault, например. Даже +2 не дают за accept.

Comment: @Vesper, спасибо за информацию. по-моему, это несправедливо. по крайней мере для новичков.

Answer (score 1):

**решение2: (альтернативное или дополнительное)** в той же самой ситуации, если автор всё-таки вносит правку в вопрос, поставить вопрос в какую-нибудь из «проверочных» очередей (может быть, движок позволяет новые очереди создавть без «внутреннего» вмешательства?).