# Голосовалки за сложность вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы

На ru.SO, как на других сайтах SE, встречаются вопросы разного уровня сложности. Баланс по количеству и активности в зависимости от уровня сложности [нарушен в сторону простых вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/615/32432) по мнению некоторых участников.

Для решения данной проблемы я предлагаю:

1. Ввести квоты места на главной странице для разных уровней сложности, например, не более 50% сложных, не более 90% средних и не более 40% простых;
2. Разрешить фильтрацию вопросов по уровням сложности.

Физически на сайте сохранится дисбаланс, но выглядеть это будет, как будто бы больше средних и сложных вопросов.

---

Уровень сложности - субъективная характеристика, поэтому для его определения предлагаю добавить голосование за уровень вопроса. Предлагаю две модели для голосования:

1. Простая. Пользователи оценивают насколько сложный вопрос *для этого сайта*. Каких голосов больше, такой и уровень у данного вопроса;
2. Сложная. Пользователи оценивают насколько сложный вопрос *для них лично*, также по вопросам и ответам оценивается "уровень сложности пользователя", и по алгоритму типа PageRank выводится вероятный объективный уровень сложности вопроса (то есть если эксперт сказал "средне", то это, наверное, сложный вопрос; если новичёк - то простой).

Предлагаю следующие категории сложности:

1. Простая - "новичковые" вопросы, доступные напрямую в документации. Вопросы по базовой терминологии, "очевидные" примеры использования API;
2. Средняя;
3. Сложная - "мини-исследования". Малое количество пользователей может понять этот вопрос или что-либо предложить.

Категория сложности ≠ качество вопроса. Возможно, голосование за категорию следует открывать только при голосовании вверх за вопрос.

Открытые вопросы:

1. Что делать при редактировании вопроса?
2. Какой вес при голосовании у автора вопроса?

Comment: "Песочница" для этого вопроса: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620/32432

Comment: А не приведёт ли это к массовому отсутствию хороших ответов на простые вопросы? Опытные участники просто не будут видеть эти вопросы, а отвечать на них будут неопытные участники. В результате качество контента упадёт.

Comment: Будет невостребованным, мне лень иногда даже просто проголосовать, не то что зачем-то пытаться оценивать сложный это вопрос или простой.

Comment: Кому-то может не лень. Может, если даже 10% от проголосовавших за вопрос будут также голосовать за сложность, будет некоторый эффект на главную страницу.

Comment: @VladD, Не будут видеть только те, кто явно нажал кнопку "развидеть простые вопросы". Остальные будут видеть просто _меньше_ простых вопросов. Ещё можно стили использовать (типа простой вопрос - желтовытый оттенок заголовка, сложный вопрос - синеватый). Это не должно быть два отдельных мира - для простых вопросов и для сложных - просто некоторая степень отдалённости. Как в поезде со спальными вагонами и обычными купе.

Comment: Вопрос просмотрели 50 раз из них 25 имеют право голосовать за сложность 23 просто лень это делать, осталось двое. Один проголосовал за то что вопрос сложный, второй за то что простой. `-Ты дурак! - Нет, ты!` Суровые реалии статистики.

Comment: Интересная идея. Осталось только разбросать уже оцененный вопросы по разным страницам. А для любителей репы (и опасающихся за отсутствие ответов на простые вопросы) можно давать больше очков за ответы *на простые* вопросы (а вот авторам вопросов -- наоборот).

Answer (score 11):

Мне кажется, к сожалению, сама идея ошибочна. Stack Overflow на русском - это сообщество русскоговорящих разработчиков программного обеспечения. Мы все здесь для одного - помогать нашим коллегам знаниями, попутно создавая свободно распространяемую базу прикладных решений.

Предлагаемая реализация выходит за рамки нашей ответственности. Возможно я не верно понял сам вопрос, но сейчас кажется, что идея заключается в том, что теперь участники сообщества должны выступать в роли *судий*, решая кому быть, а кому нет.

**Мы не судьи, никогда ими не были и не будем**.

Участие в сообществе - это просветительная деятельность. Мне кажется, мы выступаем в роли наставников/учителей друг другу. Согласитесь, нельзя знать всего, но научиться можно многому.

Если убрать моральную составляющую, то опять же, на мой взгляд, делить вопросы на сложные и простые - пагубное занятие. Поясню на примере. Мне не просто найти вопрос по [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), который я бы счел действительно сложным, но по [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) для меня любой вопрос сложен, поскольку я ничего не знаю про этот язык. Как уже не раз говорилось, любой вопрос сложный, пока не знаешь на его решения. Если учесть, что вопросы задают только те, кто что-то изучает, можно прийти к выводу, что вопросы всегда будут простыми для опытного профессионала (то есть отвечающего). Мне кажется, тут выбор сводится к тому, что либо знаток хочет помогать коллегами знаниями, либо нет.

---

Все же, возможно, я не верно понял вопрос. Пожалуйста, посмотрите ссылку

- [Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage)

Comment: Я понял этот вопрос несколько по другому. Никто не предлагает *выбрасывать* простые вопросы. Предлагается лишь раскидывать вопросы по нескольким группам (возможно ли технически это осуществить -- другой вопрос). И для новичков, которые хотят узнать что-либо помимо "школьной программы" я вижу в этом только плюс -- задавай такие вопросы, которые попадут в "высшую лигу" и сможешь получить нетривиальные знания.

Comment: @avp, невозможно отделить сложное от простого, т.к. вопрос сложности субъективен. Полностью поддерживаю Nicolas - эта идея нежизнеспособна.

Comment: @ixSci, то что идея не будет реализована я практически не сомневаюсь. А вот с невозможностью оценки сложности -- не согласен. Оценивем же мы тут кликаньем вверх/вниз качество вопросов/ответов. Аналогично и с сложностью, только голоса надо взвешивать репутацией по меткам (и наверное, коэффициент д.б. нелинеен).

Comment: @avp Мне кажется, не получится реализовать какой-либо правильный алгоритм "определения сложности" вопроса. Но важнее, зачем его вообще создавать? Что это даст сообществу, в контексте знаний?

Comment: В контексте знаний, говорите? Возможно это даст больше новых ответов на уже старые (и оцененные, как сложные) вопросы от свежих участников (которые высоко себя оценивают).

Comment: Движок Stack Exchange очень мощный - [можно создать сортировки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+score%3A5+isanswered%3Ano+is%3Aquestion+%5Bc%5D), которые будут создавать примерно ту выборку, про которую вы говорите.

Answer (score 7):

Проблема, которую вы пытаетесь решить - недостаток сложных вопросов на главной. Сейчас на главной странице показывается 14(!) вопросов для незарегистрированных пользователей. И около 50 для зарегистрированных.

Основная цель главной страницы - показать новым посетителям (99% новичкам) - что вопрос тут может задать **каждый**. А совсем не создать эффект "клуба для профессионалов, вход по приглашениям". Ввести перекос на главной в сторону сложных вопросов - это снизить активность. А она и так не зашкаливает.

Comment: Значит нужно несколько страниц, адресуемых с главной.

Comment: Между "клуб для профессиналов" и "консультационный пункт для новичков" есть золотая середина. Поэтому я и предлагаю квоты на процент вопросов по уровням, чтобы было и того, и того.