# Какие подарки и сувениры мы бы хотели?

Tags: обсуждение, сувениры-stackoverflow

Зачастую так случается, что участники сообщества проявляют себя с положительной стороны. На мой взгляд, было бы правильно наградить их интересными сувенирами. Каждое сообщество сети Stack Exchange может самостоятельно определить, какие именно сувениры хотели бы получать участники. Одни из самых любимых подарков являются:

- наклейки;
- футболки;
- блокноты;
- ручки;
- флешки;
- кепки.

Было бы действительно здорово сделать что-то, что будет не просто приятно получить, но и полезно в применении, а также уникально для Stack Overflow на русском!

*Какие сувениры и подарки мы бы хотели?*

Пожалуйста, публикуйте одно предложение сувенира в одном ответе, чтобы другие участники могли голосовать за или против. Не стесняйтесь добавлять изображения с примерами, для более ясного понимания идеи!

Как пример, несколько ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsnSn.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHuqp.jpg)) возможных вариантов сувениров, которые я подготовил для встречи участников сообщества Санкт-Петербурге.

Comment: а цена вопроса какая? захотеть можно и ноут с логотипом SO )

Comment: @BOPOH Тяжело сказать. Поясню на примере. Чехол для ноутбука - скорее да, чем нет, ноутбук - скорее нет, чем да.

Comment: Под рукой нет граф.редактора, поэтому комментарием: кошельки, ремни, шарфы (хз, можно ли сделать шарф с лого) юсб-хабы, мышаки и клавы, в конце концов. Чехол для ноута - это был бы огонь.

Comment: логотип можно нанести ещё и на: рюкзак, сумку, браслет, кольцо, очки (солнцезащитные), визитку, банковскую карту т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @Etki: Так проголосуйте за чехол ) http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/897/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin done

Comment: в тему: [Can I have “real world” badges?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300483/4279)

Comment: палатка было бы круто :)

Comment: Одно осталось неясным - как заслужить себе какой-нибудь сувенир )

Comment: «Слона-то я и не приметил!» :) В англоязычном сообществе Stack Overflow вручаются подарки по достижению репутации. Подарок выбирается самим пользователем. В нашем сообществе мы можем сами себе установить правила. Изначально я думал скорее в контексте встреч или каких-то единичных событий. Хорошая тема для раздумий. Кстати, можно думать и всем сообществом.

Comment: футболка ручка шарф - хорошая идея , отдам в студию что бы сделали

Comment: Привет всем. Скажите, пожалуйста, где я могу заказать нужный мне товар. Например, хочу футболку и рюкзак. Спасибо.

Answer (score 30):

Традиционно - кружки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант еще может быть большая кружка (0.4 или 0.5)... или еще лучше пивная :))

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrbCO.png, только на русском

Answer (score 29):

Футболки.

---

Пример реализации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 23):

Рюкзак

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: или сумка, в т.ч. для ноута, но можно и меньше

Answer (score 20):

Блокноты.

---

Пример реализации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 20):

Внешние аккумуляторы.

---

Пример реализации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кстати, на логотипе ведь 6 полосок - было бы круто их сделать индикаторами заряда. Хотя, наверное, такое дорого выпускать?

Answer (score 19):

Флешки.

---

Пример реализации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 18):

Наклейки.

---

Пример реализации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Также в качестве надписей на наклейках можно использовать медальки.

Comment: @soon Пожалуйста, поясните идею.

Comment: Берем значок (почему-то думал, что их перевели как медальки), к примеру - [Фанат](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55/fanatic) и печатаем его с учетом оформления. Это не обязательно должен быть значок с сайта, но если сохранить стиль, то он будет узнаваем для завсегдатаев. Значки-наклейки могут выступать как дополнение к основной наклейке с логотипом и названием сайта.

Comment: ещё можно крепление как магниты на холодильник, чтобы коллегам напомнить о сайте и [beta медальку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/30/beta) прикрепить.

Answer (score 18):

Шапки и/или шарфики.
Потому что зима близко.

[image: шапка]

Comment: Трон из логотипов не обсуждается? )

Comment: сразу будет видно что это сообщество на Русском языке :) плюс однозначно

Answer (score 17):

Значок (металлический, на булавке). На значке может быть логотип RU.SO + изображение соответствующего знака.

Выдавать за получение особо значимых знаков, например [разных золотых](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold):

- [Сократ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/89/socratic)
- [Легенда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary)
- [Фанатик](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55/fanatic)

Answer (score 14):

Ручки.

---

Пример реализации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 13):

Визуализация варианта с шарфом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 12):

Зонты.

---

Пример реализации.

[image: пример зонтов]

Comment: зонт с невидимой^w нано ручкой!

Answer (score 11):

Сувенирные баночки с конфетами, что-то вроде этого[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 10):

Визитницы, держатели для карточек[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8):

[Чехол для ноутбука](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/879/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8/890#comment2562_879).

Если можно, это было бы очень круто.

Answer (score 8):

Сувенирные **грабли**, if you know what I mean. Можно "грабли с песочком", говорят, нервы успокаивает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Bluetooth-колонки

---

Пример реализации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Штаны и кроссовки!

На встрече сообщества обсуждали, что все делают брендированные майки, но никто не делает штанов. В итоге за штанами приходится все-таки идти в магазин. Поэтому очень желателен вариант штанов-сувенира.

Comment: Так можно выйти и на производство одежды)

Answer (score 6):

В дополнение хотел бы добавить толстовку. Т.к. до сих пор никто не предложил такой популярный сувенирчик. Альтернативный вариант лонгслив или свитшот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Только лучше темную (не марко)

Comment: @avp суть же не в цвете а в самой толстовке, цвет может быть различный)

Answer (score 6):

Появилось на просторах сети с подписью

> "Подарок на НГ от SO"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вполне себе не дурно.

Comment: Хм... А что там на заднем плане написано?)

Comment: @nick_gabpe какая-то копипаста вестимо

Answer (score 5):

Календари (настенные, настольные, карманные)

Answer (score 5):

Бумаги для заметок

Comment: Вы имеете в виду [клеящиеся листы](http://76.img.avito.st/640x480/1737907576.jpg)?

Comment: Да, точно. Я не знал, как сказать Post-it notes на русском)

Answer (score 5):

Аналог кнопок от YouTube за достижения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикольная штука!

Answer (score 4):

**Матрешки**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Платки.

---

Пример реализации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как бандану я бы носил такой )

Answer (score 3):

Силиконовый браслет. Например для носки на мероприятии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Брелок. Был бы отличным вариантом для носки с различными связками ключей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я за матрёшку, где была бы представлена иерархия определённого типа. Например самая большая "object", а в ней наследуемые типы: и чисто русский сувенир и какое-никакое практическое применение :)

Comment: Эм.. Наоборот тогда: object - самый вложенный.

Comment: @Qwerty или так... Мне кажется, что суть понятна. Переформулировать?!

Answer (score 1):

Стикерпак [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У нас есть такой, только физический и с единорогами. =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky огонь!

Answer (score 0):

Чехол на смартфон. Как вариант можно сделать его деревянным с логотипом, как например на варианте с флешкой. Например лимитированная версия для определенной линейки iPhone

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как же те, кто айфоны не любит? (((

Comment: `@Qwertiy`, как же те люди, что не носят рюкзаки?) Это вопрос личности)