# Какова политика Stack Exchange относительно нанесения логотипа на собственные вещи

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow, stackexchange, авторские-права, сувениры-stackoverflow

Навеяно вопросом [Какие подарки и сувениры мы бы хотели?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/879/181472)

Например, я хочу сам себе сделать майку, ноутбук или силовую броню с логотипом StackOverflow или другими узнаваемыми элементами дизайна. Будут ли возражения со стороны Stack Exchange?

О массовом производстве и продаже речь не идет.

Comment: А на территории Украины?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

На территории РФ использование товарного знака в личных целях не подлежит контролю со стороны правообладателя. "Для себя" можно рисовать что угодно на чем угодно.

Comment: А откуда дровишки? Когда я у Николая спрашивал об этом перед организацией встречи в Москве, он сказал, что SE против нанесения логотипов самостоятельно.

Comment: @Suvitruf ГК РФ Статья 1484. Исключительное право на товарный знак - там подробно перечислено все, на что действует товарный знак. Если не вводите товары в оборот и не оказываете услуги - можно хоть всего себя облоготипить.