# Сувенирная футболка

Tags: обсуждение, сувениры-stackoverflow

Ещё до трансформации hashcode в SO была возможность пользователям с 1к+ рейтинга получить футболку с логотипом hachcode.

Я в тот момент был занят переездом и как-то не сложилось. В силе ли сейчас это предложение? Да, я бы мог сам принт сделать, но это совсем не то, вы же понимаете.

Comment: К слову, я предпочёл бы [шапку](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/895/181472). Зима близко!

Comment: Cвежие слухи: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269557/there-should-be-system-to-send-users-gifts-like-free-stickers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот что известно об этом рядовым участникам:

- Сувениры планируются и футболка - один из популярных вариантов. [Какие подарки и сувениры мы бы хотели?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/879/181472)
- Сувениры, бывает, раздаются на встречах сообщества. Обсуждалось в чате, было тут: [Первая встреча сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Санкт-Петербурге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/790/181472)
- В ближайшее время планируется [Встреча сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Москве и Новосибирске](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1838/181472), и в анкете есть вопрос про размер футболки ;)
- Вы в любой момент можете сделать себе сувенир самостоятельно. [Какова политика Stack Exchange относительно нанесения логотипа на собственные вещи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/901/181472). Хотя это совсем не то, согласен.

> «Слона-то я и не приметил!» :) В англоязычном сообществе Stack Overflow вручаются подарки по достижению репутации. Подарок выбирается самим пользователем. В нашем сообществе мы можем сами себе установить правила. Изначально я думал скорее в контексте встреч или каких-то единичных событий. Хорошая тема для раздумий. Кстати, можно думать и всем сообществом.

[Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ 5 окт в 14:13](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/879/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8#comment4222_879)