# Как получить сувенир Stack Overflow?

Tags: поддержка, сувениры-stackoverflow

Увидел тему [Какие подарки и сувениры мы бы хотели?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/879/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8)
У меня хоть и не высокий рейтинг и вообще я относительно недавно начал пользоваться SO, но хотел бы узнать, как можно получить сувенир?)) очень наклейку хочется))

Comment: Сходите в полиграфию да напечатайте себе логотип на клеящейся бумаге. См. также: [Какова политика Stack Exchange относительно нанесения логотипа на собственные вещи](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/901)

Comment: Да это все понятно, можно что угодно распечатать, а вот получить от официально куда приятнее))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Съездил на встречу, получил что хотел)))