# Лучший первый вопрос, лучший ответ и лучшее сообщение, по мнению сообщества

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено

Некоторое время назад мы с вами [обсуждали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/879/), какие сувениры мы бы хотели выпустить для себя, участников сообщества. С другой стороны, до настоящего момента у нас не было особого повода отправлять созданные сувениры. Предлагаю этот повод создать интереса и веселья ради!

Предлагаю вниманию сообщества инициативу – еженедельное соревнование в номинациях:

1. «*Лучший первый вопрос*». Вопрос, имеющий наибольший рейтинг, заданный новым участником сообщества в день регистрации.
2. «*Лучший ответ*». Ответ, набравший наибольший рейтинг.
3. «*Лучшее сообщение, по мнению сообщества*». Наиболее понравившееся участникам сообщение по результатам «голосования звездами» в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) (сообщение – это вопрос или ответ с основного сайта).

Лучший первый вопрос и лучший ответ будут выбираться по понедельникам по данным за предыдущую неделю. Конкурсная неделя считается с 0:01 субботы и длится 7 дней до 23:59 пятницы по Санкт-Петербургу (то есть мы оставляем два дня, чтобы уравнять шансы). Если два сообщения будут иметь одинаковый рейтинг, то лучшим будет признано то, что было опубликовано раньше.

Лучшее сообщение (вопрос или ответ с основного сайта) по мнению сообщества будет выбираться в чате по пятницам. Период номинирования и голосования: с 16:00 до 18:00 по Санкт-Петербургу. Для номинирования сообщения необходимо опубликовать в чате ссылку на вопрос или ответ. Номинировать можно как свои сообщения (если у вас меньше 1К баллов репутации), так и сообщения других участников имеющих также не более 1К баллов репутации. Далее участники сообщества «голосуют звездами» за понравившиеся сообщения. Победителем становится автор сообщения, которое будет занимать наивысшую позицию в боковой панели с наибольшим количеством звезд к 18:00 по Санкт-Петербургу в день голосования. Сувенир вручается как автору номинированного сообщения, так и участнику опубликовавшему ссылку в чате!

[image]
<sub>Пример боковой панели. Если бы мы сейчас выбирали победителя, им бы стал D-side (сообщение от Etki закреплено, то есть в конкурсе не участвует).</sub>

Соревнование начинается… уже началось! Первые победители будут объявлены в ближайший понедельник! Длительность проведения: примерно два месяца.

#### Дополнительно

Спешу также предложить отдельно вручать «приз зрительских симпатий» за вопросы с меткой [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) или [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc), которые будут иметь положительный рейтинг с тремя и более голосами «за» и как минимум одним ответом с положительным рейтингом.

---

Давайте делиться знаниями друг с другом и приятно проводить время: задавайте ваши вопросы, отвечайте и голосуйте за понравившиеся сообщения!

#### Дополнение от @Qwertyi и @A K

Друзья! Приглашаем вас в новую чат-комнату -- "[номинашки](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61455/)", посвящённую обсуждению хороших вопросов и ответов! Подробности в [отдельной теме на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5563/213987).

## Победители

- #### [C 23 июня по 30 июня](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5565/6)
- #### [C 1 июля по 7 июля](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5588/6)
- #### [С 8 июля по 14 июля](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5611/6)
- #### [С 15 июля по 21 июля](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5632/6)
- #### [С 22 июля по 28 июля](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5689/6)
- #### [С 29 июля по 04 августа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5762/6)
- #### [С 5 августа по 11 августа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5763/6)
- #### [C 12 августа по 18 августа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5771/6)
- #### [С 19 августа по 25 августа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5801/6)
- #### [С 26 августа по 1 сентября](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5833/6)

---

На этом мы завершаем соревнование на «лучшее сообщение» лета 2017 года. Большое спасибо всем, кто принимал участие: задавал вопросы и отвечал на них. Без вас лето было бы грустным!

Если у вас есть мысли о том, как улучшить проведение подобных мероприятий в сообществе или замечания по о данном конкурсе, пожалуйста, оставьте ваш отзыв через [форму обратной связи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact) или [напишите мне напрямую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile). Нам важен ваш отзыв!

**Обновление**

15 октября отправил сувениры победителям! Если вы писали мне на почту и вам не пришел сувенир до конца октября, пожалуйста, дайте знать. Будем искать вместе!

Comment: `Ответ, набравший наибольший рейтинг` – нужны ограничивающие условия, иначе безоговорочно победит этот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1813/181472

Comment: По сувенирам: [значки на булавках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/900/181472) будут когда-нибудь?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Как раз сейчас думаем о чем–то интересном. Посмотрю, можно ли значками запастись.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вопросы будут выбираться за определенный срок, то есть заданные на прошлой неделе с субботы по пятницу. Если мы увидем, что что–то идет совсем не так с голосованием в чате, то можно будет его отменить. Как мне кажется, если помнить, что это всего лишь игра, должно получиться весело!

Comment: Про вопросы-то понятно, что на прошлой неделе. А вот ответы какие? Тоже опубликованные на прошлой неделе? Или ответы на вопросы, заданные на прошлой неделе?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, совершенно верно, ответы за тот же период рассматриваются!

Comment: Очень жаль, что номинировать можно только _первые_ посты участников. Мне например на этой неделе очень понравился [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684468/213987) заданный не новичком, думаю, что вопросы от тех, кто чуть подосвоился могут быть и более интересными. Но я так понимаю, что это некоторая короткая стимулирующая акция, которую скоро прикроют. Ещё один вопрос сразу возникает: а есть ли где-то список первых постов именно от новичков, как их выискивать?

Comment: @AK Номинировать можно любые вопросы и ответы, если вы имеете в виду, голосование в чате. Лучший первый вопрос – это отдельная категория. Акция ничего не стимулирует, на самом деле, возможно, кроме нашего с вами интереса к проекту, а направленна на повышение развлекательной составляющей. Для поиска победителей в номинации лучшего первого вопроса я буду использовать [вот этот запрос](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/689027) по SEDE. Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание, это не список первых сообщений, это список вопросов заданных в день регистрации.

Comment: Перечитал ещё раз, нашёл противоречие. Из третьего пункта в списке как будто бы следует, что мы голосуем за вопросы и ответы, которые кто-то запостил в чат. А в примере на скриншоте сообщение D-side не содержит ссылок на вопрос или ответ. Картинка нагляднее, чем текст, поэтому я в первый раз понял так, что мы просто награждаем за самое популярное сообщение в чате.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky также непонятно, зачем ограничение про день регистрации. Вот человек зарегистрировался и читал сайт год-другой, а теперь решил задать вопрос. Чем он хуже того, кто зарегистрировался только ради вопроса?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Картинка нужна лишь чтобы пояснить механику определения победителя. Люди, которые только читают сайт ничем не хуже, чем только что зарегистрированные. Пожалуйста, составьте запрос к SEDE, чтобы включить всех, кого бы вы хотели включить в рассмотрение для вручения сувенира! Буду рад расширить границы конкурса!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, [Ответ, набравший наибольший рейтинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/Для-чего-нужны-свойства/197075#197075).

Comment: Обновил правила по [результатам обсуждения в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38479224#38479224).

Comment: Что-то оглавление запаздывает

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо за замечание!

Answer (score 6):

С радостью спешу объявить победителей за период с 1.07.2017 по 07.07.2017!

#### Лучший первый вопрос и лучший ответ

Автором лучшего первого вопроса становится [@Spark](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/257368/spark): «[Начальное значение Random() в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/687355)». Лучший [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687368) был опубликован к тому же вопросу, за авторством [@tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763/tym32167)!

Рекомендуем обратить внимание и на другие интересные первые вопросы:

- «[Как узнать процент покрытия кода тестами JUnit в IntelliJ IDEA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/686208)»
- «[Размер пакетов от MS SQL не может быть больше 590 байт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/687062)»
- «[Проверка на гласные и согласные буквы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685627)»

И, конечно, прекрасные ответы!

- «[Как узнать процент покрытия кода тестами JUnit в IntelliJ IDEA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/686261)»
- «[Нанооптимизация в цикле for](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685901)»
- «[Статические методы у не статических классов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687035)»

#### Лучшее сообщение по мнению сообщества

По результатам голосования звездами в чате лучшим сообщением на Stack Overflow на русском стал вопрос [@Андрей Миндубаев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/253651/) – «[Как оптимизировать деплой через docker-compose?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/686027)». Вопрос был номинирован участником [@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin).

#### [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

На этой неделе приз зрительских симпатий достается [@TuM0xA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/256946/tum0xa) за вопрос «[Проверка корректности алгоритма, вычисляющего разницу между двумя датами(например длину жизни)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685978)».

---

Поздравляем победителей! Мы свяжемся с вами для уточнения деталей отправки сувениров в ближайшее время.

**С нетерпением ждем новых интересных вопросов и развернутых ответов!**

Answer (score 5):

С радостью спешу объявить победителей за период с 23 июня по 30 июня!

#### Лучший первый вопрос

Автором лучшего первого вопроса становится [@Михаил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/256673): «[Хранение локальных переменных в c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685245/)».

Рекомендую обратить внимание на другие интересные первые вопросы:

- «[Доступ к полям родительского класса (Рефлексия) - C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684951/)»
- «[Ограничить время жизни потока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683534/)»
- «[Как растянуть канвас-бекграунд на всю страницу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685130/)»

#### Лучший ответ

[@A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k) опубликовал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684487) на вопрос «[Хелперы ASP.NET RAZOR MVC5 для использования с using](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684468/)», набравший наибольшее количество голов за на этой неделе.

Еще немножко отличных ответов:

- «[Как защититься от вирусов-вымогателей Petya и Misha?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684683)»
- «[Почему может не работать метод “split”?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/683414)»
- «[В каком случае лучше использовать volatile?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/683965)»

#### Лучшее сообщение по мнению сообщества

По результатам голосования звездами в чате лучшим сообщением на Stack Overflow на русском стал вопрос [@D .Stark](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/238013/d-stark) – «[В каком случае лучше использовать volatile?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/683216)». Вопрос был номинирован участником [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy).

---

Поздравляем победителей! Мы свяжемся с вами для уточнения деталей отправки сувениров в ближайшее время.

**С нетерпением ждем новых интересных вопросов и развернутых ответов!**

Answer (score 4):

С радостью спешу объявить авторов «лучших» сообщений с 15.07.2017 по 21.07.2017!

#### Лучший первый вопрос

Автором лучшего первого вопроса становится [@Bill Joy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/259410/bill-joy) за вопрос «[Тип объекта не известен во время компиляции. Какой механизм выбрать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694300/6)».

Рекомендую обратить внимание на другие интересные первые вопросы:

- «[Как рекурсивно создавать из массива список?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693147/6)»
- «[auto как аргумент функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693442/6)»

#### Лучший ответ

[@Алексей Шиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/) опубликовал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693249/6) на вопрос «[Почему в 2D играх используют раскадровку, а не GIF анимацию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/668971/6)», набравший наибольшее количество голов за на этой неделе.

Еще немножко отличных ответов:

- «[Как сделать необычную рамку при наведении на элемент?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/694387/6)».
- «[Различия методов Find(), FirstOrDefault() при использовании с Entity Framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693150/6)».
- «[Зачем volatile если есть True/False sharing?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693418/6)».

#### Лучшее сообщение по мнению сообщества

По результатам голосования звездами в чате лучшим сообщением на Stack Overflow на русском стал вопрос участника [@Максим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/251099/) – «[Почему в 2D играх используют раскадровку, а не GIF анимацию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/668971/6)». Огромное спасибо [@AK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/), [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/) и все всем всем, кто голосовал!

#### [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

На этой неделе приз зрительских симпатий достается участнику [@Николай Петров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/258897/) за вопрос по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) «[Максимальное количество чисел из массива, сумма которых не превосходит K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692821/6)».

---

Поздравляем победителей! Мы свяжемся с вами для уточнения деталей отправки сувениров в ближайшее время.

**С нетерпением ждем новых интересных вопросов и развернутых ответов!**

Answer (score 3):

С радостью спешу объявить авторов «лучших» сообщений с 08.07.2017 по 14.07.2017!

#### Лучший первый вопрос

Автором лучшего первого вопроса становится [@hteb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/257945/): «[Проблема с шифрованием XOR](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/689959/6)».

Рекомендую обратить внимание на другие интересные первые вопросы:

- «[Как вставить переменную-счетчик в аргумент фу-ии CreateDirectory?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688741/6)»
- «[Работа с Enum в С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/689998/6)»

#### Лучший ответ

[@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) опубликовал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/689929/6) на вопрос «[Выполнить строку как участок кода в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688781/6)», набравший наибольшее количество голов за на этой неделе.

Еще немножко отличных ответов:

- «[Как передать массив строк функции на чистом си?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/689955/6)»
- «[Как сделать градиентную резиновую кнопку с косым краем (в виде трапеции) и закругленными углами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/689925/6)»
- «[Проблема с шифрованием XOR](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/689963/6)»

#### Лучшее сообщение по мнению сообщества

По результатам голосования звездами в чате лучшим сообщением на Stack Overflow на русском стал вопрос участника [@User12367](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/258576/user12367) – «[Подсчет количества ip адресов в диапазоне IPv6?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/691884/6)». Огромное спасибо за номинирование [@A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k) и [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy).

#### [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

На этой неделе приз зрительских симпатий достается [@d-3210](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/258392/d-3210) за вопрос «[Сложение всех элементов массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/691359/6)».

---

Поздравляем победителей! Мы свяжемся с вами для уточнения деталей отправки сувениров в ближайшее время.

**С нетерпением ждем новых интересных вопросов и развернутых ответов!**

Answer (score 2):

С радостью спешу объявить авторов «лучших» сообщений с 22.07.2017 по 28.07.2017!

#### Лучший первый вопрос

Автором лучшего первого вопроса становится [@Ксения Рябинова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260741/), с вопросом «[Ruby on Rails Activerecord - id в модели перепутаны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/696406/6)».

Рекомендую обратить внимание на другие интересные первые вопросы:

- «[Как завершить проект в Android Studio?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/697181/6)»
- «[Что быстрее: обход вектора или обход списка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/698129/6)»

#### Лучший ответ

[@etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki) опубликовал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/697365/6) на вопрос «[Зачем volatile если есть True/False sharing?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692793/6)», набравший наибольшее количество голов за на этой неделе.

Еще немножко отличных ответов:

- «[Как сделать треугольную стрелку под табом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/698541/6)»
- «[Дублирование проверки на null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/698210/6)»
- «[Добавить поле к существующему классу (Attached Properties)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/698473/6)»

#### Лучшее сообщение по мнению сообщества

Голосование не проводили!

#### [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

На этой неделе приз зрительских симпатий по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) достается «обществу анонимных и не зарегистрированных участников» за вопрос «[Как переставить элементы массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/696971/6)».

---

Поздравляем победителей! Мы свяжемся с вами для уточнения деталей отправки сувениров в ближайшее время.

**С нетерпением ждем новых интересных вопросов и развернутых ответов!**

Answer (score 1):

С радостью спешу объявить авторов «лучших» сообщений с 29.07.2017 по 04.08.2017!

#### Лучший первый вопрос

Автором лучшего первого вопроса становится [@NuNumberOne](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/261604/nunumberone): «[Как увеличить буквы в выводе консольного приложения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699375/6)».

Рекомендую обратить внимание на другие интересные первые вопросы:

- «[Как создать очень большой массив объектов (более 10 миллионов) в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699718/6)»
- «[Различные имена типа в объявлении и определении шаблонной функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700263/6)»

#### Лучший ответ

[@Алексей Шиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/) опубликовал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701431/6) на вопрос «[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/6)», набравший наибольшее количество голосов за на этой неделе.

Еще немножко отличных ответов:

- «[Как по координатам найти объект на Canvas'е и переместить его?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699504/6)»
- «[Как сделать numeric из string?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699613/6)»
- «[Исключается ли код неиспользуемых функций при подключении библиотек?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701051/6)»

#### [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

На этой неделе приз зрительских симпатий достается [@adamshakhabov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14935/adamshakhabov) за вопрос по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) «[Алгоритм нахождения суммы степеней с уменьшающим основанием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700420/6)».

---

Поздравляем победителей! Мы свяжемся с вами для уточнения деталей отправки сувениров в ближайшее время.

**С нетерпением ждем новых интересных вопросов и развернутых ответов!**

Answer (score 1):

С радостью спешу объявить авторов «лучших» сообщений с 12.08.2017 по 18.08.2017!

#### Лучший первый вопрос

Автором лучшего первого вопроса становится [@Stan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/263835/stan), за вопрос «[Как сделать функцию более короткой не теряя функционала?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/707113/6)».

Рекомендую обратить внимание на другие интересные первые вопросы этой недели:

- «[Распаковка массива zip архивов в одну папку с переименованием файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706339/6)»
- «[Выполнение кода из textbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705895/6)»
- «[Период десятичной дроби](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/707365/6)»

#### Лучший ответ

[@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) опубликовал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/707361/6) на вопрос «[Существуют ли реальные алгоритмы со сложностью O(1/n)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/707355/6)», набравший наибольшее количество голосов за на этой неделе.

Еще немножко отличных ответов:

- «[Как получить возраст пользователя?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705489/6)»
- «[Выполнение кода из textbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705977/6)»
- «[Программно определить вычислительную сложность неизвестного алгоритма JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705729/6)»

#### [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

На этой неделе приз зрительских симпатий достается [@Artur](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13192/artur), за вопрос «[Существуют ли реальные алгоритмы со сложностью O(1/n)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/707355/6)»

---

Поздравляем победителей! Мы свяжемся с вами для уточнения деталей отправки сувениров в ближайшее время.

**С нетерпением ждем новых интересных вопросов и развернутых ответов!**

Answer (score 1):

С радостью спешу объявить авторов «лучших» сообщений с 19.08.2017 по 25.08.2017!

#### Лучший первый вопрос

Автором лучшего первого вопроса становится [@akp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/264304/akp), за вопрос «[Как сделать другой репозиторий ответвлением в текущем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708667/6)».

Рекомендую обратить внимание на другие интересные первые вопросы:

- «[cannot bind ‘T’ lvalue to ‘T&&’](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708357/6)»
- «[Удаление повторяющихся слов из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709935/6)»
- «[Как определять одиночные нажатия в консоли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708422/6)»

#### Лучший ответ

[@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) опубликовал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708447/6) на вопрос «[Контейнер deque в STL c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708404/6)», набравший наибольшее количество голосов за на этой неделе.

Еще немножко отличных ответов:

- «[Как удалить вредоносный код из сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708326/6)»
- «[Почему в играх непостоянная кадровая частота (FPS)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/707873/6)»
- «[cont = cont++ не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708057/6)»

#### [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

На этой неделе приз зрительских симпатий достается участнику [@Pavel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/224866/pavel) за вопрос «[Ускорить поиск строк в массиве с длинной меньше средней](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709111/6)».

---

Поздравляем победителей! Мы свяжемся с вами для уточнения деталей отправки сувениров в ближайшее время.

**С нетерпением ждем новых интересных вопросов и развернутых ответов!**

Answer (score 0):

С радостью спешу объявить авторов «лучших» сообщений с 05.08.2017 по 11.08.2017!

#### Лучший первый вопрос

Автором лучшего первого вопроса становится [@Данила Никонец](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/263019/) за вопрос «[Вращение блока при движении мышкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/704299/6)».

Рекомендую обратить внимание на другие интересные первые вопросы:

- «[Как создать собственную асинхронную процедуру в 1С?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/703319/6)»
- «[Приведение double к float в C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/704038/6)»
- «[Как лучше наследовать обычный класс от дженерика в С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/703872/6)»

#### Лучший ответ

[@Abyx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177684/abyx) опубликовал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/702455/6) на вопрос «[Сопрограммы в С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/702454/6)», набравший наибольшее количество голосов за на этой неделе.

Еще немножко отличных ответов:

- «[Микросервисная архитектура Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/703004/6)»
- «[Как начать делать текстовый квест?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/703186/6)»
- «[Что означает O(n^{2}). в описании сложности алгоритма?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/704032/6)»

#### [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

На этой неделе приз зрительских симпатий достается [@Vladislav Osipenkov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/216588/vladislav-osipenkov) за вопрос «[Что означает O(n^{2}). в описании сложности алгоритма?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/704009/6)».

---

Поздравляем победителей! Мы свяжемся с вами для уточнения деталей отправки сувениров в ближайшее время.

**С нетерпением ждем новых интересных вопросов и развернутых ответов!**

Answer (score 0):

С радостью спешу объявить авторов «лучших» сообщений с 26.08.2017 по 01.09.2017!

#### Лучший первый вопрос

Автором лучшего первого вопроса становится [@user265506](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/265506/user265506): «[Массив целых чисел: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/712989/6)».

Рекомендую обратить внимание на другие интересные первые вопросы:

- «[о принципе работы into into](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/711291/6)»
- «[Как работает selectionArgs в android и SQLite?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/711494/6)»
- «[Как отменить подавление ошибок в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/712632/6)»

#### Лучший ответ

[@Zergatul](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/9784/zergatul) опубликовал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/712909/6) на вопрос «[if \ else vs. switch \ case в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444383/6)», набравший наибольшее количество голосов за на этой неделе.

Еще немножко отличных ответов:

- «[Большое ли преимущество использования IN вместо множества OR в sql?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/712755/6)»
- «[Почему при сложении byte не переполняется?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711856/6)»
- «[Как узнать о поддержке браузером CSS свойства?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710802/6)»

#### [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

На этой неделе приз зрительских симпатий достается [@rudolfninja](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/219041/rudolfninja) за вопрос «[Описать прямоугольник вокруг контура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/711623/6)».

---

Поздравляем победителей! Мы свяжемся с вами для уточнения деталей отправки сувениров в ближайшее время.