# Чат "номинашки"

Tags: обсуждение

Сегодня на нашем сайте появилась новая чат-комната — "[номинашки](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61455/)".

Возникла она по следам конкурса "[Лучший первый вопрос, лучший ответ и лучшее сообщение, по мнению сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5540/213987)": Николас предложил еженедельно выбирать хорошие посты и награждать самых-самых на пятничном голосовании в чате.

Изначальный автор идеи с отдельным чатом — @Qwerty, а потом я приложил руку  к идеологии.

Этот чат создан для того, чтобы кидать в него ссылки на вопросы и ответы, которые вы считаете хорошими и качественными. Увидели на сайте вопрос, понравился он вам — киньте ссылку в этот чатик.

Мы думаем, что такой способ поиска хороших постов будет занимать гораздо меньше времени, в фоновом режиме. Кроме того, отдельный чат даёт возможность обсудить с другими людьми эти вопросы — действительно ли они хороши настолько, что достойны номинации, какие посты более интересны и чем.

Итог, который хочется достичь — это:

1. Выстроить дополнительный механизм привлечения внимания к хорошим постам. (Это чем-то сродни тому, что делает NickVolynkin — привлекает запуском конкурсов внимание к интересным вопросам). Хорошие вопросы и ответы должны поощряться — и ссылки на действительно хорошие посты принесут их авторам дополнительные баллы репутации.
2. Создать живой чат с экспертным сообществом, которое будет давать свою оценку материалам сайта. Не секрет, что действительно живая комната по факту одна — общий чат, а [в тематических чатах очень мало постоянной аудитории](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3983/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82). Я надеюсь, что "номинашки" будут постоянно привлекать и постоянных авторов и новичков в комнату и вокруг интересных вопросов и ответов будут складываться и интересные дискуссии.

Попробую заранее ответить на некоторые вопросы в форме FAQ:

В: Означает ли создание этого чата, что на номинацию в пятницу можно будет выставлять только те посты (вопросы и ответы), которые уже были в чате?

О: Нет, это необязательно. Вполне возможны ситуации, когда хороший вопрос проглядели или не закинули в чат для номинирования.

В: Нужен ли какой-то специальный формат сообщения в чат или достаточно просто кинуть ссылку?

О: Достаточно просто кинуть ссылку. Если вы не торопитесь и у вас есть немного времени — можете в следующем сообщении пояснить, чем вам нравится вопрос и почему он достоин номинирования.

В: Голосование недели осуществляется звёздами в основном чате, может быть стоит и в чате для номинаций устраивать некоторое предварительное голосование, этакие "праймериз"?

О: В принципе, мы такое не планируем, но если сообщение действительно хорошее — то возможно, найдутся желающие приколоть звездой действительно выдающийся пост, чтобы не потерялся.

Если у вас есть вопрос, который вы хотите задать по этой теме — можете написать в комментариях к [посту на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5563/213987) (и возможно, ответ попадёт также и в текст FAQ), либо задать в [самом чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61455/).

Comment: Мне нравится этот чат. Буду в него заглядывать в поисках интересных вопросов, на которые можно назначить конкурс.

Comment: Привет из будущего. Инициатива не взлетела, чат в очередной раз замёрз.