# Знак "Фанатик" по-моему не совсем корректен

Tags: обсуждение, знаки, фанатик

> Фанатик: Посещать сайт ежедневно в течение 100 дней подряд. (Учёт дней
> по UTC.)

1. Из Википедии:

   > Фанати́зм (греч. Φανατισμός, лат. fanatismus — от fanaticus «фанатик» — от fanum «священное место», «храм»[1]) — слепое, безоговорочное следование убеждениям, особенно в религиозной, национальной и политической областях; доведённая до крайности приверженность каким-либо идеям, верованиям или воззрениям, обычно сочетающаяся с нетерпимостью к чужим взглядам и убеждениям. Отсутствие критического восприятия своих убеждений. Фана́тик — фанатичный человек (в прямом и фигуральном смыслах). Фанатизм - отсутствие разума.
2. Google-картинки выдают в основном фашистов со свастикой.
3. Простите, но я не фанатик. Прошу как то убрать у меня этот значок. Спасибо.

Comment: нечего было _слепо, безоговорочно следуя убеждениям_ заходить на сайт каждый день  в течение **100 дней подряд**

Comment: Это фича. Сами носим.

Comment: Помнится была идея ещё сделать значки на булавках. Предлагаю "фанатик" в первую партию включить. [Идея не нова](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/879/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8/900#comment2567_887).

Comment: Нет, не оскорбительно. Иронично.

Comment: Мало того что назвали фанатиком, так и ещё и минусов понаставили.

Comment: Минусы на Мете на репутацию не влияют. Не переживайте.

Comment: Меня как-то назвали кнопкатыком в комментариях. И я себе поставил это в качестве имени на месяц. (Окей, было б меньше, если б система не заставила, но всё же.) Все знатно повеселились. Здоровая доза самоиронии ещё никому не мешала :)

Comment: Фанатик?  Каждый понимает данное значение по мере своей испорченности))))  Лично я фанатик, а то что google выдает такой ответ, это проблемы гугла, а не мои...

Answer (score 18):

Я начал писать в комментариях, а потом решил оставить ответом.

Я — один из тех, кто поставил минус. Поставил — за истерику и неадекватное поведение.

Наверное я не очень толерантно высказался, но я думал, что взрослый человек понимает, что такое "переносное значение", "ирония", а также в курсе термина "геймификация". Играя, дети получают новое знание, взрослым игра не даёт заскучать на работе и делает её интереснее.

Судя по тому, что набрали 1к репутации -- вы умеете давать полезные ответы и задавать интересные вопросы, будет жалко, если вы уйдёте.

Я не буду иронизировать на тему "чем вы раньше думали, когда сто дней подряд заходили на сайт", потому что видел людей, которые делали татуировку, а спустя некоторое время решали её свести.

В медали этой нет ничего плохого. На нашем сайте она означает лишь то, что человек настолько сильно увлёкся сайтом, что без перерыва сидел на нём сто дней (ну, есть и те, кто целенаправленно вымучивал и таки нафармил).

Я думаю, что в тему ещё придёт кто-либо из администрации и даст ответ, можно ли "свести тату" и убрать медаль. Надеюсь, что при любом варианте ответа вы всё же останетесь с нами и продолжите давать ответы, не гоняясь и не отвергая знаки и медали.

Comment: Ждём знака ["Реверс"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) по текущему обсуждению.

Comment: @alexolut и на этот раз оно даже не по мою душу)

Comment: @Regent ушла эпоха ... :)

Comment: " что без перерыва сидел на нём сто дней" а я бота на это дело поставил)