# Строим «город знаний» вместе!

Tags: поддержка

Участвуя в Stack Overflow на русском, мы возводим «город знаний». Важнейшей задачей при его построении является создание окружения, в котором вместо ссор жители будут создавать ценность. Окружение - это архитектура сайта, его функционал и правила. Ценностью являются знания, а самый главный движущий элемент системы - это участники сообщества.

Одни города «цветут», становясь центром республик, а другие блекнут и со временем умирают. Какая судьба ждет наш «город знаний», зависит исключительно от добродетели нашей и наших коллег. Именно сообщество русскоязычных разработчиков делает Stack Overflow на русском таким, каким он выглядит, за счет активного участия в обсуждениях на Мете и, конечно же, помощи в решении технических задач.

Важность Stack Overflow на русском, как и аналогичных проектов, например Википедии на русском, сложно переоценить. Ведь ваши ответы - это не просто помощь коллегам здесь и сейчас, это свободно распространяемая база прикладных решений на русском языке, которая доступна каждому пользователю сети Интернет. Язык в этом случае имеет грандиозное значение.

Обычно люди действуют по принципу «минимально и достаточно». Для того чтобы объясняться с большинством других людей, живущих рядом, нам достаточно знания одного языка. Действительно, в мире есть слишком много интересностей (программирование, например), чтобы тратить время на изучение нескольких языков. Выучив язык, мы переходим к изучению интересующих нас разделов знаний. Это может быть: математика, физика, химия, биология или литература. Здесь наступает переломный момент - сколько достоверных качественных источников информации может найти учащийся в пространстве языка на момент изучения?

Наличие знаний ведет к созданию новых идей и ценностей, а как результат - к новым открытиям и новым знаниям. Их отсутствие - к отставанию в образовании и, что хуже, негативному отношению к своему языку и всем его носителям (мы не раз сталкивались с самокритикой в отношении русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков от самого сообщества).

*Но ведь забота о «качестве жизни в городе знаний» - личная задача жителей!*

В конечном счете каждое поколение ответственно за интеллектуальное наследие, которое оно передаст следующему. Более того, многие из нас на протяжении всей жизни продолжают интересоваться чем-то новым, постоянно пополняя свой «багаж знаний». Мы, так же, как и те, кто только делает первые шаги в профессии, постоянно чувствуем свою зависимость от размера базы знаний в нашей языковой нише и от ее содержания. Если раньше такая база знаний была спущена сверху (мы все учились по одним и тем же книгам), то сегодня каждый из нас имеет уникальную возможность поделиться с сообществом тем, что интересует именно нас, теми знаниям, которыми мы обладаем! Мы вместе создаем и управляем нашим «городом знаний»!

Создание ценности на порядок сложнее и ответственнее поддержки. Первые жители «города знаний» не просто подготавливают землю для будущих «поселенцев», в их руках ответственность за большинство создаваемых правил и принимаемых решений (например, вводимый нами технический термин сегодня, завтра может использовать вся индустрия). Именно благодаря таким же первооткрывателям, благородно возводящим Stack Overflow на русском, когда-то был заложен Stack Overflow на английском, который теперь имеет [более десяти миллионов вопросов](https://stackoverflow.com/10m).

Сегодня наш «город знаний» - это небольшой цветущий островок в океане Рунета и ему особенно нужна ваша помощь! Тот город процветает, где живет больше достойных людей. Многим из наших коллег часто не хватает руки помощи в виде готового решения, которое можно найти через поисковик. И мы в силах им помочь! Пожалуйста, предлагайте вашим коллегам и друзьям задавать их технические повседневные вопросы на Stack Overflow на русском. Чем больше интересных вопросов они зададут, тем больше развернутых ответов мы сможем опубликовать и тем богаче будет пространство русского языка. Именно для этого и создан Stack Overflow на русском: помогать нашим товарищам, попутно создавая базу многократно используемых прикладных решений.

Достичь новых высот мы можем исключительно вместе, всем русскоязычным сообществом разработчиков программного обеспечения и системных администраторов.

---

Stack Overflow на русском - это то место, которое мы, сообщество, создаем для себя. Если вы имеете четкое видение того, как сделать сайт лучше, пожалуйста, публикуйте ваши идеи в виде [вопроса на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/)! В частности, если вы считаете, что сообществу стоит решить какую-то конкретную задачу, для того чтобы перейти на следующий этап развития, пожалуйста, опубликуйте ее в [соответствующем вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/955/). Если у вас есть замечания по существующему окружению, обратитесь [к этому вопросу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/594/).

Уверен, сообщество Stack Overflow на русском будет радо видеть как можно больше интересных идей и, конечно же, новых участников, задающих интересные вопросы. Повышение уровня образования русскоязычных разработчиков программного обеспечения, увеличение производительности труда и результирующее качество самого труда являются отличными стимулами для продолжения работы над нашим «городом знаний»!

Comment: Раз уж Вы (без очевидного повода) помянули Википедию, позвольте поинтересоваться: где взглянуть на Ваш вклад там?

Comment: На мой взгляд, чтобы упоминать Википедию, не обязательно  публиковать на ней статьи. Если проект нравиться, уверен, каждый вправе обсуждать его с товарищами. Все же, отвечу на ваш вопрос. Хоть я и верю в огромную пользу Википедии, но не разделяю точки зрения на модерирование публикуемого содержимого. Те несколько статей, что я опубликовал, были либо урезаны или удалены, как результат, мой текущий вклад минимален.

Comment: Ваш ответ меня, в принципе, удовлетворил. На будущее: следите за формами возвратных глаголов русского языка (особенно в третьем лице). Больше претензий к Вам не имею.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, а были прям претензии? ))

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: я заметил, что, при всех ваших знаниях, стиль общения у вас довольно резкий. Возможно, так принято на Википедии, но не здесь.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я так же заметил, что при прочих возможных знаниях *IncnisMrsi*, его редакторские правки на этом ресурсе приходится переисправлять в части правил русского языка, что тем более не извиняет выбранный им тон, позволяемые себе замечания о формах возвратных глаголов и прочих "претензиях" ..

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы некоторые (не будем тыкать в них пальцем) участники сообщества воздерживались от использования фраз в стиле командного тона. По моему мнению, комментарии подобного рода чаще всего отталкивают от форума новичков, не готовых участвовать в словесных баталиях, что явно не на благо сообществу (если конечно мы не хотим получить на выходе группу "всевышних" с задранными носами).

Comment: @margosh: соглашусь. Кратко: за меритократию, против демагогии. )

Comment: Товарищи, вы молодцы!

Comment: @StrangerintheQ: так и вы тоже, дело-то общее)