# Как создать русскоязычный сайт на StackExchange?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, stackexchange

Задаю этот вопрос здесь, т.к. сайт успешно продолжает работу, несмотря на то, что официальная позиция [такова](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-se-2-0-sites-edition).
Сегодня нами была предпринята [попытка](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90963/electronic) создать русскоязычный Q-A по электронике. Как можно догадаться - неудачная. В то-же время, в этом имеется насущная необходимость и мы уверены, что смогли бы организовать работу сообщества на высоком уровне.

А ведь есть ещё несколько активных русскоязычных тематических сообществ, в которых до сих пор, по привычке, продолжается складирование полезнейших ответов в отстойниках форумов и ЖЖ.

Неужели для всех них нет альтернативы на данный момент, кроме поднятия своего движка?

Как долго может продолжаться эта странная политика администрации и с чем на самом деле это может быть связано?

Comment: Вопрос скорее на мету SE. Тут вряд ли кто-то сможет донести позицию администрации всей сети SE.

Comment: По моему проще самому поднять на отдельном движке, чем убеждать кого-то там сделать электронику на русском, в стенку головой бьетесь.

Comment: Попытка не пытка. Затраты на создание такого сайта весьма высоки, свободных движков достойного уровня - нет. А выхлоп, до раскрутки на первые строки в google, весьма мал. Хэш ведь тоже переехал сюда - на это были причины.

Comment: Насколько я знаю из официального заявления SE, на момент когда они задумались о создании локальных SO-сообществ, ХК был самым солидным клоном в русскоязычном сегменте. Поэтому они и предложили.

Comment: Да, только после переезда кое-какие остатки http://sezn.ru были утеряны и теперь мы не можем легко без какой-то связи c SE создавать новые тематические сайты . Например [математика](http://math.hashcode.ru/) так до сих пор там и болтается и на русском её не предвидится на новом движке.

Comment: И как же предполагается теперь с ней быть? Симптоматично, что входа с главной уже нет, его заменил редирект на SO...

Comment: Понятия не имею, так и будет на старом движке работать наверное. Я вам поэтому и говорю что проще поднять свой движок, допилить какой-нибудь опенсорсный или у @Nicolas Chabanovsky попросить старый хэшкодовский.  sezn.ru закрыт из-за переезда сюда, а на SE локализованные сайты не создают если там 3.5 пользователя и 2 вопроса.

Comment: Думаю, что тем, кто тратил время на ответы и своим трудом зарабатывал репутацию этому сайту, несколько обидно такое положение дел. C'est la vie, конечно. 
А не создают как бы вообще. Но при этом вроде бы собираются, и понятно, что этим кильнут любые локальные сообщества, но когда - непонятно. Странно это, отсюда и мой вопрос.

Comment: Нормальное положение, зачем тратить время и ресурсы на поддержку мелких локальных сообществ, когда есть огромное основное, просто поглотившее все остальное. Глобализм конечно довольно мерзкая штука, но ничего не поделаешь, приходится иметь с ним дело.

Comment: Всё верно. Конечно, уже почти оффтопик, но вот вижу я, к примеру, что, несмотря на наличие ютьюб, торренты таки незаменимы и процветают, а глобализму приходится бороться с ними силовыми средствами. Вот и в нашей сфере наверняка появится свой децентрализованный аналог умного рейтинга SE -  вопрос времени. Вангую, что странная политика менеджмента SE этот момент ускорит.

Comment: Какой умный рейтинг? В вебе уже лет 10 если не больше полно средств для оценки контента пользователями вроде кармочки/лайков/фоллоуми. Только вот на деле это ничего не дает. Если что-то сильно заплюсовано скорее всего это либо что-то скучное, давно известное, смешное и бесполезное, либо чьи-то сиськи.

Comment: я же и говорю - умный, smart, не просто плюсик, нет. Это не работает конечно. А вот например: https://github.com/snordenstorm/wiki/wiki/%5BRussian%5D-White-Paper

Comment: Децентрализованные социальные сети на основе blockchainа? Зачем? Железо то все равно никак не децентрализуешь. В итоге она все равно будет децентрализованно болтаться в централизованном дата-центре, построенном за все те же доллары, а не BTC.

Comment: А вообще что-то мы заболтались, если хотите что-то обсудить заходить в [местную флудилку](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23460) или [основной чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462).

Answer (score 9):

Общий процесс создания сайта вопросов и ответов на русском языке ничем не отличается от других. Для этого следует использовать сайт «[Зона 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)».

#### Позиция относительно новых сайтов на языках отличных от английского

С очень большой вероятностью, такие заявки будут закрываться.

#### Почему и как поступить?

*Почему?*

Причины подробно расписаны в упомянутой вами статье. Из своего опыта спешу добавить.

1. Запустив, например, 5 сообществ без заинтересованных энтузиастов, мы получим не много не мало 5 мертвых сайтов.
2. Сеть Stack Exchange развивалась по модели деления на более мелкие сообщества, если в одном крупном становилось «тесно», то есть набор рассматриваемых тематик выходил за пределы основного сайта, но участники были крайне заинтересованны в создании знаний по ним. Перефразирую. Чтобы запустить успешный сайт по электронике на русском языке, согласно опыту компании, в сообществе Stack Overflow на русском должно быть большое количество ребят (и конечно же девушек) заинтересованных данной темой. В понимании компании, интерес проявляется в конкретных вопросах и ответах.

*Как поступить?*

На мой взгляд, есть два шага, которые должны привести нас, русскоговорящих специалистов разных профессий, к той же объемной базе знаний, что есть на английском.

1. Создать как минимум одно больше дружное сообщество. Предполагаю, им, скорее всего, может стать Stack Overflow на русском, хотя [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) по многим параметрам выглядит «сильнее» (точнее выглядел, [пока не сломался Яндекс](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/875/)). [Чем больше интересных неординарных коллег будут частью сообщества, тем выше наши шансы на успех.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1146/)
2. Начать задавать вопросы по электронике на основном сайте, если сообщество не будет против. Я, как человек, начавший свою карьеру в ИТ с сервис центра по ремонту КПК и сотовых телефонов, абсолютно положительно отношусь к данной тематике. Если из 100 публикуемых в день вопросов, например, 5 будут на тему электроники, возможно, никто не будет против.

Таким образом, для запуска сообществ на русском языке, нам необходимо сначала «поставить на ноги» нашего «первенца». Уверен, это можно сделать только всем русскоязычным сообществом разработчиков, именно так было создано англоязычное. Затем, собрать группу энтузиастов внутри Stack Overflow на русском, и начать задавать вопросы.