# Что такое "вопрос-опросник"?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Что неоднозначно в вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452712 и почему это "вопрос-опросник"?

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/642/31258

> "Если вопрос интересный и полезны, коллега с радостью поможет нам. Если же мы подойдем к нему/ней с вопросом на вроде "где скачать библиотеку", уверен, ответ если и будет, то очень грубый. В первом случае - это профессиональное общение, во втором мы просто отвлекаем человека от работы."

Я не чувствую разницы. Ведь в интернете - не нравится, не отвечай.

Comment: `Привет посоны, посоветуйте дистрибутив линукс и тему диплома. На чем лучше делать C# или Java? С меня как обычно.` Некоторых это раздражает, мне вот вообще все равно.

Comment: Qubes OS, верифицированные GLL-парсеры,  на F*, bitcoin:1928Qk3Mw7RM4nKVHs3AzYrMebUBnVvg4H, в чем проблема просто ответить (или не ответить)?

Comment: С таким же успехом можно ответить: `Finnix, разработка 3D игры по Bocu no Pico на Petooh`. И все Ваши попытки доказать мне почему Ваши парсеры интереснее и полезнее будут тщетны. Поэтому такие вопросы и не любят.

Answer (score 7):

Решение задачи, особенно, если оно абстрагировано до некоторого общего решения,  не теряет своей актуальности со временем.

Чего не скажешь о выборе библиотеки, который актуален только на момент постановки вопроса. Спустя некоторое время появятся библиотеки лучше, ссылки в принятом ответе перестанут работать, и ответ потеряет свой смысл.

В этом и разница.

> Ведь в интернете - не нравится, не отвечай.

SO - не типичный форум, цель которого помочь отдельно взятому человеку с его проблемой. Цель SO - сохранить знания и опыт, которые будут полезны широкой аудитории в будущем.

PS. Вопрос про калькулятор был бы оффтопиком, даже если бы не был опросником, т.к. не связан с программированием, настройкой серверов, вот с этим всем.

Comment: а если интервал времени взять по-больше, то вообще смысла трепыхаться нет. потому что всё течет, всё меняется.

Comment: Верно, но это другая крайность. И тут каждый выбирает для себя баланс. У SO есть определенные принципы, которые призваны поддерживать уровень качества в рамках той цели, к которой SO стремится.

Comment: Если @hse5yzdx и сотни подобных ему уйдут с ресурса (и другим сюда дорогу закажут) кому-то (наверное пргрессивному программирующему человечеству) и впрямь станет лучше? Могу только сказать еще раз -- ценность данного ресурса (и en.SO тоже) не в накоплении некой базы знаний, **полезной для всех**, а в **быстрых ответах** (быстрее, чем решить самому) на вопросы *конкретных людей*. (а "база знаний" (с тоннами копипасты) это уже побочный продукт)

Comment: @avp, У меня вот обратный опыт. Всего пара моих вопросов на en.so, но неисчислимое множество случаев, когда на en.SO я находил подробные разъяснения, полезный код, грязные хаки и быстрые решения вида "stacktrace →  ответ".

Comment: @avp, да нет этих сотен. Раз в месяц кто-то ворчит и хлопает дверью, что его ожидания не оправдались. Но нельзя соответствовать ожиданиям неограниченного множества людей. Водитель автобуса не может исполнить все прихоти пассажиров - ему нужно в пункт назначения попасть, иначе в следующий раз пассажиры на нем не поедут. И да в автобусе нельзя плевать семечки на пол и играть на гармони. Но если знаешь, что автобус точно довезет в пункт назначения, можно и потерпеть.

Comment: ну окей, покажи мне каким запросом найти ответ на мой конкретный вопрос. Если ответа нет, то как ты думаешь, почему так?

Comment: @hse5yzdx, либо об этом никто еще не спрашивал, либо кто-то спрашивал, но оффтопик был удален.

Comment: А я не говорю про конкретные ошибки вида "stacktrace → ответ". Да, на них отвечают. А спросить что-то более абстактное (или как в случае с @hse5yzdx не популярное (кстати, я тоже не знаю ответа на его вопрос, но это ведь не означает, что его *никто не знает*)) стало проблематичным. Тут же обругают и закроют вопрос. Действительно *соответствовать ожиданиям* всех невозможно, но не стоит и лишать надежды получить ответ тех из них, чьи вопросы непонятны десятку активистов (фиг-то уж с ним, с процентом отвеченных вопросов на пути из бэты, что IMHO и движет большинством "закрывателей")

Comment: @avp: мной движет не процент, а желание видеть конструктивные ответы. Смотреть на перепалку адептов разных языков и библиотек нет желания, вчитываться в карьерные страдания — тоже.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не нравится -- не смотрите, просто пройдите мимо.

Comment: @avp, если проходить мимо, то порядка не будет. Сообщество без механизмов саморегуляции быстро станет помойкой. Наверняка ведь вы слышали [про теорию разбитых окон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD)?

Comment: Ага. Только создаваемый в рамках всех текущих правил порядок  сделает сайт отстойником тривиальных ответов на тривиальные вопросы. / @VladD где-то правильно заметил, что вопрос это просто повод блеснуть своими знаниями. Вряд ли многим интересно постоянно демонстрировать их очередному user12345. Их интересно показать людям, которые что-то в самом деле понимают в сложных IT задачах.   Здесь же просто не найдется места для обсуждения подобных вопросов (скорее всего, как не имеющих одного очевидного правильного и т.д. решения). Ну, думаю, дальнейшие рассуждения очевидны.

Comment: @avp, то есть многолетний опыт StackOverflow не показателен?

Comment: Нет. Хотя бы из-за разницы количества участников (в т.ч. потенциальных) на 2 порядка.

Answer (score 6):

> Что такое “вопрос-опросник”?

Так называется категория вопросов, которые являются субъективными и ответ на которые не основан на знаниях и практическом опыте, например:

- [What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/845/56.html)
- [What is your best programmer joke?](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/234/075.html)

На такие вопросы нет однозначно правильного ответа -- кому-то нравится золотой цвет, а кому-то лимонный.

Насколько я понимаю, [официальная позиция, что подобные вопросы ухудшают соотношение сигнал/шум на сайте](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) и привлекают некомпетентных людей, создающих нерабочую атмосферу в обсуждениях.

Я не знаю, насколько такие вопросы вредны или даже полезны (популярность) для небольшого сайта, который в 100 раз меньше большого SO. Правила усиливаются сообществом -- существует заметная инерция к использованию правил с большого SO -- в не зависимости имеет это смысл или нет. Есть движение ослабить некоторые ограничения, например, [Что делать с вопросами в стиле "скажите что почитать"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/23044) Можно задать вопрос на Мете (здесь) о разрешении вопросов в метке `[рекомендация-ПО]` -- чтобы вместо теории, на практике убедиться о фактическом влиянии подобных вопросов на сайт (вопросы, принадлежащие одной метке можно позже убить автоматом, если сильно вредными окажутся).

> Что неоднозначно в вопросе [калькулятор, с учётом размерностей записанных по-русски с падежами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/452712/23044) и почему это "вопрос-опросник"?

Вопрос относится к категории "рекомендация программного обеспечения." (русского сайта [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) нет и в данный момент [нельзя создать в рамках SE](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1253/23044)).  Учитывая, что список ПО, который поддерживает описываемое поведение, скорее всего не является обширным или широко известным, то вопрос является полезным, хотя и не является [строго по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). По теме был бы вопрос о том как реализовать подобную функциональность, такой как, например, для простых арифметических выражений: [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279).

Answer (score 5):

Принцип «не нравится, не отвечай» — не соответствует правилам StackOverflow. Создатели сайта ратуют не только за высококачественные ответы, но и за высококачественные вопросы.

Именно поэтому некорректные вопросы можно закрывать. Ваш вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта, поскольку вы не решаете программную проблему (скорее, пользовательскую) и вам нужен другой ресурс, где сидят другие специалисты, не программисты.

Если бы вопрос касался того, как реализовать подобные требования, он был бы ближе к тематике, но всё равно некорректным, поскольку корректный вопрос требует активной предварительной работы того, кто спрашивает. «Мне нужно то-то, я сделал так-то, но у меня не получилось. Как мне сделать правильно?» — вот вопрос для StackOverflow.

Вопрос также не соответствует правилам, поскольку невозможно понять, корректный ли ответ на него дан. «Какая программа лучше?» — это очень субъективно.

Comment: "вам нужен другой ресурс". Эээ, какой? klerk.ru ? Так они скажут - такой программы нет, идите к программистам.

Comment: @hse5yzdx Любой из StackExchange, который соответствует тематике Вашего вопроса. Например, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/, где можно спросить: "can I use Russian measures in formulas?". Либо любой ресурс, где правила не запрещают свободные обсуждения, например, RSDN.

Comment: @hse5yzdx, вот так, теперь. Вы поняли, что перед тем как что-нибудь тут спросить, надо тщательно изучить проблему (и если Вы все же не нашли ответа), то можно задать этот вопрос здесь, желательно оформив его как выступление на заседании какой-либо Академии Наук.

Comment: "can I use Russian measures in formulas?" - ответят, что традиционно мозги утекают в англоязычные страны, потому что в России много вахтёров. После этого уже для русских ничего не делают и поэтому нет такого софта, который позволяет использовать русский язык в формулах. А на rsdn и lor меня пожизненно забанили по IP за "глупые" вопросы в промышленных количествах.

Comment: @hse5yzdx Если не требуется поддержка падежей/чисел, возможно, Вам подойдёт F# Interactive. Я запускаю его через Visual Studio, но кажется есть возможность найти и запускать `fsi.exe` без студии. Если требуется, то, вероятно, нужно разрабатывать такую программу.

Comment: @hse5yzdx, *"вам нужен другой ресурс". Эээ, какой?* То, что такого ресурса нет, не значит, что можно оффтопить на SO.

Comment: @hse5yzdx *А на rsdn и lor меня пожизненно забанили по IP за "глупые" вопросы* - очевидно та же судьба ждет вас и здесь, Если там вас не "приняли" это не значит, что теперь здесь нужно делать то же самое.

Comment: @avp, *вот так, теперь* — вы явно не правы. задавать можно **любые** вопросы — и элементарные, и явно не относящиеся к тематике сайта. вот только ни одному (**любому**) вопросу **не гарантированы** ни ответы, ни сколько-нибудь долгая «жизнь».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, видно я что-то новое упустил. Разъясните.

Comment: @avp, для того, чтобы задать вопрос (на [ru.so]), не требуется ничего из вами перечисленного. даже с учётом сарказма.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, пофлудить потянуло?

Answer (score 5):

Этот сайт — о разработке ПО и системном администрировании. На нем приветствуются конкретные вопросы о том, как решать ту или иную задачу. Ваш последний вопрос, на который вы ссылаетесь, не удовлетворяет требованиям тематики сайта:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/452712/181472

> Программа должна понимать именно русские слова, записанные в кириллическом алфавите (а не английские слова, записанные латиницей)
>
> поддержка падежей требуется.
>
> можно онлайновую, но лучше бы локальную.

В вопросе нет ни одного собственно вопросительного предложения. Вы в свободной форме изложили требования к некоторому ПО. Ладно, а что дальше, что именно вы хотите?

- Чтобы для вас кто-то нашел это ПО?
- Чтобы для вас кто-то его написал?
- Чтобы мы просто ознакомились с вашими потребностями?

Ничем из этого мы тут не занимаемся. Для поиска ПО есть поисковые машины и сайт Software Recommendations. Для напиания есть биржи вроде Upwork. Для разговоров о насущном есть чат(ы).

В данном случае под не очень ясной формулировкой «опросник» имеется в виду «а есть ли программа Х? Найдите ее за меня».

Вы в каждом вопросе даете большой список литературы, как в научной статье. Скажите, а вы читаете все эти источники? Я свои читаю, даже пишу некоторые.

1. [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
2. [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
3. [Какой тип вопросов лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
4. [Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»? Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)
5. [Какое поведение ожидается от пользователей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)
6. [Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)
7. [В чем значение голосов «за» и «против»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1036/181472)
8. Software Recommendations — [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
9. Wikipedia – [Upwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upwork)
10. Google — [Справка по поиску](https://support.google.com/websearch/?hl=ru&rd=2#topic=3378866)

Comment: "сайт Software Recommendations" - он точно также не работает по тем же причинам, что и здесь

Comment: "конкретные вопросы о том, как решать ту или иную задачу" - окей, конкретная задача - как получить дамп вычислений выражений такого типа на русском языке в традициях российской математики?

Comment: @hse5yzdx: разработать требования, разработать алгоритм, реализовать алгоритм в ПО, оттестировать ПО.

Comment: Зачем здесь, ты в исходном вопросе попробуй ответить. Увидишь, что ответ бесполезный, потому что не содержит конкретики. А другим людям возможно задача понравится и они её сделают для себя.

Comment: @hse5yzdx, речь о чем-то вроде [units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Units), но на русском?