# Причина закрытия: "Вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию"

Tags: предложение, причины-закрытия

Можно ли добавить в раздел "Не по теме" новую причину закрытия: "Вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию (не соответствует теметике сайта)"?

Недавно встретил  в очереди проверок [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/348173/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-linux). Написал комментарий как причину закрытия.  Было бы удобнее, чтобы среди стандартных причин имелось бы что-то подобное.

Comment: Тематика Stack Overflow на русском шире чем "программирование": ["На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Хотя конкретный пример вопроса не вписывается и в тематику указанную в справке.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Поддерживаю.

Т.к. список причин закрытия у нас ограничен (насколько я помню, не больше 5 штук), то предлагаю устранить [существующий дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1370/177221) (который к тому же [сформулирован совсем неоднозначно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1361/177221)):

Убрать причину-дубликат

> Не по теме, потому что… → Вопросы-опросники запрещены на Stack Overflow на русском.

Поставить на ее место

> Вопрос не имеет прямого отношения к программированию или системному администрированию

...примерно в таком виде  он чаще всего встречается в [кастомных причинах закрытия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats).

Comment: Сжечь опросники!