# Требование однозначности ответа

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

В существующих [правилах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) (и скорее всего не только в этом месте) есть весьма сомнительное требование к вопросу -- он не должен допускать неоднозначных ответов.

Там написано:

> необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ

а далее обоснование:

> обсуждения, основанные на различных мнениях – это прекрасно, но они тоже с большой вероятность не подходят для формата вопросов и ответов.
>
> Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Однако, очевидно, что многие нетривиальные вопросы, например:
[Рендер туманности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3030)
[Защита от DDOS атак](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069)
[Системы контроля версий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/113235)
[Фрагментация памяти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180995)
(и многие другие) **не могут иметь однозначный ответ**, поскольку либо допускают несколько правильных решений (а оптимальное зависит от массы факторов), либо предмет вопроса может (и должен) быть рассмотрен с разных сторон для получения правильного представления о нем.

Поэтому предлагаю исключить данную причину из списка тех, по которым вопрос может быть закрыт (удален, уничтожен, задвинут или как-то еще подвергнут репрессиям).

Естественно, это предложение не относится к так называемым *всеобъемлющим вопросам*  (конечно, грань весьма субъективна), на которые вряд ли можно дать ответ разумного (тоже субъективно) размера и уж точно к просто плохим вопросам.

Comment: Я думаю, нужно не исключить, а восстановить первоначальную идею: исключить вопросы наподобие «какое ключевое слово C++ лучше всех» или там «какие могут быть причины падения приложения».

Comment: @VladD, это верно. Только к таким вопросам надо что-то подходящее придумать. Причины падения -- вроде ясно -- это всеобъемлющий, а со любимыми словами... (больше всего подходит "бред" (но, некорректно и т.д.))

Comment: Так ведь "однозначно верный ответ" не означает, что ответ может быть всего один. Это означает, что по любому из ответов можно однозначно сказать, верный он или нет.

Comment: @Regent: Раз это не самоочевидно по тексту, текст нужно улучшить. Если у нас эта формулировка вызывает вопросы, то она вызовет вопросы и у новичков.

Comment: Уже обсуждали, что речь об объективности, а не о единственности ответа. Если об ответе на вопрос нельзя точно утверждать, что он является или не является решением, хотя бы частичным — то ценность этого вопроса и ответа невысока для будущих читателей. Поэтому такие вопросы не входят в тематику сайта. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1368/181472

Answer (score 14):

Я специально прочитал все ответы про системы контроля версий и вот, что я узнал:

- Barmaley не любит Git, но любит SVN. В 2012 году ему нередко приходилось работать через плохой канал вроде GPRS.
- У Barmaley были проблемы с настройкой файрволла для работы Git через порт 9418. Это единственный раз, когда я слышал о проблемах с Git и файрволлом.
- Различные перечисленные фичи не пригодились Barmaley в его работе.
- К 2012му году Barmaley не встретил такого клиента для Git под Windows, который бы ему понравился.
- В 2012 году поддержка Git в Eclipse была хуже, чем поддержка Git в Netbeans, по оценке Barmaley.
- Несколько интересных особенностей работы с системами контроля версий в неизвестной компании, где работает KoVadim
- По наблюдениям KoVadim, быстрее осваивают Git программисты под Android и те, кто пользуется командной строкой.
- Yura Ivanov имел дело с Bazaar
- sys_dev предпочитает Mercurial, а вот Perforce ему совсем не нравится.

И так далее. Поскольку я разбираюсь в вопросе, то могу оценить и отфильтровать информацию. Если бы я был новичком, то скорее запутался бы, прочитав все эти ответы. **По всем темам, в которых я новичок, я бы не хотел натыкаться на такие пространные рассуждения, а хотел бы видеть обоснованные утверждения, понятные инструкции и хорошие иллюстрации**. Поэтому я против вопросов, провоцирующих обмен субъективными мнениями.

Comment: Может быть тогда жесточайший оффтоп про тяжелые отношения Barmaley и GIT стоит просто удалить?

Comment: @PashaPash Nofate его удалил вчера.

Answer (score 8):

"Однозначный" здесь ближе к "объективный" нежели "единственный". То есть существует объективный критерий (например, простой юнит-тест), который мог бы сказать является ли данный ответ правильным или нет.

Ясно, что на один и тот же вопрос можно дать несколько правильных ответов -- поэтому на SO разрешено давать несколько ответов вместо коллективного редактирования одного ответа (cравните с Википедией: одна тема -- одна статья на данном языке). Подкатегория: [Что такое “вопрос-опросник”?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1397/23044)

Возможно необходимо обновить перевод так как я больше не вижу аналога "однозначный" в [английском варианте](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

- **primarily opinion-based** - [discussions focused on diverse opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) are great, but they just don't fit our format well.

  > Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.

Текущий [русский вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

- **необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ** – [обсуждения, основанные на различных мнениях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) – это прекрасно, но они тоже с большой вероятность не подходят для формата вопросов и ответов.

  > Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Вот перевод близко к тексту:

- **необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно правильный ответ** – [обсуждения, основанные на субъективных различающихся мнениях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) – это прекрасно, но они плохо вписываются в наш формат сайта вопросов и ответов.

  > Многие хорошие вопросы могут породить различающиеся мнения, основанные на опыте знатоков, но ответы к этому вопросу имеют тенденцию быть почти полностью основанными на личных мнениях, а не на фактах, ссылках или конкретном опыте.

Если есть идеи по улучшению, не стесняйтесь редактировать перевод (я сделал ответ общим, чтобы облегчить процесс).

Comment: Т.е. Вы считаете, что  разные точки зрения на решение проблемы на данном сайте не допускаются? И те участники, которые **субъективно** чувствуют, что новый вопрос потенциально может вызвать дискуссию должны его превентивно закрыть?

Comment: @avp: разные точки зрения, конечно, допускаются (какая конкретно фраза в моём ответе заставила Вас предположить обратное), если они ведут к верному ответу. Очевидно, что разные решения могут быть основаны на разных trade-offs -- одно решение может быть лучше в одном случае, другое в другом. Не обязательно, чтобы каждый вопрос до последней точки требования бы определял (это не математическая теорема, используйте здравый смысл).

Comment: Согласен. Первый раз невнимательно прочел именно Ваш вариант (в самом конце ответа). Думаю, всюду в правилах (и подсказках  причин закрытия) надо как-то акцентировать, что несколько правильных ответов могут существовать.

Comment: Могу предложить <s>Говоруна</s> императив: **переформулируйте вопрос, чтобы на него существовал объективно верный ответ** — обсуждения различных мнений всегда интересны, но плохо вписываются в наш формат сайта вопросов и ответов. // Ваш вопрос требует выражения субъективного мнения, а не фактов. Переформулируйте вопрос, спросите о чём-то конкретном, или удалите его совсем.

Comment: @VladD: у меня нет предпочтений по поводу перевода. Вы можете прямо в ответ добавить Ваш вариант. Насколько я понимаю только [модераторы и сотрудники компании могут редактировать справку](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/91/23044)

Comment: @VladD я за императив (как обычно)

Comment: @jfs: Всё же мой текст достаточно сильно отличается от вашего, поэтому я не рискнул вносить без вашей санкции такие большие изменения.

Comment: @jfs Я против прямых переводов. Причины две: 1) наша цель создать инструмент, а не предоставит лучший русскоязычный вариант, англоязычного термина, 2) в большинстве своем, подобные текст адаптированы и оптимизированы для того, чтобы донести какую-то мысль наилучшим способом используя наименьшее количество символов. Если их перевести напрямую, смысл очень легко потерять. На мой взгляд, следует как можно более понятно описывать, почему вопросы закрываются, при этом формулировка может полностью отличаться от варианта на английском языке.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: я нигде не говорил, что прямые переводы должны быть использованы, но иногда даже прямой перевод английского варианта может быть лучше текущего варианта. Например, ясно что слово "однозначный" порождает путаницу в данном случае. Я не имею предпочтения по переводу, если он не хуже перевода с английского, например, можно [вариант, предложенный VladD, использовать](http://goo.gl/tzvR67)

Comment: @jfs Во многих причинах закрытия, как и в [шаблонных комментариях](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222/), я старался использовать «выразительные» слова, которые побуждают к действию. Уверен, что они не оптимальны, но на практике именно при таких формулировках мы получали наибольший отклик на ХэшКоде. Я обоими руками за улучшение, которые позволят получить больший отклик участников. Можно создать отдельный вопрос для каждой причины закрытия, собрать варианты и провести AB тесты. Менять формулировки не сложнее, чем сделать запрос количества закрытых вопросов за период.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky:  я понимаю стремление добавить "позыв к действию", но это не имеет отношения к текущему обсуждению о путанице со словом "однозначный" (в любом случае предпочтительно иметь две части: "что не так" + "как исправить", а не только "как исправить"). Существующие вопросы на Мете демонстрируют, что "однозначно правильный ответ" может быть неясен как новичкам (`hse5yzdx`) так и опытным участникам (`avp`). Ясно и без тестов, что текущую формулировку следует заменить. Если нет консенсуса по более подходящей формулировке, то можно отдельное обсуждение начать.

Answer (score 6):

Проблема в том, что если разрешить подобные вопросы, то от них будет невозможно избавляться, даже если никто не захочет на них отвечать. Сейчас существует компромисс: если хороший ответ есть, то вопрос считается "спасённым", причём зачастую вопрос после этого переписывается с нуля; в противном случае вопрос удаляется. Лучше так, чем открывать ящик Пандоры.

И я не наблюдаю проблем с приведёнными вами вопросами.

- [Рендер туманности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3030) — не самый выдающийся вопрос, но в нём описана конкретная проблема (заданы критерии, описано решение, описана проблема). Вопрос позволяет выходить за рамки изначального решения, но это не преступление.
- [Защита от DDOS атак](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069) — довольно-таки бесполезный вопрос с набором бесполезных ответов (ответы-ссылки, ответы-хаки, ответы на пару общих слов, ответы невпопад). Нет ни одного ответа, достойного спасения. Следует или развернуть принятый ответ-ссылку (на указанной странице действительно есть что-то про DoS (не DDoS!)), или удалить вопрос, потому что сообщество оказалось не в состоянии написать что-то вменяемое.
- [Системы контроля версий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/113235) — откровенно "форумный" вопрос с открытым обсуждением и тысячей подвопросов. Ответы соответствующие. Надо заметить, что вопрос уже неактуален, потому что Git победил, и его знают все. Можно заблокировать и сохранить для истории, больше толку нет.
- [Фрагментация памяти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180995) — по-хорошему, надо просто переформулировать вопрос. Есть проблема, есть решения. Имеющиеся ответы довольно посредственные, надо заметить, и не в последнюю очередь из-за неудачной формулировки вопроса. Здесь нужна конкретика и в вопросе, и в ответах. Программист, зайдя на страничку в текущем виде, узнает одно: "Да, проблема существует". Возможно, сможет обнаружить ключевое слово "кастомный аллокатор". Всё. Если вопрос будет завтра удалён, Интернет ничего не потеряет. Это не то качество, к которому мы должны стремиться.

Так что постарайтесь привести более убедительные примеры.

Comment: Про "Системы контроля версий" - полностью поддерживаю историческую блокировку. Самый популярный вопрос по своей метке, а в ответах только мнения, никакой конкретики.

Comment: На самом деле проблема не с этими конкретными вопросами, а с будущими, теми которые так и не будут заданы, если активное (и зачастую малограмотное) большинство будет очень часто совершенно формально следовать правилам, подобным этому. А плохие вопросы надо удалять (м.б. и вручную), независимо не от чего (только вот тут как всегда -- "а судьи кто?").

Comment: @NickVolynkin, видите ли, не все темы (точнее их уровень обсуждения) очевидны для всех. Думаю, \@Котик не зря его задавал.

Comment: @avp А если так спросить: "Меня интересует мнение опытных пользователей языков программирования по поводу сражения Java vs C#, равно как и JVM vs .NET"?

Comment: Меня интересует мнение опытных пользователей текстовых редакторов по поводу сражения IntelliJ IDEA vs Vim, равно как и полнофункциональных IDE против текстовых редакторов без графического интерфейса.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а что, эти "сражения" реально происходят не только в головах начинающих программистов?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спросить можно. Возможно даже (но маловероятно), что кто-то из разработчиков этих языков (сред) расскажет несколько интересных историй. А в конце-концов, что будет плохого если такой вопрос и полежит с негодными ответами, а остальные будут удаляться, как дубликаты с ссылкой не него?

Comment: @avp Плохо то, что это официальный оффтопик на любом сайте Stack Exchange. Не надо превращать СО в форум, просто потому что вам нравится флудить на холиварные темы. Мне тоже нравится, но я же этим здесь не занимаюсь.

Comment: @avp На мой взгляд, не стоит говорить о полезности какого-либо формата основываясь на том, что «опытные» участники задают такие вопросы. Ответы и вопросы – это две разные вселенные. Когда я отвечаю, я знаю о чем пишу, а когда задаю вопрос, волнуюсь как в школе, ко всему мне нужен ответ _сейчас_, что иногда приводит к несоблюдению правил, особенно если знаешь, что в сообществе есть участники, которые могут помочь. Для дискуссий есть чат.

Answer (score 3):

Правила не требуют **однозначности** ответа в том смысле, который вы в него вкладываете - существование ровно одного правильного решения.

Будь это так, не было бы смысла городить систему с возможностью дать несколько ответов на один вопрос.

Более того, один из показателей для беты на [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) - это среднее количество ответов на вопрос - причем ruSO с 1.8 не дотягивает по нему до рекомендованных 2.5.

Правила требуют возможности дать **однозначно верный** ответ - такой, глядя на который можно сказать - "да, это одно из правильных решений". Причем это "да" должно быть обосновано чем-то кроме "я так думаю".

Comment: Видимо, критерий "я так думаю" все же зависит от авторитета отвечающего? Например, если Вы прочтете ответ  Андерса Хейлсберга (а как насчет RMS?) с такой формулировкой.

Comment: В любом случае формулировку в **правилах** надо как-то менять (уточнять).

Comment: @avp согласен, надо. можно взять за основу вариант из ответа jfs

Comment: Да, формулировка @jfs значительно лучше, только все равно проблема остается. Вообще-то она в том, что в момент задания вопроса достоверно не известно, какие ответы (основанные не *фактах* или *только субъекивных мнениях*) будут даны. Иногда это можно довольно точно спргнозировать, иногда нет (но это всегда субъективно).