# Проблемы причины закрытия "опросник" и возможные решения

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия

Уже несколько раз всплывали проблемы с причиной закрытия "опросник":

> Не по теме, потому что… → Вопросы-опросники запрещены на Stack Overflow на русском.
>
> Для получения ответа, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Проблемы

- невнимательные, но очень старательные закрывающие воспринимают "однозначно правильный ответ" как "ровно один ответ", хотя формулировка подразумевает **однозначность правильности**, а не **единственность** ответа. Подробно рассмотрено в [Требование однозначности ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1606)
- причина полностью дублирует причину "Однозначно верный ответ", вплоть до формулировки. С.м.- [Причины закрытия — "Вопрос-Опросник" vs "Однозначно верный ответ"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1370/)

Слово **однозначно** в формулировке однозначно вызывает проблемы. Основной путь появления проблемы:

1. Участник-новичок A постит вопрос "как в языке X сделать Y".
2. В языке X есть два или более полностью корректных способа сделать Y.
3. Добросовестный участник B1 видит этот вопрос. Он задумывается, вспоминает что в причинах закрытия было что-то про однозначность.
4. Открывает диалог закрытия - ну так и есть - "...на него можно дать однозначный ответ"
5. Участник B1 ставит тревогу. Или голосует за закрытие (если у него больше 500 репутации)
6. Участники B2 - B5 бодры и пытаются улучшить сайт. Они просматривают очередь на закрытие и видят там вопрос от A. Над вопросом надпись "... необходимо...однозначный ответ...".
7. Можно дать два ответа - да! И вопрос закрывается как "опросник".

На мой взгляд, это особенность восприятия словосочетания "однозначно правильный ответ". По какой-то неизвестной причине все читают его как "однозначный ответ". Это не еденичный случай, это массовое явление. Оно возникло сразу же после того, как в формулировке появилось слово "однозначный".

Текущее предлагаемое администрацией решение - просматривать закрытые вопросы, просматривать (повторно, за другими!) очередь на закрытие, находить там "неправильные" голоса, как-то (интересно, как?) связываться с теми, кто их поставил, и доносить до них разницу между "однозначный ответ" и "однозначно правильный ответ". Осложняется это тем, что

- личных сообщений нет
- к закрытым вопросам закрыватели не возвращаются
- мету они не читают
- в чате не сидят
- даже если вопрос получается переоткрыть - вред уже нанесен - новичок ушел с сайта

С ним надо что-то делать.

На мой взгляд, самый простой способ - это разорвать цепочку на пункте (4). Убрать слово "однозначно", заменить на "объективно" - пусть формулировка будет так же размыта, но в ней не будет слова "один", которое применимо к *количеству* ответов - и участник B1 вместо закрытия напишет ответ. Все будут счастливы.

Возможно, стоит вообще устранить причину "опросник" - т.к. внятного определения "опросника" и отличия его от просто "вопроса без однозначно верного ответа" никто привести не может. А, возможно, и нет. Поэтому я предлагаю два варианта решения - с опросником и без него.

Если кто-то считает, что текущая формулировка не вызывает проблем - напишите свой вариант (желательно, объясняющий, как устранить проблему без смены формулировки).

Comment: "бодры и пытаются улучшить сайт" — говорите уж прямо, "роботы". )

Comment: @NickVolynkin нет, я сегодня случайно достучался до двоих - и, как ни странно, оба действительн пытались улучшить сайт, просто неправильно прочитали причину.

Comment: @NickVolynkin чуть что - сразу Владимир? :)

Comment: неа, сейчас я не имел в виду Владимира. Он успешно прошел тест Тьюринга. ))

Comment: Обратите внимание на аргументацию _против_ причины «опросник»: _[Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 1: “опросники” должны умереть](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/)_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Убрать причину опросник. Совсем.

“Однозначно верный ответ” переформулировать как “Объективно верный ответ”

<sub>Pashapash: лично я бы проголосовал за этот пункт, но не могу :(</sub>

---

Обоснование удаления "опросника" есть в самом вопросе, но на всякий случай:

Тот факт, что причина является практически полной копией причины "Однозначно верный ответ", но со словом "опросник" приводит к:

1. Закрытию вопросов, к которым она неприменима (т.к. каждый толкует "опросник" по-своему, от "вопросник" до "задано несколько вопросов в одном"). Чаще всего
2. ...что ломает вообще всю идею причин закрытия - автору не дается подсказки, что же он должен исправить - т.к. в большинстве случаев он не должен исправить ничего, т.к. вопрос быз закрыт ошибочно.

До сих пор не было приведено [ни одного примера](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1370/), который однозначно бы показал разницу между "опросником" и "требуется однозначно верный ответ". Никто не может сказат, что же такое "опросник", настаивающий именно на слове "опросник" @NicolasChabanovsky пояснения давать отказывается.

Приведено [достаточно примеров использования причины не по назначению](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1924/). Наносимый вред (отпугивание участников, удаление контента), на мой взгляд, несоизмерим с личным желанием @NicolasChabanovsky оставить слово "опросник"

Причина должна быть удалена!

---

Разбор формулировки изменяемой причины

> Необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ
>
> Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

- Что именно не так с вопросом - он подразумевает ответ, основанный не на знании, а, в основном, на личном мнении отвечающего.
- Что нужно сделать для переоткрытия - перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективно правильный ответ.
- Исправлена ли проблема, озвученная в вопросе - да, никто больше случайно не сможет прочитать его как "...дать ровно один правильный ответ...

Comment: Отличная формулировка!

Comment: поддерживаю данный вариант по тому что под грань между "Опросник" и разрешенным вопросом крайне размыта

Comment: Обновил формулировку, убрал указанную причину. Как мне кажется, все же, нам необходимо еще поработать над улучшением именно обсуждаемой причины.

Answer (score 13):

Предлагаю убрать обе причины и сделать одну:

> **Зависит от мнений**
>
> Много хороших вопросов имеют ответы, зависящие в некоторой степени от
>   мнения и опыта отвечающего эксперта. Но ответы на этот вопрос будут
>   почти полностью зависеть от мнений, нежели от фактов, ссылок и
>   специфичных исследований.

Это прямой перевод причины из основного SO.

После закрытия вопроса такой причиной, автору вопроса должна быть предоставлена ссылка на статью ["Какой тип вопросов лучше не задавать?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
, в которой чётко прописана инструкция по исправлению вопроса или его удалению.

---

Разбор по топику [Зачем на сайте присутствует функционал закрытия вопросов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

**1. Позволяет решать проблемы возложенные на данный инструмент**

На Stack Overflow не приветствуются вопросы, ответы на которые основаны на мнениях. Хороший ответ это тот, который построен на фактах. [Справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) так же рекомендует воздержаться от ответов на вопросы, которые "провоцируют обмен мнениями, а не фактами". Такая формулировка причины хорошо подходит для закрытия вопросов, с описанными выше проблемами.

**2. Содержит четкое описание ошибок, допущенных при написании вопроса**

В формулировке используется приём антитеза, чтобы выделить контраст между хорошим и плохим вопросами. Таким образом, автор будет понимать, каким образом его вопрос не соответствует категории "хороший вопрос".

**3. Содержит набор конкретных шагов, выполнив которые, вопрос станет удовлетворять правилам сообщества, и призыв к действию – исправлению вопроса**

Под причиной закрытия каждого закрытого вопроса появляется следующее:

> Если этот вопрос можно переформулировать согласно правилам,
>   изложенными в [Справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), отредактируйте его.

Это и есть призыв к исправлению всех вопросов. Он вшит в код. А по ссылке можно найти конкретные правила. Если этого не хватит, то можем отредактировать справку с конкретными заголовками. Текст справки подготовлю, если будет нужно.

Comment: лично мне этот вариант нравится, но стоит отметить что [@NicolasChabanovsky прямо высказывался против прямых переводов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1606/%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0#comment4671_1609)

Comment: @PashaPash, сами оцените: смысл утерян? Это то, что объединяет обе причины и является лучше них одновременно. Причина закрытия должна помогать автору вопроса сделать его лучше. Этот вариант в полной мере обеспечит нужной информацией. С другой стороны, для голосующих не будет слов с двойным смыслом, или тех, что можно спутать. Заголовок "Зависит от мнения" прямо и говорит о том, что ответить на вопрос объективно не получится.

Comment: я строго за одну причину с нормальной формулировкой. Николас, по какой-то причине - против.

Comment: Замечу, что **новую причину добавлять не надо, она уже есть**, просто её заголовок в изуродованном виде из-за одичавших локализаторов: "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ". Эта штуковина находится на первой странице диалога закрытия вопроса. Вину за одичавших локализаторов принимаю на себя, это я открыл ящик Пандоры...

Comment: @Discord: Насчёт вины не страшно, главное, что мы можем его закрыть назад.

Comment: @VladD пока, судя по всему, не можем

Comment: @PashaPash: Исходя из верхних двух ответов в этом вопросе, есть шанс.

Comment: Может вместо _Зависит от мнений_ что-то вроде _Субъективный ответ_?

Comment: @Grundy, думаю, что такая формулировка больше подойдёт для удаления ответов. Но это не суть.

Comment: @LEQADA, ну или _Подразумевает субъективный ответ_ :-)

Comment: @Grundy, да, возможно потом нужно будет подкорректировать текст, чтобы получить более понятно/грамотно, без изменения смысла. Думаю, что ваше предложение нужно учесть. Но это сейчас скорее идея, чем конечный результат.

Comment: @LEQADA, я в любом случае уже проголосовал за убрать все, но вот _Зависит от мнений_ как-то не подходит что ли :-) на мой взгляд

Comment: @Grundy, согласен, "Зависит от мнений" - корявый перевод. Нужно подумать над этим.

Comment: С такой формулировкой все вопросы по проектированию и дизайну ПО можно будет смело закрывать. А тем не менее все ответы на такие вопросы -- это по-прежнему и знания, и опыт, и точка зрения. И ничего плохого в том, что овтеты будут отличаться. Мы ведь базу знаний строим?

Comment: @andreycha, с текущими формулировками их тоже можно закрывать. Тем не менее,[было на мете обсуждение](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review)  и, судя по лидеру, решение по поводу Code Review. Мне кажется, что это другой вопрос.

Comment: @LEQADA Отличное предложение! Для придания конкретики, пожалуйста, добавьте в сообщение [разбор формулировки](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/).

Comment: В предложенном варианте нет шагов, которые следует проделать для улучшения вопроса. Нет призыва к действию. К сожалению, я бы даже сказал, в нем нет конкретных параметров, по которым можно сказать, что конкретно этот вопрос не удовлетворяет им. На мой взгляд, стоит учитывать, что SOen узнаваем до невозможности. Проблема SOen – слишком большой поток вопросов, в которых сложно разобраться, нужен фильтр. Проблема SOru – небольшое количество вопросов. Для SOen позволительно сказать, что вопрос не соответствует и... все. Для нас – нет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, скоро отредактирую и добавлю всё, что требуется.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, обновил ответ. 3 и 4 пункты соединил в один.

Comment: @LEQADA призыв к изменениям, насколькоя я понял, должен быть конкретным

Comment: @PashaPash, этот вопрос не для двух строчек. Чтобы объяснить человеку, что его вопрос просит ответ, основанный на мнениях, в справке выделим жирным один заголовок, в котором будут инструкции и подробные объяснения. Люди разные бывают. Одни понимают быстро, другим нужно долго объяснять. Я не верю в то, что эту проблему можно решить непосредственно в теле самой причины.

Comment: @LEQADA Возможно, стоит попробовать конкретизировать шаги по улучшению вопроса? Также, было бы здорово обновить вопрос так, чтобы он содержал в одном месте все его части. На сколько я понимаю, закрывающий видит тоже самое, что будет в формулировке после закрытия.

Comment: На самом деле, в текущей формулировке, например, я воспринимаю причину так – «Есть такие вопросы, которые основаны на мнениях, и это не хорошо. Ваш вопрос закрыт». Причем эти две мысли даже не связанны между собой явно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, причину видит, но то, что будет под причиной добавляется сайтом (ссылка на справку и призыв к редактированию вопроса). Я тут, между делом, у португальцев глянул. У них точно такая же причина. В любом случае, это идея, вариант. Решать вам и другим участникам сообщества. Я-то за свой вариант проголосовать не могу ) Нашлись те, кто в голосовании поставил минус (зачем?).

Answer (score 0):

Оставить обе причины.

“Однозначно верный ответ” во всех формулировках заменить на “Объективно верный ответ”.

Comment: объективность чем мерять - и в каких единицах?

Comment: @LazyBadger в те же, что и "однозначность правильности", которая упоминалась в старой формулировке.

Answer (score 0):

#### Оставить обе причины.

Я не вижу чем "Объективно верный" лучше "Однозначно верный". Если хочется уточнить формулировку, то это надо делать текстом, а не менять одно словосочетание на другое.

По этому надо дополнить причины закрытия следующим образом

- Необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ.
  Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно <s>правильный ответ</s>**правильные ответы**, либо удалите вопрос вовсе. **(Вопрос может иметь несколько ответов, но ответы должны опираться на факты, а не предпочтения отвечающих.)**
- Вопросы-опросники запрещены на Stack Overflow на русском.
  **Вместо вопросов вида "перечислите ВСЕ книги по языку X", или "ВСЕ способы сделать Y" постарайтесь** перефразировать Ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать конечное (небольшое) количество ответов.