# Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 1: "опросники" должны умереть!

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, нытьё

- **Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 1: “опросники” должны умереть!**
- [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 2: “вопрос неясен” — это не MCVE/SSCCE!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1931/)

---

Однажды на ничего не подозревающих пользователей Stack Overflow на русском свалились исковерканные причины для закрытия вопросов: причины "рекомендация стороннего ресурса" и "опечатка или невоспроизводимая проблема" исчезли, на их место пришла причина "опросник". Слава богам, администрация прислушалась к возмутившимся пользователям и вернула хотя бы "опечатки". К сожалению, "опросники" выжили и продолжают уродовать сайт до сих пор.

Что такое опросник — никто не знает. Кого ни спросишь, все дают разные ответы. Споры о формулировке ведутся до сих пор, и даже сейчас на Мете проводится очередной вопрос с целью выяснить, что же такое "опросник".

Но давайте обратимся к истории. История нам говорит, что причина по сути была введена как замена причине "рекомендация стороннего ресурса". Давайте же не поленимся пройтись по сайту и найти "опросники", которые не вписываются в "рекомендации".

Для быстрого поиска я воспользовался [запросом на Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/294078/most-upvoted-questions-closed-for-a-specific-reason?topn=1000&reason=102). К сожалению, способ получить детальную информацию о закрытии не нашёл, поэтому пришлось перелопатить больше вопросов, чем хотелось бы (около 200). Так как надписи на системных причинах закрытия тоже обезображены, то всюду ниже использую оригинальные английские формулировки.

Итак, в путь!

- [Как повесить обработчик на нажатие кнопки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458196/176051) - нормальный вопрос, хоть и тривиальный (кандидат на переоткрытие)
- [Как сделать такой выбор даты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427289/176051) - too broad (можно исправить)
- [Хранение в БД текста со ссылками на медиа-файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/465326/176051) - opinion-based
- [Футтер в шаблоне на Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464659/176051) - too broad (можно исправить)
- [Какую версию Yii посоветуете?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459873/176051) - opinion-based (нужны конкретные требования)
- [Как загрузить файлы на GitHub?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450514/176051) - too broad (нет описания проблемы)
- [При открытии файла или папки он удаляется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/466580/176051) - перенос на Super User (но у нас его нет)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/439741/176051 - too broad (хотя можно и оставить открытым)
- [Где грань достаточно веской причины для отклонения кода при Code Review?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456490/176051) - opinion-based / too broad
- [Как сделать массовую переустановку компьютеров сразу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417708/176051) - too broad (неоднозначно)
- [Агрегатные функции в mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463769/176051) - too broad (кандидат на удаление)
- [Помогите разобраться со скриптом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435100/176051) - too broad + third-party (кандидат на удаление)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435430/176051 - opinion-based (кандидат на удаление)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435435/176051 - opnion-based (кандидат на удаление)
- [Как вывести на сайте опцию - музыка из вконтакте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/436057/176051) - too broad / mcve (?)
- [Как получить iOS9 beta и El Capitan официально ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/442541/176051) - custom: "third-party support" (хотя можно и оставить открытым)
- [Постраничная навигация при помощи MVVM Light](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/466890/176051) - opinion-based (с учётом ответа кандидат на переоткрытие)
- [Android/Java :как правильно хранить url/http ссылки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/467006/176051) - opinion-based
- [Кастомизация виджетов Андроид: наследование стандартных или создание собственных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/436166/176051) - opinion-based
- [запуск приложения по времени на android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460457/176051) - судя по ответу, нормальный вопрос, кандидат на переоткрытие
- [Запись видео с веб-камеры на Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460442/176051) - too broad (?)
- [Построение графиков div'ами - рационально ли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460602/176051) - opinion-based
- [А Parser3 от ArtLebedev до сих пор кто-нибудь использует?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450888/176051) - opinion-based
- [Открывать страницы в зависимости от выбора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468722/176051) - нормальный вопрос, хоть и тривиальный
- [Пошаговое руководство по установке Nodejs под Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/262891/176051) - too broad
- [Возможна ли установка xcode 5 на mac os x 10.7.5?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/255045/176051) - нормальный вопрос, хоть и странный
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468949/176051 - custom: "third-party support"
- и так далее

Абсолютно все остальные вопросы, закрытые как "опросники", попадают в критерии "рекомендация стороннего ресурса".

Что мы видим?

1. Не найдено ни одного вопроса (прописью: *абсолютный ноль, ноль без палочки, дырка от бублика, зеро*), который не вписывался бы в существующие или существовавшие причины для закрытия. Вывод: **причина "опросник" бесполезна для расширения допустимых закрытий**.
2. Как "опросники" закрывается множество вопросов, которые должны быть закрыты по другим причинам. Это вводит в заблуждение пользователей, потому что они ещё меньше понимают смысл слова "опросник", чем закрывающие. Вывод: **причина "опросник" вредна как путающая пользователей и мешающая понять пути к исправлению проблемы с вопросом**.
3. Некоторые простые, но совершенно нормальные вопросы закрываются как "опросники". Пользователь с высокой репутацией, которому не нравится вопрос, но который не видит подходящих причин для закрытия, использует причину, которая подходит абсолютно всегда. Вывод: **причина "опросник" вредна как приводящая к закрытию нормальных простых вопросов**.

Answer (score 3):

Пытаемся на SO закрыть вопрос, в том же варианте  **Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic** возможные причины на выбор:

- Questions about general computing hardware...
- Questions on professional server- or networking-related
  infrastructure administration
- Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
  library, tutorial...
- Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")
  must include the desired behavior
- This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be
  reproduced or a simple typographical error
- Blatantly off-topic

У нас же:

- Скорее всего, данный вопрос не относится ни к обсуждению работы сайта
  Stack Overflow на русском, ни к программному обеспечению сети Stack
  Exchange, согласно правилам, описанным в справке.
- Другое (добавьте комментарий, объясняющий причину закрытия)

Так же не ru SO нету вариантов:

- unclear what you're asking
- too broad
- primarily opinion-based

Как только все эти варианты появятся и здесь, то проблемы явно не станет, или, по крайней мере, станет проще.

Comment: Во-первых, вы привели причины закрытия на Meta.Ru.SO. На основном сайте Ru.SO разнообразие всё-таки побольше. Во-вторых, три приведённые вами в конце причины таки присутствуют и на Мете, и на основном сайте, просто они изуродованы "альтернативным" переводом "для большей понятности". Три причины в самом низу на первой странице диалога закрытия — это и есть unclear, too broad и opinion-based.

Comment: @Discord "Три причины в самом низу на первой странице диалога закрытия — это и есть unclear, too broad и opinion-based" - Вы открыли мне глаза О_О

Comment: @Suvitruf вы привели список кастомных причин с диалога закрытия на мете (их там две). на основном сайте - больше.

Comment: @PashaPash да. Но не меняет сути: их меньше, чем на en SO, они не очевидны.

Comment: @Suvitruf их ровно столько же - 5 основных причин, 1 к 1 как на enSO. Чуть отличается спискок подпричин в в причине 2 - offtopic, у нас нет причины, запрещающей поиск книг (т.е. она есть - это "опросник", по задумке Николаса), нет причин, посылающих на SF/SU (потому что они у нас онтопик). и нет подпричины "совсем оффтопик" - я просил ее ввести, но Николас не хочет.

Comment: @Suvitruf т.е. разница реально в одном пункте (Blatantly off-topic) и в кривейшей формулировке еще одного пункта ("Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam" -> опросник)

Comment: @PashaPash я только после слов Discord'а понял, что эти пункты значат =/

Comment: @Suvitruf а до этого все спускали в опросник? :)

Comment: @PashaPash угу =/

Comment: @Suvitruf судя по статистике закрытий - не вы один. Поэтому мы и пытаемся [сжечь опросник - присоединяйтесь](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1918/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?lq=1)