# Двойные стандарты: грань между разрешёнными и запрещёнными опросниками

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, модерация, тематика, причины-закрытия

Почему мы придерживаемся [двойных стандартов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B), почему некоторые вопросы *"Опросники"* имеют право на жизнь некоторые же категорически не приветствуются?

Хочется знать, где проходит та хрупкая грань.

Навеяно

- [Проблемы причины закрытия "опросник" и возможные решения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1918/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F);
- [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 1: "опросники" должны умереть!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1924/%D0%92%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-stackoverflow-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)
- [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: Больше конкретики, пожалуйста. Покажите вопрос, который получил право на жизнь и вопрос, который не приветствовался.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я хочу не пожаловаться на то что мой вопрос был признан опросником, а узнать как можно задать вопрос-опросник правильно и получить на него ответ, в ином случае я бы добавил метку *нытьё*, Вы же не будете отрицать что на ресурсе есть вопросы опросники?!

Comment: «вопрос-опросник» это очень размытое понятие, что неоднократно объяснялось, в том числе в указанных вами вопросах. Какой именно вопрос вы хотите задать, о чём?

Comment: @NickVolynkin блин Вы прям вынуждаете меня *жаловаться* :) хочется получить рекомендации от более опытных Коллег где можно посмотреть код.

Comment: Я просто хочу услышать конкретный запрос. Совета/мнений/личного опыта можете попросить в чате.

Comment: @NickVolynkin это я уже проходил :), пытался задавать вопрос, на что получил откуп: "Задайте вопрос", и я ведь не один такой

Comment: @NickVolynkin пример конкретного вопроса: "Посоветуйте пример приложения с открытым исходным кодом реализующим *здесь указана технология*" разве на такой вопрос нельзя ответить? кто то может не согласиться поставить минус, кто то подержит поставит плюс, в коментах натыкался на  рекомендации участие в проектах с открытым исходным кодом, а как их узнать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Забудьте про слово "опросник", оно только вводит в заблуждение.

Если вас интересует вопрос, который на большом СО закрыли бы как "primarily opinion-based", то здесь его закроют или по аналогичной причине, или как опросник, но в любом случае — закроют. Хотите, чтобы вопрос остался — добавьте конкретики.

- *"Что лучше: стулья или табуретки?"* — закроют.
- *"Что безопаснее для построения пирамиды до луны: стулья или табуретки?"* — оставят.

Аналогично с "too broad".

- *"Расскажите про четырёхмерных инопланетян"* — закроют.
- *"Преодоление проблемы трёхмерного восприятия четырёхмерных инопланетян у детей от двухсот лет и больше"* — оставят.

Аналогично с "third-party resource recommendation".

- *"Посоветуйте библиотеку для материализации фантазий"* — закроют.
- *"Как материализовать пони из мультсериала ростом больше метра без рассеивания через час, если эти библиотеки имеют ограничения на объём и время действия"* — оставят.

Что касается работы за автора, то она не запрещена, хотя и не приветствуется. В приведённом вами сообщении всё детально разобрано.

Comment: "Что лучше: стулья или табуретки?" vs "Что безопаснее для построения пирамиды до луны: стулья или табуретки?" вот это я и понимаю под *Двойным стандартом*, т.е. что бы получить ответ на казалось бы простой вопрос о рекомендации приложения для изучения и впитывания примеров как это делают *большие пацаны*. я должен написать что то типа: Посоветуйте приложение с открытым исходным кодом в котором реализован/используется *некий общий принцип*(пусть будет mvvm). хотя такой вопрос все равно попадает под  "third-party resource recommendation".

Comment: Что первый, что второй вариант в примере со стульями - это opinion based. Второй пример - это "работа за автора" в обоих вариантах.

Comment: @Bald56rus Разница между первым и вторым вопросом — в наличии чёткого критерия, а не абстрактного "лучше". Также предполагается, что в самом вопросе будут разораны конкретные детали решаемой проблемы. А в рекомендации стороннего ресурса разница в наличии чётких требований и явных проблем с существующими решениями. Это выход за рамки рекомендации, так как решением будет и воркэраунд в рамках имеющихся решений, и другое решение, и какой-то наколеночный подход.

Comment: @Suvitruf Предполагается, что вопрос не ограничивается заголовком, а в тексте рассматриваются детали требуемой безопасности, то есть требования формализованы. Первый же вариант полагается на абстрактное "лучше". Что касается работы за автора, то она не запрещена. Читайте пост по ссылке из вопроса.

Comment: @Discord лично я, если автор просит сделать работу за него, но при этом не пишет, что он уже сделал, голосую за закрытие.

Comment: @Suvitruf Лично вы не слишком внимательно относитесь в своим обязанностям и правилам сайта. С чем и поздравляю. Надо смотреть не только на наличие кода.

Comment: @Discord это не благотворительная организация. Если автор сам не хочет сил прикладывать к решению проблемы, почему мы должны ему помогать?

Comment: @Suvitruf Если вам просто не нравится вопрос, то его следует минусовать. Закрывать его следует тогда, когда он нарушает правила, принятые на сайте сообществом и администрацией. Если вы этого не делаете, то вы нарушаете правила. В случае активной "борьбы" с вопросами без кода вы можете быть забанены. Так или иначе: голосование за закрытие — это не высказывание вашего личного отношения к вопросу или его автору, это ваша **оценка соответствия вопроса существующим правилам сайта**. Вот плюсы и минусы — ваша **личная оценка вопроса** (но не автора!), используйте как хотите.

Comment: @Discord то есть такие вопросы http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4791/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-button-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BC, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/190039/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c - это нормально ?

Comment: @Suvitruf Если добавить в вопрос используемую технологию, то да, нормальный вопрос. Чтобы совсем было хорошо, можно добавить скриншот с желаемым видом. Код в этом вопросе не нужен абсолютно.

Comment: @Discord я хоть раз про код упомянул в своих сообщениях?

Comment: @Suvitruf но такие вопросы ведь все равно будут, и ответить на него можно, и даже нужно, останется вопрос, не будет задан новый