# Зачем на сайте присутствует функционал закрытия вопросов?

Tags: поддержка, faq, причины-закрытия, правила

В системе есть много различных инструментов, один из которых «закрытие вопросов». В последнее время вокруг него существует очень много споров. Есть вероятность, что не все участники прений до конца понимают зачем он нужен вообще.

#### Зачем нужна функция закрытия вопросов?

Для того, чтобы определиться с формулировками причин закрытия вопросов, необходимо оценить, а *нужны ли они вообще*?

Если бы меня попросили описать, что такое Stack Overflow, я бы сказал следующее.

1. Stack Overflow — это прежде всего сообщество профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения и энтузиастов программирования, то есть это реальные люди, которым не безразлична судьба разработки ПО и их коллег.
2. Stack Overflow — это свободная база прикладных решений, а-ля Википедия для работы, которая позволяет повысить качество результирующего продукта, упростить и ускорить его разработку.

Второй пункт — следствие и результат первого.

Представим идеальный мир, в котором все перед публикацией вопроса знакомятся со справочным центром, осознают правила сайта и не нарушают их. В результате, если справочный центр действительно детальный, на сайте будут задаваться только хорошие вопросы.

Как мы понимаем, идеального мира не бывает. Участники не до конца понимают правила, торопятся при публикации или просто не умеют четко описывать проблему, а иногда даже делают кросс-копирование одного и того же текста на множестве ресурсов с разным форматом.

Для того, чтобы система под названием «Stack Overflow» работала нам необходимо, чтобы:

1. собралось сообщество неравнодушных профессионалов;
2. сообщество создавало качественные знания, которые можно использовать многократно.

Крайне важным требованием для существования сообщества является то, что каждый участник может и хочет ассоциировать себя с этим сообществом. Для создания базы знаний требуются «правила игры». Мы вместе создали эти правила и описали их в справочном центре. Таким образом, можно сказать, что есть как минимум два основных назначения функционала закрытия вопросов.

1. Чтобы оградиться от людей, которых мы не можем отнести к сообществу программистов, как минимум в контексте нашего личного понимания этого термина.
2. Чтобы оградиться от содержимого, которое мы не можем отнести к полезной базе знаний прикладных решений.

Закрытие вопросов — это инструмент сообщества, у которого есть вполне конкретное назначение. Не более.

#### Для кого закрываются вопросы?

**Вопросы закрываются для задающих**. Закрывая вопрос мы говорим автору, что в текущем виде он (вопрос) не соответствует требованиям сайта или сообществу. Самое важное, чтобы *автор вопроса предельно ясно понимал*:

- что именно не так с вопросом;
- какие *конкретные* шаги следует проделать, чтобы исправить вопрос.

**В формулировке *обязательно* должен иметь место призыв к действию**. Мы с вами знаем, что Stack Overflow — лучшее место для получения ответа по программированию, это знают и многие участники, но понимают это уже *после публикации* нескольких вопросов, но правила нарушаются, по большому счету, новыми участниками, которые далеко не всегда слышали про существование Stack Overflow и вполне могут не понимать различия между сайтом вопросов и ответов и форумом. Для них Stack Overflow — это еще один сайт, где можно опубликовать непонятно что, получить в ответ непонятно что, возможно, содержащее решение. Именно на нас, сообществе, лежит груз ответственности за обучения наших коллег правилам ведения профессионального диалога. Один из способов достижения цели как раз и является призыв к действию с «[положительным подкреплением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F))».

Согласитесь, нам не нужна база закрытых вопросов, нам нужна база знаний. Добавляя конкретные шаги по улучшению вопроса и призыв к действию мы увеличиваем вероятность исправления недочетов.

#### Как подобрать правильные причины закрытия вопросов?

Как уже говорилось, закрытие вопросов позволяет нам оградиться от не соответствующего правилам сообщества содержимого и нежелательных участников. Это лишь инструмент, содержащий две панели. На первой панели содержится наименьшее количество наиболее распространенных ошибок, которые регулируются командой развития сообществ, конечно же, в тесном содействии с участниками. На второй, вложенной — дополнительные типичные ошибки, набор которых, по сути, регулируется сообществом.

Таким образом, набор причин закрытия, — это лишь список наиболее часто допускаемых ошибок при публикации вопросов на *текущий момент*. Список может и должен изменяться в зависимости от *настоящих требований* сообщества.

Подчеркну, набор причин закрытия регулируется нуждами конкретного сообщества в конкретный момент времени, а их формулировка составляется исходя из норм, принятых в конкретной культуре. Прямой перевод формулировок из других сообществ, особенно на других языках в данному случае не применим, в связи с различием в размерах сообществ и культурных норм.

#### Как оформить предложение по изменению причин закрытия вопросов?

Причины можно и нужно менять. Предлагая изменения, пожалуйста, убедитесь, что новая формулировка или старая, после исправления:

1. **позволяет решать проблемы возложенные на данный инструмент;**
2. **содержит четкое описание ошибок, допущенных при написании вопроса;**
3. **содержит набор конкретных шагов, выполнив которые, вопрос станет удовлетворять правилам сообщества;**
4. **содержит призыв к действию — исправлению вопроса.**

Пожалуйста, учтите, что формулировка будет применяться к семейству вопросов, а читаться в контексте одного, то есть должна быть составлена с одной стороны в общих словах, но с другой содержать конкретные рекомендации.

Comment: Любопытно, что на этом вопросе есть голос за закрытие.

Answer (score 6):

Мой ответ не вписывается в комментарий, поэтому добавляю отдельное сообщение.

> На первой панели содержится наименьшее количество наиболее распространенных ошибок, которые регулируются командой развития сообществ, конечно же, в тесном содействии с участниками. На второй, вложенной – дополнительные типичные ошибки, набор которых, по сути, регулируется сообществом.
>
> Таким образом, набор причин закрытия, – это лишь список наиболее часто допускаемых ошибок при публикации вопросов на текущий момент. Список может и должен изменяться в зависимости от настоящих требований сообщества.

**I**. Причины на первой странице — это причины, единые для всей Сети. Они — результат долгих лет развития десятков сайтов Q&A. В них каждое слово высечено потом и кровью.

Ни одному сайту не давалось права изобретать на их месте что-то своё. Каждый сайт в Сети использует эти причины. Что у локализованных сайтов появилась техническая возможность полностью изменить текст — это не значит, что появилось право. Наша обязанность — перевести оригинальный текст с учётом всяких там культурных особенностей, но — перевести, сохранить идею и дух оригинального текста.

**II**. Вот где каждое отдельное сообщество решает, какие причины нужны — это вторая страница. И здесь уже следует ориентироваться на границы конкретного сайта Сети. Но — стараться избегать хождения по граблям, по которым уже прошёлся большой СО.

Один из уроков большого СО: надо избегать причин, которые легко интерпретировать неверно. Если такие есть, то даже те пользователи, кто старается следовать правилам сайта, будет нарушать их. Яркий пример — "опросник", когда даже самые опытные пользователи не могут решить, что же именно это означает. Думаю, не надо приводить цитату самого высокорепового юзера на сайте, чтобы доказать правоту.

Ещё один важный аспект: когда выбираются причины, их текст должен быть мотивирован разницей в тематике с остальными сайтами, потому что причины для закрытия на второй странице целиком и полностью определяются тематикой. Например, мы включили SU, SF, почти включили CR, но есть ли у нас хотя бы одна причина закрытия, которая возникла из-за этого включения? Нет. Но у нас есть "опросник", который не мотивирован тематикой и спецификой сайта вообще никак.

> Подчеркну, набор причин закрытия регулируются нуждами конкретного сообщества в конкретный момент времени, а их формулировка составляется исходя из норм, принятых в конкретной культуре. Прямой перевод формулировок из других сообществ, особенно на других языках в данному случае не применим, в связи с различием в размерах сообществ и культурных норм.

Набор общих слов. Если вы говорите про разницу в культуре, то приведите примеры и аргументацию на основе конкретных причин закрытия. Без фактов отсылки к "особенностям" — это демагогия.

Comment: __I__ _В них каждое слово высечено потом и кровью._ – На английском, в контексте англоязычных культурных норм. _Ни одному сайту не давалось права изобретать на их месте что-то своё_ – наше сообщество не просто другой сайт, мы – другая культура. Теоретически, единственное, что останавливает нас от уменьшения или увеличения количества причин на первой панели – необходимость внесения изменений в коде.

Comment: __II__ _надо избегать причин, которые легко интерпретировать неверно_ – полностью согласен с вами. По конкретному примеру идет дискуссия. Уверен, мы придем к решению.  _ их текст должен быть мотивирован разницей в тематике с остальными сайтами_ – вовсе нет, причины должны соответствовать лишь набору наиболее распространенных ошибок.

Comment: __III__ _про разницу в культуре, то приведите примеры и аргументацию на основе конкретных причин закрытия._ – разница заключается в формировании аргументов и их восприятию. Конкретно? Каждый из нас знает, в английском языке важен порядок слов в предложении, в русском – нет. Фраза на русском языке может иметь очень много смысловых оттенков. Делая перевод, мы допускаем две грубых ошибки: 1) исходим из англ. формулировки, смысловой оттенок которой до конца понятен лишь носителям языка, а не реальной проблемы. 2) калька даже не несет туже смысловую нагрузку, и вполне возможно, опускается вообще.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky И опять куча общих слов. Ещё и порядок слов вспомнили. Я сказал же: хочу конкретный пример. Это значит, что вы берёте ваш "unclear" и аргументируете выбор слов в нём с точки зрения "культурных норм", чтобы доказать его превосходство над оригинальным переводом или текщим MVCE.