# «Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу»

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия

В заголовке — цитата из текущего уведомления о причине закрытия (полный текст для справки приведён ниже).

А вот ярчайший пример буквального следования данному совету: [Помогите с курсовой (Язык С), нужно реализовать очередь. Не понимаю как задать очередь со структурами [требует правки]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/970828/178576) (к сожалению, пока я писал, автор уже удалил вопрос).

По шагам:

1. автор вопроса скопировал описание задачи.
2. такие вопросы полагается закрывать — его закрыли.
3. автор вопроса **буквально** последовал совету — т.е. дописал 94 строки кода.

Возникает (абсолютно риторический) вопрос: **чем** эти 94 строки кода помогут понять, что же у автора вопроса не получилось, т.е. **как** ему помочь? (ответ: ничем и никак)

---

Моё **предложение**: надо как-то скорректировать текст причины закрытия. да хоть ссылку на [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) привести. или позаимствовать оттуда какое-то краткое резюме. или хотя бы убрать эту фразу (вынесенную в заголовок).

---

Близкие по тематике обсуждения:

- [Причина "Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи" применяется не так, как задумывалась изначально](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6189/178576)
- [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 3: “текст задачи” — это не отсутствие кода!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5953/178576)

---

Полный текст причины закрытия (выделение — как в оригинале):

> **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Насколько я помню, эту причину вводили не для того, чтобы прояснить детали задачи автора, а для того, чтобы была формальная причина закрывать вопросы, которые автор не потрудился решить сам (не показал, что действительно пытался решить задачу до того, как запостил ее на SO). Т.е. суть причины - именно в этой фразе, которую вы предлагаете убрать. Для "покажи mcve" есть другие стандартные причины закрытия. Предполагалось, что закрывающие как-то оценят (угадают), пытался автор решить задачу, или нет. Так что формально - да, вопрос надо было переоткрыть после правки автора.

Comment: Эту причину давно пора вообще прибить.

Comment: @Qwertiy И какой пользоваться в таких случаях?...

Comment: У баракина заголовок с большой буквы... OMG, всем шампанского... а, не, это всего лишь цитата. Расходимся.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ надо запилить бота, который бы расставлял Заглавные буквы у данного пользователя в его сообщениях)

Comment: очень был бы полезен бот, который банит за праздные разговорчики в строю^w комментариях.

Comment: @Harry Есть целых две причины. Я [обычно выбираю](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49648562#49648562) "непонятна суть вопроса" (потому что он на первой странице), [другой вариант](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49648745#49648745) "слишком общий". И часто "нет mvce" можно закрыть.

Comment: @AK И что "непонятного" или "слишком общего" в вопросе "напишите мне программку по такому - очень точному - заданию"?...

Comment: @Qwertiy не согласен, что *причину закрытия по поводу учебных вопросов надо давно прибить.* Тогда предложи вариант, как поступать в ситуациях когда в период сессий студентура начинает скидывать сканы заданий, тестов и т.д., даже не трудясь перепечатать вводную информацию и внести хоть какие-то вразумительные объяснения что им надо и что конкретно не понятно. Просто "Срочно! Вот вам..."

Comment: @L.F.C., просьбой привести mcve.

Comment: @Qwertiy просьбы это классно, но всегда действенно

Comment: @L.F.C. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDqMn.png

Comment: @Qwertiy да, для закрытия по данным вопросам тоже подойдет, но мне кажется данная причина не отражает суть проблемы. Хотя, бывает в вопросе есть код (произвольный, даже не по теме) и как-бы уже не подходит причина с учебными вопросами в данной формулировке. Может саму причину лучше подкорректировать как-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy а если вопрос не про "помогите с отладкой", а напишите код?

Comment: @L.F.C. эту причину уже корректировали, несколько раз. Вот последняя правка https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6189/. Проблема не в том, что причина плохая, проблема в том, что [механизм закрытия создан для улучшения вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936). А не для преследования ленивых студентов. При попытках использовать его для уничтожения вопросов вылазят такие вот последствия.

Comment: @yolosora "Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.". Вполне подходит. Само по себе наличие задания - это не техническая проблема, и не повод тащить его на SO :)