# Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 2: "вопрос неясен" — это не MCVE/SSCCE!

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, нытьё

- [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 1: “опросники” должны умереть!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1924/%d0%92%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-stackoverflow-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-1-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c)
- **Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 2: “вопрос неясен” — это не MCVE/SSCCE!**

---

Добро пожаловать во вторую часть эпопеи, посвящённой разбору провала обсуждения "[Как должны выглядеть сообщения о закрытии вопроса?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/545/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)" и последствий необдуманных действий администрации, которые не были восприняты пользователями с энтузиазмом (на данный момент изменения произведены в соответствии с ответом с оценкой +4/−2).

Сегодняшняя тема обсуждения — причина закрытия вопроса *"unclear what you're asking"*, что в переводе на русский дословно означает *"неясно, что вы спрашиваете"*. Оригинальное пояснение:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Дословный перевод:

> Пожалуйста, поясните, в чём именно ваша проблема, или добавьте ещё подробностей, чтобы подчеркнуть, что именно вам требуется. В текущем виде сложно сказать, что именно вы спрашиваете. См. страницу "Как задавать вопросы" в справке для получения помощи в пояснении вопроса.

Что это означает? Только одно: **вопрос отсутствует**.

Например, приведён пример кода, но нет объяснения, что он делает и зачем. Например, описана ситуация, но нет пояснения, в чём проблема. Например, приведены шаги воспроизведения, но нет требуемого поведения. Например, вопрос полностью состоит из малосвязного текста, который даже специалисты в реверс-инжинеринге переводов Google Translate не могут дешифровать с десятой попытки.

В общем и целом: на вопрос невозможно ответить в принципе, так как вопрос не был сформулирован. Причина закрытия указывает автору, что отвечающие не обладают телепатическими способностями, и в вопрос нужно добавить собственно вопрос.

Что мы видим сейчас?

> *необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса*
>
> Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Разберём по пунктам.

1. *необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса* — уже заголовок в корне неверный. Уточнять "подробности вопроса" невозможно, потому что вопроса нет.
2. *Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы* — обожаемая отдельными пользователями старого Хэшкода ничего не значащая отписка, пришедшая из "шаблонных комментариев". Сама по себе она не несёт абсолютно никакого смысла: во-первых, качественный вопрос — далеко не всегда портянка на несколько страниц текста, скорее наоборот; во-вторых, для улучшения качества нужно добавлять не любые детали, а вполне конкретные.
3. *Для получения ответа* — вводный текст, мусор в чистом виде. Ответ можно получить и на закрытый вопрос, а открытость вопроса не гарантирует получение ответа.
4. *в чем именно вы видите проблему* — единственный кусок из оригинальной формулировки!
5. *как её воспроизвести* — кусок текста, спёртый из причины "MCVE" ("краткий, самодостаточный, воспроизводимый пример"), аналог известного в народе понятия "[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)" ("Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example"), адаптированный под реалии SO. Здесь он бесполезен: во-первых, потому что далеко не все вопросы требуют воспроизведения; во-вторых, потому что тогда, когда воспроизведение требуется, уже есть причина "MCVE".
6. *что вы хотите получить в результате* — опять кусок из "MCVE", см. выше, абсолютно аналогично.
7. *Приведите пример кода* — уже сто раз обсудили, что далеко не каждый вопрос должен содержать код. Более того, прямо сейчас в блоке "Важное на Мете" в самом верху висит прикреплённый вопрос "[Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)" как раз про это.

Так как изначальной мотивацией было добавить пояснения, что нужно сделать автору для исправления вопроса, и избежать неоднозначностей, а не вывернуть причину закрытия наизнанку, скрестив бульдога с носорогом, то, очевидно, цель совершенно не достигнута.

Предлагаю **вернуть оригинальную причину для закрытия** на родину, потому что даже дословная калька с большого СО несоразмеримо более понятна и однозначна. Кроме того, оригинальная причина не пытается быть всем сразу одновременно, не пытается отхватить кусок от "MCVE", а сводится к одному простому требованию: добавить собственно вопрос.

Comment: А третья часть будет? Хочу трилогию )

Comment: @NickVolynkin По каждой причине будет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Э... А смысл менять ссылки? Редирект лишний, если текст убрать. Кроме того, ФФ, например, подсказки к таким ссылкам красиво отображает.

Comment: https некорректно открывается, а текст лишний убрал заодно, на мой взгляд он ухудшает восприятие. Но про ссылки в ФФ — действительно так лучше, убедили.

Comment: Отлично, ждем следующих выпусков. Любопытно, что в каждом главный герой (причина закрытия) должен умереть жестокой смертью. Вы прямо-таки наш Джордж Мартин.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы понять, насколько новая формулировка способствует правильным закрытиям вопросов, просмотрим список [вопросов, закрытых по причине "unclear what you're asking"](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/294078/most-upvoted-questions-closed-for-a-specific-reason?topn=1000&reason=103) с испорченной формулировкой:

- [Креш Visual Studio 2013 в WinForms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414855/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88-visual-studio-2013-%d0%b2-winforms) - очень чётко и детально описанный вопрос, но проблема не воспроизводится у других (вероятна аппаратная проблема)
- [Какими средствами проще организовать клиент-серверное приложение с одним клиентом и множеством серверов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442091/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be) - too broad
- [Android разметка. Тень View элеменов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456392/android-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-view-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2) - нормальный вопрос, хоть и краткий, кандидат на переоткрытие
- [Поддержка кириллицы в С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439721/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%a1) - вопрос исправлен, но не переоткрыт
- [Не работает autoreconf в Debian 8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458178/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-autoreconf-%d0%b2-debian-8) - нормальный вопрос, возможно, mcve
- [Начало работы скрипта после прокрутки элемента (div)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437708/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-div) - совершенно нормальный вопрос с хорошим ответом, кандидат на переоткрытие
- [Делегация прав Клиент -> WCF сервис -> MSSQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/168785/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2-%d0%9a%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-wcf-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81-mssql) - совершенно нормальный вопрос, закрыт с дивной аргументацией: "Поскольку для автора этот вопрос вряд ли уже актуален, я считаю, его надо закрыть".
- [Структура данных для хранения миллионов точек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/290431/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba) - too broad
- [Exception: TypeInitializationException - The type initializer for ... threw an exception](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349664/exception-typeinitializationexception-the-type-initializer-for-threw-an-e) - почти нормальный вопрос, mcve, спасать уже поздно
- [Снятие выделения кнопки, расположенной на месте предыдущей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429830/%d0%a1%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9) - mcve в чистом виде
- [Как подружить PHP с консолью Google Chrome?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/297961/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-php-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%8e-google-chrome) - too broad, нет описания конкретной проблемы
- [Как добавить разделитель в Android OptionsMenu между элементами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/125459/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b2-android-optionsmenu-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8) - нормальный вопрос
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/30984/%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85 - third-party recommendation
- [Масштабирование ListView Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189209/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-listview-android) - судя по комментарию, дубликат
- [Ошибка с удалением\редактированием базы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/8726/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b) - mcve
- [Сравнение текстов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423496/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2) - third-party recommendation
- [Запуск одного окна один раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455649/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7) - нормальный вопрос, кандидат на переоткрытие
- [реализация алгоритма diff3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448700/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b0-diff3) - too broad

Продолжать не имеет смысла. Я просмотрел всего несколько десятков вопросов, но **подавляющее большинство** закрыто неверно (в том числе старых вопросов), причём это сделано после введения новых формулировок. Я даже представить не мог, что всё настолько плохо. По сути, **причина для закрытия используется неверно почти всегда**. Это катастрофа.

P. S. Комментарий автора вопроса "Креш Visual Studio 2013 в WinForms":

> Тему закрыли по причине: "Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы.". Не знаю как ещё подробнее, гг ))

Воистину, гг )), лол.

Comment: лично я, закрывая вопрос, конкретно предложил автору отладить студию. то, что он пропустил этот коммент - его проблемы :)

Comment: если серьезно - у автора валится коммерческий продукт. у которого есть официальный саппорт. автор не может даже стектрейс показать. как ему кто-то чем-то может помочь на SO? т.е. переоткроют вопрос - и что? придет саппорт MS и принесет ему ответ?

Comment: а в целом - наша причина "необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса" - это не аналог "unclear what you're asking". НУПВ применим к любой проблеме, где не хватает шагов для воспроизведения - в пояснении к причине так и написано **поясните ... как её (проблему) воспроизвести**.

Comment: Поясню по поводу своей "дивной" аргументации. (Она и правда "дивная", но я несколько косноязычен, а тратить час на написание правильной формулировки я тогда не мог). Проблемы, подобные этой, требуют длительной отладки, перебора разных вариантов, изучения тонкостей работы системы. Ответить на подобный вопрос в отрыве от конкретной неработающей связки - невозможно. И для того, чтобы день, два или даже неделю все это настраивать, отлаживать и проверять - нужна сильная заинтересованность в ответе. Такая, которая есть только у автора вопроса.

Comment: Но баг подобный такому, не может жить 3 года - его давно уже либо исправили (не написав ответа сюда), либо обошли. А потому мы имеем ровно ноль человек, которые могут проверить предложенные решения, сообщить дополнительную информацию о проблеме - и сказать, как же в итоге проблема была решена. А без этого ни один ответ полезным не будет. Если же такая проблема возникнет у кого-то еще - он, скорее всего, задаст новый вопрос. Поэтому старый вопрос не нужен никому.

Answer (score -3):

К сожалению (или к счастью), “вопрос неясен” — это именно MCVE/SSCCE - или, по крайней мере, очень близкая к ним по формулировке причина.

Попытка дословно перевести причины с enSO не сработала. Некоторе переводы восприняли как есть, некоторые - начали использовать не по назначению. Причины этого до конца не ясны (но я считаю что виноват переводчик!). В числе "ужасных" переводов оказался "unclear what you're asking" который был переведен как "непонятна суть вопроса".

Причину начали использовать в полном соответствии с ее русской формулировкой. Т.е. человек с высоким рейтингом по PHP открывал вопрос по C#, пытался его осознать, и ставил "непонятна суть вопроса".

Это попытались исправить - [Как должны выглядеть сообщения о закрытии вопроса?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/545/)

Новая формулировка полностью изменила суть оригинальной причины. По сути, причина была **заменена** на гибрид "Unclear" + "MCVE/SSCCE".

Упоминание "как её воспроизвести" сделало ее идеальной для закрытия вопросов, в которых не хватает деталей для воспроизведения вопросов. Суть причины поменялась с "вообще непонятно чего вы хотите" на "почти понятно что у вас не так, но скажите как это воспроизвести".

В сочетании с тем, что причины MCVE/SSCCE у нас нет (есть "помогите с отладкой без MCVE/SSCCE"), это сделало причину отлично применимой к некоторым вопросам, которые на enSO оффтопик, а у нас, в силу специфики - нет. Например, к вопросам по администрированию (шагов нет, MCVE/SSCCE нет, просьбы с отладкой - это ж не программирование - тоже нет).

Кроме того, новая формулировка полностью включает в себя вопросы об отладке без MCVE/SSCCE - а находится она ближе в меню закрытия.

---

Вопрос не в том, является ли текущая причина “вопрос неясен” аналогом "unclear what you're asking" - достаточно очевидно, что не является, ни по формулировке (совпадает пару слов), ни по целевым вопросам (почти не пересекается).

Вопрос в том, нужна ли нам причина-аналог "unclear what you're asking"?

При этом, насколько я понял, [официальная позиция администрации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1606/%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0#comment4671_1609) - "прямые переводы нам не нужны".

Из-за ее отсутствия сейчас на "unclear" вопросы ставят "опросник".

Лично я считаю, что нужна, но в совершенно отличной от “вопрос неясен” и “непонятна суть вопроса” формулировке. В какой именно - наверное, стоит обсудить отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Если у нас проблемы с отсутствием причины для закрытия вопросов SU, SF, CR и других, то нужно добавлять причины, а не изменять их. Так как у нас сайт всеобъемлющий, то с проталкиванием причин не должно быть особых проблем. На каждую тематику я бы добавил причину в духе "Вопрос тематики [SU/SF/CR] должен следовать таким-то правилам [SU/SF/CR]". Отсутствие шагов для воспроизведения — это лишь одна из проблем, нужны конкретные причины.

Comment: Имеющаяся причина с MVCE по духу именно "предоставьте идеальный баг-репорт" (шаги воспроизведения, желаемое, полученное), выросло оно из SSCCE, просто из-за использования на большом СО формулировки подогнаны конкретно под код. Никто не запрещает расширить эту причину, потому что по духу именно она и соответствует описываемой вами проблеме с вопросами.

Comment: Если вы считаете, что причина "unclear" чаще других использовалась не по назначению, причём именно теми, кто не разбирается в теме, то приведите данные, пожалуйста. Так или иначе, я и сейчас встречаю, когда вопрос закрывают те, кто в теме не разбираются. Изменением формулировки здесь не поможешь — эти люди банально нарушают правила, и в случае чего могут запросто писать собственные причины, чем, к слову, многие регулярно и занимаются, закрывая неугодные их вкусам вопросы.

Comment: Короче, бороться в нарушителями, то есть теми, кто намеренно нарушает правила или банально не отличается умом и сообразительностью с помощью подбора слов — пустая трата времени. Таких людей надо сначала предупреждать, а при повторении нарушений банить. Формулировки причин в первую очередь должны быть для авторов вопросов.

Comment: @Discord ок, так предложите конкретные изменения по конкретным причинам закрытия. нытье "все поломали" - неконструктивно. Насчет бана - предлагаете забанить себя же? :) цитирую: - [>> "Причина там Just For Fun. На сайте все причины закрытия изуродованы, от этого у меня попаболь, которая выливается в выбор причин по желанию левой пятки](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25842067#25842067)

Comment: @Discord тем не менее - те, кто использует "необходимо уточнить вопрос" к MVCE - действуют полностью в рамках правил. Они не могут (и не обязаны!) телепатить - что ж там именно Николас хотел выразить пол года назад где-то на мете. Хотите чтобы у нас **появилась** причина "unclear what you're asking"  - проводите голосованием.

Comment: @Discord лично я хочу чтобы она появилась, а причины "опросник" и, возможно  "необходимо уточнить вопрос", сгинули. но нормальную формулировку придумать не могу. К тому же попытки поменять хоть одно слово в формулировке упираются в какую-то непроницаемую стену со стороны администрации.

Comment: Моё конкретное предложение: вернуть всё назад. Когда сайт был только создан, unclear, opinion и broad были переводами. Они и должны ими остаться. Возможно, стоит чуть подправить литературность. ВСЁ. / Что касается нарушений, то вопрос в объёме и последствиях. Что один из пяти проголосовавших закрыл вопрос с не самой подходящей причиной — последствий ноль. / И как я уже 10 раз сказал, я не виню юзеров, которые используют unclear как MVCE. В этом вина администрации.

Comment: @Discord судя по ситуации с "опросником" -  вернуть назад нельзя. но "это повод задуматься о решении (с)"!

Answer (score -3):

#### «За жизнь»

В данном вопросе, по большей мере, содержится сравнение имеющейся причины закрытия и причины закрытия взятой из сообщества другого размера с другими культурными нормами. Само сравнение происходит в контексте разбора лишь одной формулировки, что, по сути, нельзя назвать сути сравнением. Более верный термин в нашем случае – критика. Но что самое важно, к сожалению, публикация не содержит главного – рекомендаций по улучшению.

Пожалуйста, приведите конкретные предложения по улучшению с учетом публикации «[Зачем на сайте присутствует функционал закрытия вопросов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/)».

Как мне кажется, сравнение двух вариантов не лучший подход, так как может существовать третье, более верное решение. Если по вашему мнению данная формулировка неуместна, возможно ее стоит удалить вообще, а на ее место добавить совершенно новую?

Для формирования новой причины необходимо описать популярную ошибку публикации вопросов, шаблонные критерии ошибки, способы улучшения, подкрепив призывом к действию. Это и будет новая формулировка причины закрытия.

#### По поводу критики

Хочу подчеркнуть, что, как мне кажется, @PashaPash правильно понял проблему. Нам, сообществу, не нужны переводы, нам даже не нужен точный аналогичный список причин закрытия. Нам надо понять типичные ошибки публикации вопросов и описать их, дополнив рекомендациями по улучшению.

По приведенным выше пунктам можно спорить достаточно долго. Один, из возможны вариантов ответа.

1. > *необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса* — уже заголовок в корне неверный. Уточнять "подробности вопроса" невозможно, потому что вопроса нет.

   Формулировка причины создавалась исходя из конкретной проблемы – вопросов низкого качества. Наиболее типичный представитель этой категории (как минимум на момент создания формулировки) – крайне короткий вопрос, не раскрывающей всех деталей проблемы. Например, «У меня ошибка ERROR #NNN, как исправить?». Такие вопросы не соответствуют критериям, не потому что в них не содержится вопроса, а потому что без деталей не ясно как помочь человеку. <sub>(Если исходить из позиции жесткой критики, то в русском языке вопрос содержится в любой фразе с вопросительным знаком на конце.)</sub>.
2. > *Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы* — обожаемая отдельными пользователями старого Хэшкода ничего не значащая отписка, пришедшая из "шаблонных комментариев". Сама по себе она не несёт абсолютно никакого смысла: во-первых, качественный вопрос — далеко не всегда портянка на несколько страниц текста, скорее наоборот; во-вторых, для улучшения качества нужно добавлять не любые детали, а вполне конкретные.

   Соглашусь. Достаточно общая рекомендация, более того, больше далеко не всегда значит лучше. Опять же, формулировка пишется исходя из наличия систематической типичной ошибки. В рекомендациях необходимо включить наиболее популярные способы исправления вопроса. Исходя из пункта 1) первой рекомендацией будет писать более развернуто. Кроме того, пожалуйста, помните, далеко не все люди понимают одну и ту же фразу одинаково, как результат, в формулировке, на мой взгляд, должна присутствовать обобщенная рекомендация, понятная как можно более широкой аудитории.
3. > *Для получения ответа* — вводный текст, мусор в чистом виде. Ответ можно получить и на закрытый вопрос, а открытость вопроса не гарантирует получение ответа.

   Да, вводный, но не мусор. Для задающего вопрос человека самое главное – получить решение. Согласитесь, в большинстве случаев, это вообще единственная причина публикации вопроса. На мой взгляд, для человека не до конца понимающего уровень знаний сообщества Stack Overflow на русском, намного проще скопировать вопрос и вставить в форму публикации сообщения на одном из множества форумов–свалок информации, где ничего не закрывают, правда, бывает, поливают «помоями» в ответ. Фразой «*Для получения ответа*» мы стимулируем коллегу собраться с духом и осилить написание качественного вопроса.

4.

> *в чем именно вы видите проблему* — единственный кусок из оригинальной формулировки!

Нет. Там нет такой фразы. «clarify your specific problem» – «уточните вашу конкретную проблему», «to highlight exactly what you need» – «чтобы подчеркнуть именно то, что вам нужно», причем последний перевод кардинально отличается от подвергнутой критике фразы. Мысль о равнозначности перевода, с большой вероятностью, пришла вам на ум потому что вы видите существующую формулировку перед глазами. Исходный перевод был другой. Это еще один наглядный пример, что «в споре рождает истина». Уверен, продолжая дискуссию мы вместе придем к наиболее корректной формулировке.

5. > как её воспроизвести — кусок текста, спёртый из причины "MCVE" ("краткий, самодостаточный, воспроизводимый пример"), аналог известного в народе понятия "SSCCE" ("Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example"), адаптированный под реалии SO. Здесь он бесполезен: во-первых, потому что далеко не все вопросы требуют воспроизведения; во-вторых, потому что тогда, когда воспроизведение требуется, уже есть причина "MCVE".

   Формулировка была создана еще за долго до существования MCVE, как минимум на русском языке. На мой взгляд, не верно 1) классифицировать её как «спертую», 2) да и вообще, каким либо образом проводить сравнение. «*как её воспроизвести*» – это один из шаблонных советов исправления типичной ошибки. В общем и целом аналогично пункту 2).
6. > *что вы хотите получить в результате* — опять кусок из "MCVE", см. выше, абсолютно аналогично.

   Аналогично предыдущему пункту.
7. > *Приведите пример кода* — уже сто раз обсудили, что далеко не каждый вопрос должен содержать код. Более того, прямо сейчас в блоке "Важное на Мете" в самом верху висит прикреплённый вопрос "Работа за автора" как раз про это.

   Аналогично предыдущему пункту.

Я за текущую формулировку в сравнение с переводом, так как, на мой взгляд, она в наилучшем виде, из мне известных, описывает типичную проблему и шаблонные способы её исправления.

> дословная калька с большого СО несоразмеримо более понятна и однозначна

Субъективно, не верно, на мой субъективный взгляд.

Comment: *"В данном вопросе, по большей мере, содержится сравнение имеющейся причины закрытия и причины закрытия взятой из сообщества другого размера с другими культурными нормами."* — Вы постоянно ссылаетесь на некие "культурные нормы", но никогда не приводите ни одного *реального* аргумента с отсылкой на конкретные примеры. Кроме "нельзя, потому что нельзя" я ничего не слышал. / *"Но что самое важно, к сожалению, публикация не содержит главного – рекомендаций по улучшению."* — А в самом конце вопроса что жирным выделено? / *"Наиболее типичный представитель этой категории"* — покрывается MVCE.

Comment: "*Фразой «Для получения ответа» мы стимулируем коллегу собраться с духом*" — и нагло обманываем, по указанным мной причинам. Кроме того, такая вводная фраза верна для абсолютно всех причин — почему же она тогда только в одной? / *"Формулировка была создана еще за долго до существования MVCE"* — MVCE появился раньше. Конкретно: создан 2015-04-20, удалён 2015-07-01, пересоздан 2015-07-01. См. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats

Comment: _и нагло обманываем_ – не верно. Мы говорим, что чтобы получить ответ, надо поправить, без исправления вопрос останется закрытым, как результат, система не даст возможность публикации ответа. _но никогда не приводите ни одного реального аргумента с отсылкой на конкретные примеры._ – надеюсь, что ответил в другом ваше вопросе.

Comment: Как я уже сказал, ответ можно получить и в комментарии, а открытый вопрос не гарантирует ответ. И вы проигнорировали вторую часть про то, что вводная часть только в одной причине почему-то.