# Причины закрытия сломаны. Давайте их починим!

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Предметом обсуждения являются причины с первой страницы диалога закрытия вопроса:

[image: обсуждаемые причины в диалоге закрытия]

> **необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса**
> Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.
>
> **необходимо конкретизировать вопрос**
> В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.
>
> **необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ**
> Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

**В качестве ответов к этому вопросу предлагаю оставлять ваши варианты для этих трёх причин, а также голосовать за или против уже оставленных вариантов.**

**Если вы уже готовы выразить собственное мнение по этой проблеме, дальше читать необязательно.** Остаток вопроса — для тех, кто [ещё] не знает, в чём именно проблема и почему нужно что-то решать, и по совместительству моя точка зрения на проблему. Я ожидаю увидеть в ответах, кроме вариантов решения, другие точки зрения.

---

### В чём проблемы?

#### 1. Это не причины! (это руководство по устранению недостатков!)

Они все начинаются со слова "необходимо". Чтобы получить из них причину, нужно совершить нетривиальное смысловое преобразование в сознании, которое для разных участников может дать разные результаты.

От **причин закрытия** ожидается ответ на вопрос *"что с вопросом не так?"*. Ответ на вопрос *"что делать?"* это уже дополнительная информация, которая должна размещаться в соответствующем месте: *в пояснении*. *Кстати, она там уже есть.* И именно ответ на вопрос "что с вопросом не так?" ожидается в **большой пугающей надписи**:

> объявлен *<когда-то>* требующим правки пользователями *<...>*, так как **<что-то не так>**

Почему это важно? Потому что **это обосновывает поведение сообщества**. **Когда реальная причина не написана, берётся самая простая возможная причина.** Проще всего объяснить закрытие причиной "кому-то в верхушке сообщества не понравился мой вопрос". Ах это не так? *Объяснять уже поздно!*

Чего-то недоговаривая, мы оставляем в мыслях новых участников пустые места, которые они вольны заполнять выводами **не** в нашу пользу, искажая при этом факты. И когда выводы будут сделаны и пущены в дело, будет уже неважно, кто в этом виноват.

#### 2. Первые две причины сливаются!

"Уточнить подробности" и "конкретизировать" имеют нехилое пересечение по значению, из-за этого соответствующие причины закрытия сливаются в формулировках и между ними тяжело выбрать. О разнице чётко знают лишь опытные участники, каковыми, скорее всего, являются почти все посетители Меты. Давайте подумаем об остальных и сделаем формулировки доходчивее.

К сожалению, урон этим уже нанесён, но попробуем исправить ситуацию, максимально выделив различия. Из формулировок следует, что обе причины исправляются путём внесения в вопрос дополнительной информации. Но какой? Где грань?

#### 3. Малая "удельная осмысленность".

*Это честно выдуманная величина, отношение смысла текста к его объёму.*

Косметическая причина, частично вытекающая из первой. Помните, что причины закрытия это одна из самых заметных вещей для несостоявшихся (поначалу) новичков, поскольку именно они отгораживают их от возможности получить ответ на собственный вопрос.

Причина должна быть выражена максимально выразительно, коротко и ясно. Возможно, даже выразительнее, чем она есть на самом деле. Чтобы новые участники редактировали свои вопросы, можно либо показать им пошаговую инструкцию по исправлению...

...а можно несколько преувеличить проблемы в вопросе, вызвав ощущение "но это же не так, вы не так поняли!", что само по себе вызывает желание отредактировать собственный вопрос. Может быть. Если этим эффектом злоупотребить, можно *потерять* нового участника.

Насколько велика угроза *потери* новичков? Не слишком, если вспомнить, что **закрывают вопросы тоже участники**, которые эти причины видят *даже чаще*. И когда в причинах закрытия написаны *действительно громкие заявления/обвинения*, стоит дважды подумать, прежде чем голосовать за закрытие. Закрывающие станут осторожнее с голосами. В теории.

#### 4. Пояснения строят шаткие предположения о вопросе

Не все вопросы требуют приведения примера именно **кода**. Не все проблемы есть смысл воспроизводить. Это игра в "угадайку" про все вопросы, которые будут у нас когда-либо заданы.

Когда "официальные советы" неприменимы к заданному вопросу, новый участник с большей вероятностью уйдёт, не видя способов привести вопрос в точное соответствие с ними.

Сделанные в причинах предположения отсекают множество интересных "высокоуровневых" вопросов, вызывающих поддержку (в виде голосов) в сообществе.

*Предположения*, сделанные в пояснениях, стоит обозначить *необязательностью* или *условиями*. К сожалению, это резко добавит им объёма, поэтому стоит рассмотреть возможность *убрать их вовсе*.

---

**Ожидается, что сообщество выразит своё мнение, создав наиболее положительный рейтинг у выбранного варианта.**

***Всё ещё идёт сбор вариантов.**

...но голосовать уже есть смысл. Радикально новые точки зрения на проблему уже вряд ли появятся.*

***Приняты [первые меры](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3639/181100)!**

[Один из ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3601/181100) оказался достаточно убедительным, чтобы провести по его мотивам эксперимент с заменой первых двух причин на более прямые переводы оригинала.*

---

### См. также

- [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 2: “вопрос неясен” — это не MCVE/SSCCE!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1931/%D0%92%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-stackoverflow-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-mcve-sscce)
- [Зачем на сайте присутствует функционал закрытия вопросов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Уже был такой вопрос же?

Comment: @Qwertiy если вы [об этом](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1931/%D0%92%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-stackoverflow-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-mcve-sscce), то нет: там выдвигается конкретное предложение (с которым я частично согласен) и обсуждается именно оно. К тому же, вопрос задан довольно давно, но проблема всё ещё существует. Вообще надо оформить секцию **См. также**.

Comment: "Это не причины! (это руководство по устранению недостатков!)" - как ни странно, они и должны быть именно руководством по устранению недостатков. Это прямо сказано в топике http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/, в разделе "для кого закрываются вопросы". Само по себе закрытие - указание автору, что вопрос "требует правки", причем именно правки от *самого автора*. А не просто несет в себе какие-то недостатки.

Comment: Именно поэтому причина "непонятна суть вопроса" была ужасной - она приводила к тому, что люди закрывали непонятные им вопросы. Т.е. натурально собиралось пару человек со знанием PHP и закрывало вопрос по C#. И такое случалось регулярно. Пока причину не убрали.

Comment: @PashaPash ага, и у этого топика всего десяток голосов и **один минус** (и не мой). Учитывая то, сколько он существует, описанное в нём может быть несколько *под углом* к мнению сообщества, раз столько людей воздержалось от голосования.

Comment: @PashaPash если кто-то её снова предложит, можете поставить за неё минус и прокомментировать :)

Comment: @D-side тем не менее,  раньше причины были оформены именно в виде "причин" - и ими злоупотребляли. Пока остановились на том, что мы не "закрываем" вопросы. Мы "требуем правки".  "Причина" совершенна неважна. Важно явно показать, какая именно правка требуется. Нельзя написать пользователю "требуется правка потому что вопрос непонятен" - ему же вопрос понятен. И его обычная реакция на такое - раз вам, пяти закрывающим, вопрос не понятен - не пройти ли бы вам мимо, непонятливым.

Comment: @PashaPash это беда именно с тем, что это были "причины"? Или всё-таки неудачной их формулировкой? Беда с концепцией или её конкретной испытанной реализацией? А причины "вопрос непонятен" пока ещё никто не предложил. И я её не предлагаю.

Comment: @D-side беда в том, что это были именно причины. Так что я не согласен только с (1) из вашего поста. С тем, что текущие текстовки можно улучшить, я полностью согласен :)

Comment: @PashaPash я не вижу, где описанные ситуации возникли именно из-за того, что это были причины. Описанное "вопрос непонятен" у меня немедленно вызывает вопрос "кому? модератору? он может не понимать! всем? а вы всех спросили?". Я считаю, что можно лучше. Собственно, я уже пишу ответ (спойлер: первую причину предлагается заменить фразой *отсутствует чёткий вопрос* с другим пояснением), но за сегодня не успею. Обсудим позже. Может ещё кто подтянется :)

Comment: Неа, не об этом. Было посвежее. Надо искать.

Comment: @D-side http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3419/Заголовки-причин-закрытия-вопроса?rq=1 - даже скриншот то же

Comment: @PashaPash близко, но не совсем то. Он предлагает исправить только "краткие описания", сделав их выразительнее для своих пояснений. Я предлагаю исправить причины целиком, вместе с пояснениями.

Comment: Забавно, голосующие лишь молча минусуют, не признаваясь, что именно им не понравилось. Итого все варианты плохи, и что с этим делать, никто не знает.

Comment: @D-side Я постарался показать в ответе, что я не понимаю проблемы, которую мы пытаемся решить. «Считаю другую формулировку более понятной» – не проблема. Все мы разные, понимание – разное.  Пожалуйста, укажите более явно проблему, которую мы решим изменением формулировок, то есть что улучшиться в системе с их изменением, предположительно, на сколько? Обратите внимание на [требования к предложению внесения изменений](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1936/6).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я обстоятельно описал проблемы в вопросе. А недавно ещё и дополнил описание первой проблемы, о том, почему она всё же является проблемой. Последние две причины не столь серьёзны. Заметьте также, что ответ "оставить существующие причины" собрал пачку минусов и всего один плюс. И что сам вопрос собрал уже почти десяток плюсов. Сообщество тоже явно считает, что текущие причины закрытия (кхм) **требуют правки**.

Comment: @D-side Буду рад внести изменения, как только будут представлены убедительные доводы эффективности новых формулировок. Вторая ссылка в конце вопроса ведет на публикацию с конкретными пунктами, которые надо детально рассмотреть в любом предложении изменения. На данный момент,  к сожалению, большенство доводов в заявках «против» текущий – субъективны.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky из перечисленных в вопросе проблем субъективна лишь проблема 3. Остальные указывают, как именно существующие причины вводят в заблуждение тех или иных участников. Возможно, в ответах стоит явно указывать, что вариант исправляет какие-то из них. Но меня, в первую очередь, интересует мнение сообщества о проблеме и жизнеспособность конкретных вариантов (с доводами *за* и *против*).

Comment: Вопрос нашёлся: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3419/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy вы чуть опоздали, его уже упомянули выше и я это уже прокомментировал :)

Answer (score 8):

**Я предлагаю убрать нынешние синонимичные названия причин (которые по сути являются описанием исправлений) и заменить их на перевод оригинальных названий (над вариантами мы можем поработать):**

- **непонятна суть вопроса**
- **вопрос слишком общий**

Проблема нынешних формулировок в следующем:

- в *названия* причин пробрались *описания* исправлений
- фразы "уточнить подробности" и "конкретизировать" являются синонимами

В результате мы имеем две причины с *одинаковым* названием. Однако эти причины предназначены для *разных* категорий вопросов.

Первая обсуждаемая причина предназначена для вопросов, в которых непонятно, что хочет узнать автор. Яркий пример такого вопроса -- приведен кусок кода без всяких пояснений. Как описать проблему такого вопроса? **Неясна суть вопроса**. Как исправить такой вопрос? **Добавить детали: пояснить, в чем проблема, что хочется получить, добавить код (если нужно).**

Вторая обсуждаемая причина предназначена для вопросов, которые охватывают слишком широкую область. Яркий пример такого вопроса -- как разработать веб-сайт. Как описать проблему такого вопроса? **Вопрос слишком общий**. Как исправить такой вопрос? **Сузить: например, указать, что нужна статическая домашняя страничка**.

Как видим, необходимые для исправления действия совпадают: так или иначе в вопрос нужно добавить дополнительную информацию/детали/конкретику. Но исходные причины закрытия разные!

Я согласен с тем, что в *описании* причины должно быть указано, как устранить проблему. Но в *названии* причины должно быть указано, что именно не так. *Что не так* и *как исправить* -- это не одно и то же!

Процитирую выдержку из темы ["Зачем на сайте присутствует функционал закрытия вопросов?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1936/106):

> Самое важное, чтобы автор вопроса предельно ясно понимал:
>
> - что именно не так с вопросом;
> - какие конкретные шаги следует проделать, чтобы исправить вопрос.

Здесь мы видим ту же схему: есть *что не так* и есть *как исправить*. Название причины и описание причины. Сейчас же у нас есть только совпадающие "как исправить" в кратком и развернутом вариантах. Но нет указания "что не так". Говорится о том, что причины закрытия -- не для закрывающих, а для авторов вопросов. Так действительно ли они понятны? Действительно ли автор поймет, *почему* он должен редактировать вопрос, глядя на формулировки "необходимо уточнить подробности" и "необходимо конкретизировать"?

К тому же, я бы уточнил: *названия* причин -- они в том числе и для закрывающих. Именно закрывающие должны верно указать "что не так". А сейчас я, как закрывающий, путаюсь в двух соснах, потому что не могу вспомнить (именно вспомнить, потому что сейчас они одинаковые), какая причина для какой категории вопросов.

Comment: Да! Но беда в том, что "оригинальные причины" на английском и относятся к другим сообществам. Впрочем, это не мешает предлагать в качестве вариантов переводы и оценивать их на применимость к нашему. Возможно, **сами варианты** стоит вынести в самый верх ответа, чтобы было проще ориентироваться, **что** предлагается и **почему**.

Comment: @D-side переместил. "Оригинальные причины" естественно в переводе :).

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [требования к предложению внесения изменений](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1936/6).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky мне создать еще два вопроса? По-моему, уже и так достаточно тем обсуждают эти две злосчастные причины.

Comment: @andreycha Проблема в том, что каждый раз предложение выглядит «Я считаю, что надо по другому». На сайте зарегистрировано почти 50К человек. И все считают по–разному. Текущие причины были выведены на основе анализа количества повторно открываемых вопросов на ХэшКоде, а затем скорректированы согласно запросу сообщества. Каждый новый вариант, потенциально, может как улучшить, так и _ухудшить систему_! Наша задача – не допустить ухудшения. К сожалению, на мой взгляд, варианты «я считаю будте лучше так» тяжело рассматривать без относительно критериев.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky критерии -- это те четыре пункта, верно?

Comment: Что еще интересней, как появляются новые запросы. Обычно, кто–то из участников после посещения Stack Overflow на английском задается вопросом, а почему у нас не прямой перевод (как, кстати, произошло и в данном случае). И главный аргумент дискуссий – на английском не так. Почему–то не учитывается ни то, что англоязычное сообщество на два порядка больше, ни то, что ему в несколько раз больше лет (более сформировавшиеся), ни то, что оно англоязычное (другой менталитет, другой способ изложения материал).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky рассматривать изменения в **названиях** этих двух причин по отдельности -- смысла нет. Потому что по отдельности они работают. Вся проблема в том, что вместе они создают путаницу.

Comment: @andreycha Да, на данный момент именно они.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky проблема не в прямом переводе. Посмотрите на мой пост внимательнее. Проблема в одинаковости названий двух разных причин. Прямой перевод -- это всего лишь способ решения.

Comment: Я к тому, как появился запрос. Как я вижу, не от реальной проблемы, а от того, что у нас в сообществе что–то по–другому. Далее, мы пытаемся найти проблему для нужного решения. Проблема – плохие вопросы. Предлагаемое решение – закрытие вопросов так, чтобы они либо улучшались (открывались повторно), либо удалялись. Почему предложенные изменения положительно повлияют на систему? Большенство тех, чьи вопросы закрывают никогда не видел этого механизма вообще.

Comment: Более того, кто вообще сказал, что в название причин – это название, а не краткая характеристика с идущим ниже комментарием–пояснением?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну что вы прицепились-то к этой разнице? Конкретно мой запрос сначала в чате, а потом тут появился от реальной проблемы -- мне каждый раз приходится напрягать мозг и вспоминать, какая из двух причин за что отвечает. Ну и если говорить об авторах и о ценности, то описания "добавьте деталей, уточните вопрос" вкупе с разными названиями причин "вопрос слишком общий"/"неясна суть вопроса" дадут лучшее понимание, почему вопрос был закрыт и какие именно изменения требуются.

Comment: Разве, если задается «слишком общий» вопрос из этого не следует то, что вопрос «непонятен»? Чем англоязычный вариант лучше?

Comment: @andreycha Для задающего нет разных причин! Для него есть одна, так с которой вопрос был закрыт!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky совершенно не следует. Вопрос может быть хорошим, но, к сожалению, не подходящим под формат SO. Более того, непонятному вопросу вообще сложно прицепить характеристику "слишком общий", просто потому, что он непонятен.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky правильно. Разные причины -- они для закрывающих. Чтоб закрывающий точно указал, что не так с вопросом. И?

Comment: В случае с «конкретизируйте» – тоже самое! Разве нет?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я пытаюсь донести, что более точные названия причин помогут и закрывающим, и авторам.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky что "тоже самое"? С "конкретизируйте" проблема в том, что оно является синонимом "уточните подробности".

Comment: На мой взгляд, фраза «необходимо конкретизировать» намного более полезна, чем «слишком общий». Первая – говорит, что надо сделать, вторая – ставит штамп, не более, но что с этим делать, не ясно. Подсажите, каким образом вторая может быть полезней?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вот вы сейчас противоречите написанным вами же критериями, что причина должна обозначать "что не так" и "как исправить". Нынешние формулировки говорят только "как исправить". О том, "что не так", нужно догадываться. А этот самый "штамп" как раз и должен четко отвечать на вопрос "что не так". Это первая из описанных в моем ответе проблем. А вторая в том, что "необходимо конкретизировать" и "необходимо уточнить подробности" несут одинаковый смысл, что затрудняет и их различение для закрывающих, и понимание "что не так" для исправляющего.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky повторюсь, я говорю только об изменении формулировок названий. Описания уже достаточны и несут в себе ответ на вопрос "как исправить".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky *"кто вообще сказал, что в название причин – это название, а не краткая характеристика с идущим ниже комментарием–пояснением"* -- закрытие вопроса можно рассматривать как ошибку, которую юзер получает от системы. А хорошие описания ошибок всегда складываются из двух вещей: что пошло не так и как это можно исправить. Если указать только первую часть, юзер будет ломать голову, как ему сделать по-другому. Если же оставить только вторую часть, юзеру будет непонятно, почему он должен делать по-другому. Только четкие "что" и "как" вместе несут нужное количество информации.

Comment: «Необходимо конкретизировать» – вопрос не конкретный, то есть слишком общий. То есть из названия следует проблема. Возможно, для меня формулировки слишком очевидны (поэтому и проблем не вижу). Попробую еще раз обдумать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky *"то есть слишком общий"* -- ну так зачем идти окольными путями, если можно написать прямо и понятно? :) Повторюсь, сейчас в причинах присутствует только часть "как исправить" в кратком и развернутом вариантах, но нет четкого "что не так", о нем автор должен догадываться самостоятельно. Обдумайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky внес в ответ некоторые аргументы из нашей дискуссии. Будет хорошо, если вы на свежую голову прочитаете его еще раз.

Comment: @andreycha Чтобы хоть как–то сдвинуться с мертвой точки, предлагаю поступить следующим образом. Мы меняем названия причин, а по истечению некоторого срока, например, месяца, оцениваем, как изменилось соотношение закрытых вопросов к общему количеству вопросов. Что скажите?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky разумно. Тогда стоит подготовить/обсудить формулировки?

Comment: Не формулировки, только заголовки. Вы уже выше предложили их.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хорошо. Плюс имхо также надо оценивать соотношение переоткрытых и закрытых вопросов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да, кстати, а что насчет третьей причины из этого топика? Я про нее как-то забыл. Стоит ли ее также попробовать заменить на, например, "ответы основаны на мнениях"?

Comment: @andreycha Сложный вопрос – я считаю текущий вариант оптимальным. Если предыдущие две формулировки, возможно, как–то могут положительно повлиять на _закрывающих_, то эффект предложенной третей совсем не ясен. Возможно, стоит начать с двух. Что скажите?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хорошо.

Comment: Я лично не считаю предлагаемое изменение хорошим (на мой взгляд "непонятна суть вопроса" может быть лишь кому-то, кто может быть недостаточно квалифицирован для ответа). Но это чуть более доходчивое объяснение описанной проблемы 1, чем то, что получилось у меня.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну как там статистика, не смотрели?

Comment: @andreycha Пока еще нет. Постараюсь на новогодних праздниках.

Answer (score 4):

> **не хватает деталей**
>
> В вопросе не хватает информации, чтобы дать какой-либо осмысленный ответ. Дополните его. Уточните, в чём именно проблема, где и какие затруднения или недопонимание у вас возникли. Если возможно, приведите пример или точное сообщение об ошибке.

---

> **слишком обширен**
>
> Вопрос понятен, но полный ответ на него слишком огромен. Добавьте в вопрос детали, касающиеся именно вашего или интересующего вас случая: условия, ограничения, технологии, версии или иные подробности.

---

> **нет объективно верного ответа**
>
> Исправьте вопрос, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно и объективно правильный ответ. Если это невозможно, удалите вопрос. Вокруг таких вопросов возникают бесконечные споры и обсуждения, основанные на мнениях и разных точках зрения.

---

В сущности, это лишь "вариация на тему", но в ней непосредственно *причинам* отведено больше места в текстах пояснений. Причинам, из-за которых вопрос реально [требует правки] или [закрыт]. Они немного лучше объясняют, почему сообщество *не может дать **ответ** на вопрос, который устроит автора*. И лишь потом дают рекомендации по исправлению.

Comment: Из общей формулы немножко выбивается последняя причина, где **сначала** дано руководство по исправлению. Мне просто показалось, что так текст лучше строится. Хотя большого ущерба от перемещения последнего предложения пояснения в начало не будет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [требования к предложению внесения изменений](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1936/6).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky (1) позволяет, они **описывают что не так** и **говорят, что делать**, и при этом покрывают наиболее часто совершаемые ошибки; (2) в отличие от нынешних причин, предлагаемые явно описывают совершённые ошибки; (3) есть, в каждом пояснении лишь одно предложение не является руководством к действию; (4) есть, см. п. 3. И поскольку это мой ответ на мой же вопрос, можно неявно считать, что я ими исправляю ещё и изложенные в вопросе проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

*Взял ответ https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3575/177188 и скорректировал как мне кажется лучше.*

1. **Вопрос непонятен**
   Уточните, в чём именно возникли затруднения или непонимание. Добавьте описание входных условий и ожидаемого результата. Поясните, что вы ожидаете увидеть в хорошем и развёрнутом ответе на свой вопрос. Приведите пример, иллюстрирующий проблему, если это возможно.
2. **Вопрос слишком обширен**
   Вопрос понятен, но его контекст слишком широк. Хороший ответ займёт огромный объём. Попробуйте ограничить ваш вопрос дополнительными деталями: подробностями о задаче, используемыми технологии, техническими ограничениями или чем-то другим.
3. **Объективный ответ невозможен**
   Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ. Если это невозможно, удалите вопрос.

Comment: Может Вопрос слишком *общий*? это я про второй пункт

Comment: @Bald Слово "общий" мне как раз не нравится, оно больше подразумевает "коллективное владение", а не широту затронутой темы. ИМХО.

Comment: Про "вопрос непонятен" высказывался PashaPash в комментариях к вопросу: ситуация, когда человеку из одной сферы программирования непонятен вопрос из другой сферы, вполне нормальна. Но такая формулировка причины даёт кард-бланш на закрывашки и в таких случаях, как бы бредово это ни было.

Comment: @D-side Сферы тут не при чем, уверен вы так же 100 раз видели такие вопросы.

Comment: @Kromster вы не поняли. Почитайте комментарии к вопросу. PashaPash утверждает, что аналогичная причина уже была и ею сильно злоупотребляли. Среди прочего, по описанной причине.

Comment: @D-side нам спорить о том что считают минусаторы ни к чему

Comment: @Kromster к сожалению, минусаторы просто минусуют и ничего не предлагают. Заминусовано даже предложение оставить всё как есть. Дурацкая ситуация сложилась.

Answer (score 1):

#### По предложению

> В чём проблемы? - Это руководство по устранению недостатков!

Дело в том, что это не проблема, а реальное назначение механизма закрытия вопросов.

## Вопросы закрываются не для закрывающих, а для авторов вопросов.

Причины закрытия и комментарии к ним должны максимально точно описать **проблему** и **способы её устранения**.

> Первые две причины сливаются!

Если из формулировки вопроса не ясно, о чем именно идет речь, мы просим «уточнить подробности». Если вопрос описан слишком всеобъемлюще, предлагается «конкретизировать» вопрос, то есть сузить область знаний. Возможно, есть какая–то двузначность в восприятии, но на самом деле, причины совершенно разные: «уточнить подробности» – предоставить больше деталей, «конкретизировать» – выбрать одну конкретную проблему из нескольких описанных.

> Малая "удельная осмысленность".

К сожалению, в критике лишь общие слова, каким образом мерить введенный термин не ясно. На данный момент, пояснения к причинам содержат четкие шаги, необходимые для улучшения вопроса. Сами пояснения в несколько раз короче прямых переводов.

Давайте посмотрим конкретно, попробовав оценить формулировки согласно введеному термину. Например, какие именно слова не имеют смысловой нагрузки в следующем пояснении?

```
Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.
```

Честно, я не вижу ни одного слова (наверное, кроме `и т. д.`), которое не несет смысл. Аналогично можно посмотреть на остальные причины. Как мне кажется, вряд ли в формулировках можно сильно улучшить данный показатель.

> Пояснения строят шаткие предположения о вопросе

[За июль 2016-го было закрыто 280 вопросов](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/528650#graph). Конечно же, все вопросы разные! У каждого свой автор, свои ошибки! Но у нас в распоряжении есть пять причин закрытия вопросов, из которых две жестко заданы. Да, код надо добавить не в каждом вопроса, а лишь *в большинстве*.

### В дополнение

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на приведенную в вопросе публикацию «[Зачем на сайте присутствует функционал закрытия вопросов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1936/6)». Позволю себе продублировать часть сообщения.

> #### Для кого закрываются вопросы?
>
> **Вопросы закрываются для задающих**. Закрывая вопрос мы говорим автору, что в текущем виде он (вопрос) не соответствует требованиям
>   сайта или сообществу. Самое важное, чтобы *автор вопроса предельно
>   ясно понимал*:
>
> - что именно не так с вопросом;
> - какие *конкретные* шаги следует проделать, чтобы исправить вопрос.
>
> **В формулировке *обязательно* должен иметь место призыв к действию**. Мы с вами знаем, что Stack Overflow — лучшее место для получения
>   ответа по программированию, это знают и многие участники, но понимают
>   это уже *после публикации* нескольких вопросов, но правила нарушаются,
>   по большому счету, новыми участниками, которые далеко не всегда
>   слышали про существование Stack Overflow и вполне могут не понимать
>   различия между сайтом вопросов и ответов и форумом. Для них Stack
>   Overflow — это еще один сайт, где можно опубликовать непонятно что,
>   получить в ответ непонятно что, возможно, содержащее решение. Именно
>   на нас, сообществе, лежит груз ответственности за обучения наших
>   коллег правилам ведения профессионального диалога. Один из способов
>   достижения цели как раз и является призыв к действию с «[положительным
>   подкреплением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F))».
>
> Согласитесь, нам не нужна база закрытых вопросов, нам нужна база
>   знаний. Добавляя конкретные шаги по улучшению вопроса и призыв к
>   действию мы увеличиваем вероятность исправления недочетов.
>
> #### Как подобрать правильные причины закрытия вопросов?
>
> Как уже говорилось, закрытие вопросов позволяет нам оградиться от не
>   соответствующего правилам сообщества содержимого и нежелательных
>   участников. Это лишь инструмент, содержащий две панели. На первой
>   панели содержится наименьшее количество наиболее распространенных
>   ошибок, которые регулируются командой развития сообществ, конечно же,
>   в тесном содействии с участниками. На второй, вложенной —
>   дополнительные типичные ошибки, набор которых, по сути, регулируется
>   сообществом.
>
> Таким образом, **набор причин закрытия, — это лишь список наиболее часто
>   допускаемых ошибок при публикации вопросов на *текущий момент***. Список
>   может и должен изменяться в зависимости от *настоящих требований*
>   сообщества.
>
> Подчеркну, набор причин закрытия регулируется нуждами конкретного
>   сообщества в конкретный момент времени, а их формулировка составляется
>   исходя из норм, принятых в конкретной культуре. Прямой перевод
>   формулировок из других сообществ, особенно на других языках в данному
>   случае не применим, в связи с различием в размерах сообществ и
>   культурных норм.
>
> #### Как оформить предложение по изменению причин закрытия вопросов?
>
> Причины можно и нужно менять. Предлагая изменения, пожалуйста,
>   убедитесь, что новая формулировка или старая, после исправления:
>
> 1. **позволяет решать проблемы возложенные на данный инструмент;**
> 2. **содержит четкое описание ошибок, допущенных при написании вопроса;**
> 3. **содержит набор конкретных шагов, выполнив которые, вопрос станет удовлетворять правилам сообщества;**
> 4. **содержит призыв к действию — исправлению вопроса.**
>
> Пожалуйста, учтите, что формулировка будет применяться к семейству
>   вопросов, а читаться в контексте одного, то есть должна быть
>   составлена с одной стороны в общих словах, но с другой содержать
>   конкретные рекомендации.

Для заявки рассмотрения сообществом внесения каких–либо изменений в текущие причины закрытия вопросов или комментарии к ним, необходимо предоставить анализ проблемы конкретной причины, а также показать, что улучшеная формулировка соответствует четырем необходимым критериям.

Comment: (1) Именно! Текущие "причины" описывают **способ устранения**, но **саму причину лишь косвенно**, в этом и беда. (2) "причины совершенно разные" для нас, но это совершенно не очевидно из их формулировок без внимательного изучения. (3) Что касается "удельной осмысленности", то это скорее "возможное направление для улучшения". К примеру, мне видится избыточной фраза "для получения ответа", поскольку за иным сюда обычно не приходят.

Comment: «Для получения ответа» – это мотивация. Сообщество закрывает вопрос, почему мне, автору вопроса, просто не скопировать его 10 раз на 10 разных форумах? Зачем что–либо исправлять? Цель инструмента закрытия – улучшить качество слабых вопросов: причина закрытия, как таковая, не важна, важны лишь способы устранения.

Comment: Именно поэтому все предложенные мной *пояснения* содержат прямые инструкции по улучшению вопроса, без обиняков и очевидных фактов. Но способы устранения могут лишь дополнять и пояснять причину закрытия, но ни в коем случае не заменять её. Иначе это становится похоже на "хочу!" из уст сообщества, не подкрепленное причиной "хотения".

Comment: Представим, что в [вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433975/) присутствует новая причина. Имеем фразу `закрыт по причине того, что вопрос слишком обширен`. Какую информацию эта фраза дает автору вопроса? К каким действиям она побуждает? Текущий вариант – `закрыт по причине того, что необходимо конкретизировать вопрос ` – говорит, что _необходимо конкретизировать_ вопрос, идет призыв к конкретному действию.

Comment: Зайдя с другой стороны, дав только руководство по устранению, но не саму причину, мы оставляем без ответа закономерный вопрос "а *почему* я должен(-на) это сделать?" (не *зачем*).

Comment: Потому что вопрос закрыт, публикация ответов к вопросу в текущем виде невозможна.

Comment: Это перенаправление на "зачем" (чтобы вопрос открыли и снова можно было оставлять ответы), но не объясняет, почему вопрос был закрыт. Казалось бы, "причина закрытия" по определению должна объяснить именно это.

Comment: Не соглашусь, вы описываете вопрос не «почему я должен что–либо делать», а «почему мой вопрос закрыт». Это разные «почему». На последний ответ содержится в формулировке «_закрыт по причине_ того, что необходимо конкретизировать вопрос».

Comment: Нет. Это одно и то же "почему" (во всяком случае, задумывалось таким), но возможно, я привёл не самый удачный первый его пример. "Почему мой вопрос оказался закрыт и от меня требуют каких-то отфонарных действий?" Не хватает обоснования того, "почему сообщество так действует". Когда этого нет, можно сделать вывод о "своенравности этого форума" и "раскопировать на 10 других форумов". Почему нет? "Ну не понравился им вопрос, попробую в другом месте".

Comment: О, придумал. Можно разделить эти вопросы в формулировках "из-за чего" и "для чего". Надеюсь, так понятнее, что я имею в виду.

Comment: добавлю data point: «уточнить подробности» и «конкретизировать» слишком близки по значению для меня (я могу эти причины использовать только потому, что помню что они соответствуют "unclear" (неясен), "too broard" (слишком обширен) с английского StackOverflow). Возможно в каком-нибудь словаре «уточнить подробности» и «конкретизировать» определены именно так как в вашем ответе, но на практике язык это то что используют люди (поэтому если для заметной части людей эти формулировки слишком близки, то не нужно пытаться их объяснять -- их следует заменить на более контрастные формулировки).

Answer (score -1):

> **чёткий вопрос отсутствует**
>
> Объясните, что вы ожидаете увидеть в хорошем и развёрнутом ответе на свой вопрос. Уточните, в чём именно возникли затруднения или непонимание. Приведите пример, иллюстрирующий проблему, если это возможно.

Ключевое слово **отсутствует**, по мотивам ["Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 2"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1931/%D0%92%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-stackoverflow-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-mcve-sscce). Относится к ситуациям, когда (одно из):

- неясна даже область проблемы или технологий (худший случай)
- область ясна, но вопрос не задан или задан очень неявно (плохой случай)
- область ясна, но заданных вопросов слишком много, неясно на что отвечать
- область ясна, вопрос задан, но вопрос предполагает тривиальный ответ (для этого слово "**развёрнутом** [ответе]"), за которым сразу же последует другой вопрос (особенно часто для вопросов вида "существует ли", "возможно ли")

---

> **вопрос слишком обширен**
>
> Вопрос понятен, но его контекст слишком широк. Хороший ответ займёт огромный объём. Попробуйте ограничить ваш вопрос дополнительными деталями: подробностями о задаче, используемыми технологиями, техническими ограничениями или чем-то другим.

*// На мой взгляд, описание этой причины у меня получилось хуже всего.*

Тем, кто разбирается в теме, затрагиваемой вопросом, чтобы отделить этот вопрос от причины выше, достаточно ответить самому себе вот на это:

*"Если бы у меня **теоретически** было [бесконечное количество времени](http://xkcd.ru/505/), которое мне не жалко потратить, отвечая на этот вопрос, знаю ли я, о чём именно буду писать?"*

Если нет, то оставлять голос за закрытие *по этой причине* не стоит.

---

> **объективный ответ невозможен**
>
> Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ. Если это невозможно, удалите вопрос.

Существующее пояснение более-менее доносит суть проблемы, его можно лишь немножко улучшить:

- Заменить длиннющее "краткое описание" на *действительно* краткое
- *"Для получения ответа"* избыточно: ведь за этим вопрос задан изначально.
- Простые предложения проще воспринимаются. Поэтому предложение удалить вопрос отделено от остального и снабжено условием, которое, в отличие от пустого "либо" даёт понять, что проблема должна быть именно в вопросе, чтобы его было необходимо удалить.

Answer (score -4):

## Оставить существующие причины

Поднятые в вопросе проблемы с причинами закрытия не существуют или сильно преувеличены. Существующие неплохо справляются со своей задачей и не требуют замены.