# Временное обновление заголовков причин закрытия вопросов

Tags: поддержка, причины-закрытия

В связи с несколькими запросами на изменения заголовков и формулировок причин закрытия, предлагается провести А/Б тестирование. Мы заменим на некоторое время (от месяца до трех) текущие заголовки причин закрытия и посмотрим, как изменится общая картина с закрытием вопросов и их повторным открытием.

Основной вопрос текущего теста – необходим ли авторам вопросов (а также участникам, голосующим за закрытие вопроса) «штамп» – описание проблемы вопроса или же призыв к действию эффективней.

**Что меняется?**

Мы изменим два заголовка причины закрытия вопросов.

1. «необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса» станет «непонятна суть вопроса».
2. «необходимо конкретизировать вопрос» превратится в «вопрос слишком общий»

**Кода изменения вступят в силу?**

До конца дня (первого сентября).

---

Буду рады выслушать ваши идеи и предложения! Перед публикацией предложений и пожеланий, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на публикацию «[Зачем на сайте присутствует функционал закрытия вопросов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/)», в частности, на последние четыре необходимые пункта для рассмотрения в заявке.

Comment: Ещё бы замерить как изменится время между нажатием ссылки "закрыть" и выбором причины закрытия.

Comment: Результаты могут оказаться несколько искажены (они будут отвечать не совсем на *основной вопрос*) в связи с тем, что фраза *"непонятна суть вопроса"* субъективна и привязана к закрывающему, а потому склоняющая к злоупотреблениям. Тем не менее, посмотреть на полученные изменения будет интересно.

Comment: @alexolut, точно! А то уже надоело каждый раз читать пояснение для выбора между ними.

Comment: @Qwertiy угу, именно об этом я писал в [вопросе](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3419/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0) ранее.

Comment: @alexolut, о, точно! Это его я хотел [тут](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3573/178988) указать.

Comment: @D-side с людьми, которые будут предлагать закрывать непонятный им вопрос (например, phpшник будет закрывать вопросы по С++) нужно бороться другими методами, а именно отслеживанием неверных причин закрытия и закрытием доступа к функциональности таким людям. Прецеденты уже были. Но при проведении эксперимента и подведении итогов администрации ресурса надо будет однозначно держать это в голове.

Comment: @andreycha помню прецедент с отклонением "мелких" правок, с причинами закрытия вопросов не помню. Вы про этот случай? Или более давний?

Comment: @D-side и про этот и про многочисленные несущественные правки. Хотя могу ошибаться, возможно нельзя участнику запретить редактировать и закрывать вопросы.

Comment: Всё-таки нужно ещё последнюю причину подправить, а то `необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ` как-то уж слишком выделяется из текущего набора.