# Необходимо переформулировать причину закрытия так, чтобы не нужно было читать весь этот длинный и нудный текст

Tags: предложение, локализация, причины-закрытия

По результатам вопроса [Причины закрытия сломаны. Давайте их починим!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3573/176217) пару причин привели в порядок. Но пока ещё не всё так гладко. В частности, последняя в списке причин закрытия звучит так:

> необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ

Выглядит это довольно громоздко на фоне остальных:

> [image: причины на вопросе]

Ещё сильнее это бросается в глаза при фильтрации в очереди проверок:

> [image: причины в очереди]

И самое удивительное, что в [оригинале](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264397?key=54d4f45f5ba69184c07336fdec203444) это всего лишь:

> primarily opinion-based

Предлагаю не мудрствовать лукаво и "починить" эту причину. Т.е. в первую очередь сделать её в достаточной степени лаконичной.

Comment: Вне конкурса: "побуждает к холиворам".

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [правилами вынесения обсуждения по замене причин закрытия вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/). Это не обычная строка и общие правила выбора лучшего варианта «перевода» в данном случае не действуют.

Answer (score 1):

> primary opinion-based

О чём тут речь? О том, что любой ответ зависит, в первую очередь, от мнения отвечающего.
Объективный ответ на такие вопросы дать невозможно. Такие вопросы - просто повод похоливарить.

В общем, текущий вариант, вполне верно описывает причину закрытия; его минус лишь в многословности.
Давайте разберёмся, что в этом варианте можно упростить.

Чем он отличается от других причин закрытия, вполне себе лаконичных?
Тем, что содержит не только причину, но и алгоритм действий, который должен быть в подробном описании ниже:

> Необходимо переформулировать вопрос, чтобы

Это лишнее побуждение к действию, которое, к тому же, дублируется в тексте ниже.

---

Итак, мой вариант:

> Невозможно дать объективно верный ответ

Comment: Ага, я как раз спорил с Николасом по этому поводу: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3577/181100

Comment: И вообще, почитайте тот вопрос и ответы, там можно много узнать о текущем положении вещей и мнениях сторон :)

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее очевидный и лаконичный вариант перевода, как мне кажется:

> зависит от мнений

Comment: уже была такая версия вроддь

Comment: @Grundy а воз и ныне там.

Comment: Не, я имел ввиду, что была именно формулировка зависит от мнений - и ее поменяли

Comment: @Grundy была в живую на сайте то есть? Я не застал, видимо.

Comment: Было `"по большей части зависит от мнения"`. В истории transifex посмотрел.

Comment: @vp_arth около 4 месяцев просуществовало ~2 года назад, т.е. ещё в эпоху беты.

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос порождает бессмысленные споры

Comment: [Спо́ры — особый тип клеток с плотной оболочкой.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)