# Фильтры в очереди проверок сдвигают индикатор прогресса

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн, очередь-проверок

Если в очереди проверок голосов на закрытие выбрать фильтры и суммарная длина строк фильтров будет достаточно длинной, то индикатор прогресса смещается вниз:

> [image: индикатор]

<s>Но уже сейчас можно сказать, что проблема в переводе последней причины закрытия:</s>

> необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ

Будь она короче и единообразнее с остальными - всё было бы ОК.
О необходимости изменения перевода я уже задавал вопрос: [Необходимо переформулировать причину закрытия так, чтобы не нужно было читать весь этот длинный и нудный текст](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5025/176217)

Аналогичный вопрос на английском на MSE: [Wrong cutting-off of filter's string in review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299750/339911)