# Однозначный ответ

Tags: поддержка, локализация, справка, закрытие-вопросов, термины

Столкнулся с несколькими голосами на удаление темы из-за глупой формальности в описаниях русского SO, отсутствующей на основном SO.

Повторяется дважды.

Как причина закрытия

> Невозможно дать объективный ответ 2 Вопрос порождает бесконечные
>   прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для
>   получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно
>   было дать **однозначно правильный ответ,** либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

И в [Справка > Как задавать вопросы : На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> Активные участники с высокой репутацией, а модераторы их скорее всего
>   поддержат, могут закрыть или заморозить ваш вопрос, если им покажется,
>   что он уже задавался или **на него сложно дать однозначный**, притом
>   краткий (не больше нескольких абзацев) **ответ** или ответы будут по
>   большей части зависеть от мнения отвечающих.

Требование к ответу быть однозначным абсолютно бредовейшее, поскольку бывают задачи с более чем одним решением и удаление вопросов с такими задачами, как какой-то ереси это чистой воды культизм во славу однозначного мира! С такими культистами я к сожалению и столкнулся.

В основном это касается консультационных вопросах с желанием узнать о перечне вариантов инструментов решения или методов реализации.

В англоязычном [Help Center > Asking : What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) такого требования нет.

> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
>   also OK to ask and answer your own question. **Questions which are too**
>   **broad**, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be closed by
>   the community until they are improved.

Там просто просят, чтобы вопрос не был **слишком широким**. То есть речь о критериях.

---

**П Р Е Д Л А Г А Ю**

В тревоге. Цель: `тревога` должна стать инструментом по факту возникновения **ЛИШЬ ВОЗМОЖНЫХ** проблем (прения и дискуссии), а не на берегу, как сейчас, когда вопрос хоронят заочно. Презумпция невиновности.

> Невозможно дать объективный ответ 2 Вопрос привёл к бесконечным
>   прениям и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для
>   получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос, сузив критерии искомого
>   ответа, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

В справке.

> на него сложно дать однозначный, притом краткий (не больше нескольких
>   абзацев) ответ

Речь о том, что с виду простой вопрос, на самом деле скрывает объёмную тему. И либо трудно говорить о конкретики без понимания темы, либо ответ влечёт пояснения по смежной теме, которые влекут другие пояснения. Данной проблематики не существует, поскольку люди пользуются [ссылками на материалы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/) указывая некий вектор и [примеры кода](https://govnokod.ru/), причём зачастую несколько источников.

> Активные участники с высокой репутацией, а модераторы их скорее всего
>   поддержат, могут закрыть или заморозить ваш вопрос, если им покажется,
>   что он уже задавался или ответы будут по большей части зависеть от
>   мнения отвечающих.

Comment: Ничто не ново под луной. Наверное уже лет 5 (с преобразования Хэшкода в ruSO) эта тема регулярно всплывает, но как говорится, а воз и ныне там...

Comment: Ага, как раз читаю пятилетний пост... ужас.

Answer (score 4):

> однозначно правильный ответ

Это не такой ответ, кроме которого правильных не существует, а такой, правильность которого можно точно(однозначно) проверить.

А вот в справке действительно что-то подозрительное написано.

PS: Эта тема уже обсуждалась.

Comment: Вы просто из головы написали свою трактовку =D С тем-же успехом я могу начать фонетический разбор слова и сразу же наткнусь на численнное `одно`. А свойство возможности проверить истинность носит термин `верифицируемости`. И чем-же закончилась `уже обсуждалось`? Нашим по русски `Ай и так сойдёт`?

Comment: @Yaroslav, изменением на текущую формулировку и закончилось, если я ничего не путаю.

Comment: @Yaroslav, а может и путаю, но в общем вот: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1610/178988

Comment: Я один не понимаю, что вызвало такую бурную реакцию? @Yaroslav , если Вы можете предложить формулировку лучше - сделайте это. Сообщество проголосует и если сочтёт что, у Вас действительно получилось лучше - поставит вашу формулировку. И всего то...

Comment: @МихаилРебров я вот чего не пойму... а почему нельзя просто убрать **однозначный**? Стереть, как отвратительную муху с лобового стекла.

Comment: @Yaroslav, по всей видимости из-за того, что кто-то может считать его правильным, а кто-то нет. Наверное поэтому туда добавили слово "однозначный", намекая на то, что относительно данного ответа не может возникнуть споров относительно его верности.

Comment: Кто-что считает это глупости. Наденем артефакт: инженерские очки - "Ну ты зануда" дающие +10.  В системе есть error. Идя по цепочку связей что сейчас, что 5 лет назад мы получаем ссылку на переменную `однозначный`. Очевидно причиной ошибок в уравнении является именно она. Переменная явно несёт не верные данные. Что мы делаем в таких случаях? Удаляем переменную и тестим чё будет! Авось заработает!

Comment: @Yaroslav, если после надевания инженерных очков "Ну ты зануда", Вы начинаете удалять переменные, чтобы исправить ошибки и надеяться на то что "Авось заработает", то спешу Вас огорчить - Вам продали брак или подделку. Надеюсь Вы сохранили чек - верните их немедленно и заберите свои деньги.

Comment: @Yaroslav,  Если же говорить о формулировках... мы живем в мире в котором существует такая профессия как Адвокат. Адвокаты это такие люди, которые занимаются тем что они трактуют законы и пытаются понять можно ли применить тот или иной закон к определенной ситуации. Законы - это такая штука, которая должна однозначно описывать что человек может делать, а что человек не может...

Comment: И по идее законы нужно писать так чтобы их невозможно было трактовать по разному... но вот как-то у человечества не получилось... хотя законы существуют уже далеко не один век... И ладно бы можно было сказать что у нас в Думе раздолбаи сидят... так нет!.. во всём мире та же фигня..  Всегда найдётся человек, которого не устроит та или иная формулировка и далеко не факт, что сообщество сочтёт формулировку без "однозначно" лучшей...

Comment: @МихаилРебров в вас просто нет веры. В отличии от эти гнусных лоеров мы те, кто практикуем написание на не трактуемых языках, хотя в торопях и проэктируем написанное порой так, что сам ногу сломишь. И если у нас и есть проблемы... то это лень =D

Comment: Кстате на тему законов вы ошибаетесь. В юридически развитвх демократиях трактуют только конституцию и занимается этим конституционный суд. А лоеры ищут лазейки в кодексах, следят за фармальностями, работают с уликами, свидетелями и присяженными. Правила могут быть чёткими. Удаление переменных в системе работает! Вот удали мин. спорта, культуры, ркн, рпн, пенсионный фонд и добруб половину министерств и ведомств с увольнением десятков тысяч раздолбаев из  системы "Россия" и мгожество функций заторможенных надзорами заработают.

Comment: @Yaroslav, насколько я знаю толкованию подвержены и конституция, и нормы, и права, и законы. Во всяком случае я видел такие примеры. В том числе в развитых демократиях.

Comment: Относительно удаления министерств...если удалить все министерства, то к сожалению и деньги выделять некому будет... а самоуправление у нас пока не особо развито. Удаление наобум вызовет только отрицательный эффект, поскольку Вы не можете знать насколько кто эффективен или необходим. А вот обдуманное прореживание имеет смысл. Когда Вы после тщательного анализа удаляете лишнее, предварительно распределив освободившиеся обязанности. И сюда больше подходит рефакторинг и оптимизация.

Comment: @Qwertiy, простите нас ))) не хотел разводить дискуссию под вашим ответом)

Comment: @МихаилРобров могу и знаю! Нет нужды изобретать колесо! Достаточно взглянуть на удачные реализации других систем, благо семплов завались. И мы не увидим там 32 надзорно-контролирующих органов. Аналогов Рос Потреб Надзора в природе нет, как и многих других.) Эти прения и дисскусия точно должны стать причиной закрытия темы, но как мне бы хотелось, что в моей редакции =D

Comment: Удачи Вам, @Yoroslav

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный фрагмент является переводом следующей формулировки с англоязычного Stackoverflow:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Как видно, ничего про "однозначность" здесь нет. Как и про "бесконечные дискуссии". Это не культизм - это обычный локализаторский произвол, попытка заменить дословный перевод на некий "улучшенный", якобы адаптированный под локальные культурные особенности сайта, но по факту менее точный.

Смысл причины закрытия, конечно, не в том, чтобы прекращать бесконечные дискуссии (такие дискуссии часто возникают и под нормальными вопросами, и для борьбы с ними существует блокировка, перенос комментариев в чат и т.п.). Она нужна, чтобы отсечь те вопросы, которые на EN SO называются "primarily opinion-based" - основанные главным образом на мнениях, т.е., проще говоря, слишком субъективные, например, сравнение различных языков программирования, ОС, библиотек без конкретной задачи/критериев. Вместо введения презумпции невиновности тут нужно, на мой взгляд, просто уточнить перевод.