# Почему на ruSO так хотят попыток решения?

Tags: обсуждение

Встретился сегодня вопрос:
[Помогите написать регекс для валидации строки математического выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1316864/3415476)
Автор которого в прямом тексте просит помочь ему с регулярным выражением, т.е. он не привел попыток написания выражения самого, но в целом вопрос оформлен не плохо и имеет место быть решенным.

Но заметил что у вопроса сейчас активно падает рейтинг, т.е. сам факт того что в комментариях автор так и написал, что да, он хочет что бы написали за него играет негативную роль.

Возникает сразу несколько мыслей:

- Почему так хотят попыток решения, ведь если у человека не достаточно опыта в области задаваемого им вопроса, это же не означает что вопрос плохой и не имеет право на решение. Когда приходит человек за помощь на сайт, будучи даже не зарегистрированным пользователем, ему же не всплывает "капча" заполните пример кода.
- Так же в данном случает ответ на поставленный вопрос это не ответ одному человеку, это ответ для всех, кому-то сможет пригодиться в учебных целях, кому-то в работе или индивидуальных проектах
- Из опыта который у меня образовался с момента моей регистрации в сообществе, я понимаю, что ответ на подобный вопрос не принесет ни рейтинга, ни любой другой пользы, так как скорее всего он будет закрыт в ближайшее время.

Возникает вопрос о действительной необходимости прилагать попытки решения в не самых плохих вопросах. В комментариях я оставил ссылку на regex101.com, в котором за несколько минут набросал шаблон плюс/минус подходящий под ответ, но я думаю через несколько дней если к этому вопросу вернуться, то он будет либо удален, либо закрыт и помощи от него никакой не будет.

Интересно услышать мнение о данной ситуации, в чем моя ошибка при размышлении на сложившейся ситуацией.
Спасибо!

Comment: автор там очень интересный. Одной рукой пишет "просто я привык решать лаконично, зачем мне писать 5 строчек вместо одной?", а другой - решать эту задачу вообще не собираюсь, решите за меня.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну тема *"Помогите написать регекс"* как раз и подразумевает *"вот условие, напишите регекс за меня"* - просто в первом случае это звучит как просьба о помощи, а во втором перефразированном случае уже как приказ, но ведь это не его слова. О лаконичности, тут каждому свое, кому-то пробелы, кому-то табуляция))

Comment: Конечно же не подразумевает. Подразумевает. что человек пытается, но что-то не получается. Вот [хороший пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314922/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb). А тут с зачем мне писать 5 строчек вместо одной, когда эту самую одну даже не пытался начать писать. Привык писать лаконично, ну так и пиши.

Comment: Вот опять же, вызывает негативные эмоции про его лаконичность, я просто сталкиваюсь с подобным и в других сферах и привык уже к этому. Но тут ведь вопрос не в отношении к автору, а решению проблемы. Ну вот тоже пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1090216/341547, даже попытка решения есть, но вопрос закрыт на уточнение, хотя не понятно что нужно в нем уточнить, вроде как все ясно

Comment: негативные эмоции вызывает не "про лаконичность", а "я привык делать лаконично, но сам делать лаконично не могу и вообще не буду, поэтому сделайте-ка мне". Если бы привел пример собственного решения, хотя бы в те же пять строк и сказал, что "сделал так, но хотелось бы покороче, есть варианты?", то и не было бы негативного отношения. По вашей ссылке из вопроса вообще непонятно, что нужно. Только из комментариев.

Comment: Там по теме понятно: *JS регулярное выражение добавить пробел только 1 раз *, ну может быть только мне, после работы в техподдержке. Ну а по теме основной, то может быть он и пытался, но выкладывать свои попытки, при том что он привык писать лаконично, снизило бы его самооценку, мол плохой код людям показал =) Да и не столько важно присутствие попыток тут, сколько уже личностное отношение к автору вопроса по всей видтмости. Я сам сначала отнесся негативно к автору, но потом подумал, что придет хороший человек с таким же вопросом и найдет там ответ, пусть даже не мой, но найдет)

Comment: ну вот я читаю "добавить пробел только 1 раз". Потом смотрю код: там всё заменяется на ничто. Т.е. удаляется. Так что в итоге должно получиться? Должно удалиться всё, кроме пробелов, если их больше одного? Или как?

Comment: А это как раз пример кода от неопытного человека, возможно он первый раз открыл для себя шаблоны регулярных выражений и поразмыслив некоторое время, понял, что пора идти за помощью) при этом из той каши, которая образовалась за это время в голове, слепил, то, что получилось, кстати, если в том шаблоне, вынести символ "шляпы" как начало строки, то все сразу выглядит не так плохо)

Comment: _«возможно он первый раз открыл для себя шаблоны регулярных выражений и поразмыслив некоторое время, понял, что пора идти за помощью)»_ - но в русском языке, слово "помощь" означает содействие, подспорье, совместную деятельность ради достижения какой-то цели или ради облегчения неблагоприятного состояния. Вот пришедший за помощью у нас сам ничего не делает ради своей цели, и как / в чем ему помогать - неужели "в лежании на диване", образно выражаясь? А может надо помогать ему ходить по сайтам с протянутой рукой? И еще непонятно, почему первое открытие дает право потребл*дски относиться к ruSO.

Comment: "Пассивная агрессия", ха! Будь мы на английском SO, как минимум под тегами C/C++ (про остальные не уверен), такой вопрос был бы заминусован и закрыт быстрее, чем у автора страница обновляется после его отправки. :Р

Comment: Вы уверены, что понимаете значение термина "пассивная агрессия"? Стоит поменять название вопроса.

Comment: @Kromster, ну могу только догадываться, ведь вы только что использовали именно этот метод, завуалировав что я достаточно глуп, что бы понимать такие термины, в свой судя по всему риторический вопрос, так как после вопроса тут же следует ответ))))

Comment: @unsetName -- с новой формулировкой вопроса ответ очевиден. Они хотят более явно продемонстрировать свою значимость. Что-то вроде -- "вот видите, этот ... пишет вот такую ..., а я показываю как надо и учу его неразумного и т.д. и т.п.". Мне кажется, если бы психиатры разбирались в IT, то этот сайт был бы Меккой для пишущих диссерты

Comment: @avp, наверное это все сообщества такие, в рамках своего хобби я фотографирую на некоммерческой основе и приходится состоять в фото сообществах, там этого всего "добра" не меньше, а возможно и больше. Интересно что в сообществах психологов происходит))

Comment: @avp ruSO требует попыток решений, чтобы не превращаться в свалку вопросов-просьб "сделайте за меня мою домашку/тестовое_задание/работу". Вопрос по ссылке - отличный пример. ТС просит написать целиком за него регулярку (что есть по сути код) под свои конкретные условия. Попробуйте мысленно заменить "регулярку" на "код" - вопрос будет про "напишите за меня код вот по этим условиям". Кроме ТС этот вопрос окажется никому не нужен. В то же время ТС не спрашивает о каком-то отдельном моменте, который бы мог быть полезен (например, как перебрать в цикле N строковых символов, или конверсию в Юникод)

Comment: @Kromster, очевидно, что мы по разному оцениваем цель (полезность) сайта. Для меня он ценен в первую очередь тем, что тут можно (понятно, что для меня лично сейчас это не реально) **быстро получить практическую помощь** (в идеале готовое решение). А для многих это не так. Они почему-то хотят научить чему-то спрашивающего. Да еще хотят, чтобы он был уже подготовлен (сам изучил кучу всего) к их ответам. Реально, это просто смешно (смех сквозь слезы)

Comment: _«Они почему-то хотят научить чему-то спрашивающего.»_ - если заменить "спрашивающего" на "всех кто ищет ответы", то получаем официальную цель stackoverflow: она именно в предоставлении знаний (а не сервис решений по запросу). Понятно что ряду лиц удобнее было бы превратить базу знаний в сервис по выполнению заказов, но часть сообщества этому вполне закономерно сопротивляется. _«Да еще хотят, чтобы он был уже подготовлен (сам изучил кучу всего) к их ответам.»_ - для понимания более сложных вещей требуется понимание более базовых. Это нормально, естественно. Иначе из ответов не извлечь пользу.

Comment: По-хорошему, надо бы открыть отдельный ресурс "stackдомашка" или "хочуoverflow", но это вряд ли случится - во многом потому, что очевидна скорая смерть такого ресурса (мало кто способен долго работать забесплатно: новички уходят работать натренировавшись, альтруисты взрослеют и разочаровываются, скучающие находят другие занятия, и т.д.). На такой спрос не найдется устойчивого предложения.

Comment: @yar85, деление ruSO на домены (база знаний, решение проблемы, новички, продвинутые) мной не раз предлагалось в обсуждениях. Для этого даже не надо плодить отдельные ресурсы и как-то менять код. Достаточно пары меток и доброй воли участников (не лезть в чужой огород)

Comment: @avp, по-моему это отличная идея, такое разделение было очень полезным. И кстати, я тоже подобное предлагал однажды, но инициативу завернули с причиной "метаметки ненужны. почему - потому что ненужны", что я воспринимаю как паталогическое распухание консерватизьма и буквоедство правил, в ущерб естественному ходу эволюции ruSO.

Comment: Я тоже сталкивался с такими ситуациями. Это как спросить дорогу у незнакомца, а тот в ответ "покажите как вы пытались найти дорогу"))))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Почему так хотят попыток решения

Потому что в них польза! Считаю что самостоятельные попытки и активное мышление - это путь роста и развития; а получение готового и пережеванного - это путь лени и деградации. Требование от авторов участия в решении вопроса, это позитивное явление, а не что-то плохое или злонамеренное. Ну что же плохого может быть в мотивации на действия, в подсказках направления, в стимуле развивать "мягкие" навыки?

А для остального сообщества, польза попытки решения и описания проблемы (с моей точки зрения) состоит прежде всего в том, что достаточная детализация помогает участникам быстрее и точнее дать ответ: превратить малое благо в большее. Подтверждение такой точки зрения мы можем увидеть на реальных примерах, где уточнения вопроса приводили к хорошим (или, как минимум, к позитивно оцененным) ответам.

Когда спрашивающий сам не пробовал решать, не изучал материалы по теме, и имеет о ней только очень размытое/туманное представление - разве сможет он задать внятный качественный вопрос? Откуда в таком случае взяться качеству?
<sub>Вот серьезно, посмотри на вопросы класса *"я хочу такое, хочу-хочу, (вам) надо сделать"* и *"вот написал (скопировал) код, он не работает"*, где кроме этих фраз по сути ничего нет - поиском среди таких постов реально найти решение конкретной проблемы? Или научиться чему-то кроме скользких формулировок в попрошайничестве? Такие вопросы действительно заслуживают одобрения, поощрения, преумножения?</sub>

---

> ведь если у человека не достаточно опыта в области задаваемого им вопроса, это же не означает что вопрос плохой и не имеет право на решение.

Да, верно!
Уровень опыта, познаний и/или другие индивидуальные характеристики автору - вообще не должны влиять на оценку его вопросов. А если посмотреть внимательнее, то эти характеристики и по факту не влияют (ну, пока не видел вопросов закрытых безосновательно, чистой ненавистью). Конечно, отдельный участник вполне может поставить минус и голос за закрытие из-за своей личной неприязни, но в большинстве случаев решение выносится **группой** активных участников, которая по-моему просто вероятностно не может на 100% только из "злобных" состоять. Если пятеро отдали голос за закрытие, значит на то есть причины. Ну вот о чем же это все говорит нам, если мыслить логически?

---

> Так же в данном случает ответ на поставленный вопрос это не ответ одному человеку, это ответ для всех, кому-то сможет пригодиться в учебных целях, кому-то в работе или индивидуальных проектах

...и именно поэтому, вопросы должны быть качественными.
Делать вопросы качественными - это забота не только малой части участников, наиболее активных, а **всего** сообщества (да-да, и авторов - тоже!). Это прямое следствие из написанного в справке. Просто же: кто может и заинтересован, тот действует, и определяет результат. А от кого ожидается больше заинтересованности в решении - наверное от того, кто вопрос создал, и обладает наиболее полным "доступом" к его сути...

---

> Из опыта который у меня образовался с момента моей регистрации в сообществе, я понимаю, что ответ на подобный вопрос не принесет ни рейтинга, ни любой другой пользы, так как скорее всего он будет закрыт в ближайшее время.

Но ведь пока вопрос не закрыт, ответить **можно**. Ладно, понимаю что у каждого могут быть свои цели, и решение отвечать может определяться больше такими факторами как вероятность удаления и перспективы получения рейтинга. Но в таком случае, становится не совсем ясна связь между "получением прибыли" от ответов и требованиями попыток решения, в контексте этого вопроса...
И стоит обратить внимание на тот нюанс, что одобрение хороших ответов сообществом, имеет свойство повышать заодно и рейтинг вопроса на который качественные ответы даны (даже когда вопрос явно плох). Из этого следует: если большинство участников будет предпочитать для ответа наиболее "хайповые" и "репные" вопросы, то получается что прочие будут висеть в тишине и автоматически закрываться, независимо от их качества и пользы (такой вариант мне кажется несправедливым).

---

Тут **каждый** участник может внести свой вклад, повлиять на судьбу вопроса своими действиями. И бездействие - на нее тоже влияет. Сообщество это его участники, у их большинства одинаковые права и возможности. Разница только в том, как люди этим распоряжаются.

Comment: Ох уж эти воспитатели-преподаватели хорошего, доброго, вечного...

Comment: @avp, «Так мыслит он — и смерть ему любезна. Не скажет он, что жизнь его нужна, не скажет он, что гибель бесполезна: его судьба давно ему ясна… Его еще покамест не распяли, но час придет — он будет на кресте; его послал бог Гнева и Печали рабам земли напомнить о Христе.»

Comment: Это тоже верно. Что же, сила в разнообразии. Главное, не мешать друг-другу. В нашем случае, не закрывать вопросы (кроме откровенного бреда)

Comment: @avp, почему же не закрывать? Если вопрос бредом не является, но предполагает некачественные ответы - то закрывать его по-моему надо, и очень активно. А вот если речь про закрытие только из-за отсутствие попытки решения, то согласен, из-за этого не надо... среди таких вопросов встречаются вполне конкретные и полезные (тем более что бывают случаи когда попытку решения приложить к вопросу невозможно чисто технически, но ее все равно требуют в комментах. Всегда полезно посмотреть на суть, прежде чем нажимать закрытие).

Comment: _«бывают случаи когда попытку решения приложить к вопросу невозможно чисто технически»_ - и случаи когда вопрос о теории, а не о практике программирования. Тут почему-то плохо воспринимаются непрактические общие вопросы, хотя они более полезны для сообщества (ответы на вопросы о теории применимы к широкому спектру задач, и для получения зерна знания не приходится отфильтровывать из ответов информационную шелуху относящуюся к отдельному частному случаю).

Comment: *`"Если вопрос бредом не является, но предполагает некачественные ответы"`* -- это как? Imho хорошо ответить можно на любой (не бредовый) вопрос. Другое дело, что это м.б. крайне не просто. / С оценкой теор. вопросов полностью согласен

Comment: _«"бредом не является, но предполагает некачественные ответы" -- это как?»_ - вариаций множество, все не перечислить... выделю самые частые: вопросы о ситуациях которые не воспроизводятся (проблемы из-за опечаток, запросы решения с неверным подходом типа "дайте код надевания штанов через голову", соцопросы, и т.д.); вопросы с недостаточной детализацией сути или условий (предполагающие угадывание / написание целой книги); вопросы-невопросы, типа "мой дорогой дневничок, сегодня я написал код, и он мне показал ошибку %скриншот IDE%".

Comment: С опечатками согласен, соцопросы не укладываются в тематику (а жаль), все остальное спорно (например, детализацию можно повысить в диалоге с ТС)

Comment: @avp, действительно спорно. Например, _«детализацию можно повысить в диалоге с ТС»_ - как минимум в половине случаев по частной оценке, ТС на комментарии агрессирует/капризничает/бездействует, и это ставит под вопрос практическую возможность (с теоретической не спорю, хорошо бы это работало почаще... но увы, такие случаи скорее исключение, чем правило). У части ТСов еще странные ожидания что их тут будут активно любить, и это безусловно мешает коммуникации по линии "взрослый-взрослый" - вместо нее требуется коммуникация "родитель-ребенок" на которую я чисто органически неспособен((

Comment: "Если пятеро отдали голос за закрытие, значит на то есть причины" - это всего-лишь означает, что эти 5 участников решили, что вопрос соответствует одной из стандартных причин закрытия.  История с закрытием кучи вопросов из-за неудачно вписанного слова "однозначно"  (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1606/) - отличный тому пример.

Comment: По поводу закрытия некачественных вопросов - механизм закрытия на сайте введен не для борьбы "за качество" и не для отсеивания вопросов, которые вам по какой-то причине не нравятся. Он введен для указания автору вопроса на то, что на вопрос нельзя дать ответ в рамках правил без правки, которую может сделать только автор. Например, без добавления кода, на котором у автора падает ошибка. А пункт про "учебные задания" впилен в этот механизм особо настойчивыми участниками, которые испытывают внутреннюю ненависть к "халавщикам", и решили использовать против них все средства.

Comment: Учел замечение @PashaPash (хз касалось ли оно именно ответа, но улучшение лишним не бывает) - формулировки ответа теперь более открыты и однозначнее указывают на личное восприятие поднятого к обсуждению вопроса.

Answer (score 12):

**UPD:**

Смысл вопроса изменился с момента публикации моего ответа.
Изначально автор спрашивал *"откуда берётся пассивная агрессия?"*, позже вопрос видоизменился до *"Почему на ruSO так хотят попыток решения?"*
И на второй вопрос `@yar85` дал более точный ответ.
Со своей стороны я постараюсь внести небольшие правки в данный ответ, чтобы он больше соответствовал новой постановке вопроса и добавлю некоторые комментарии к общему обсуждению.

---

## Касательно данного вопроса:

Как отреагирует на вопрос сообщество зависит от поведения ТС и от удачи.

Я много раз встречал явно учебные задания, но которые были  отлично оформлены и в которых автор пытался идти навстречу сообществу и которые в итоге получали отличные ответы и плюсики в итоге.

Я также видел адекватные вопросы, которые были неадекватно заминусованы из-за того что кому-то что-то показалось, а все остальные последовали за ним как стадо, не пытаясь разобраться в вопросе.

Зависит от того кто первый наткнется на вопрос и как на него отреагирует. Хотя иногда и это не помогает и сообщество пытается проучить уже автора ответа, чтобы тот не давал больше ответов на такие вопросы.

Поэтому это вопрос удачи.
Чтобы ответить  на вопрос, и не испытывать гнев сообщества, нужно его сначала привести в порядок.

Автор данного вопроса своим поведением сам спровоцировал ответную реакцию. Я не поддерживаю этого. Я противник любого вида агрессии. И тем не менее я прекрасно понимаю тех, кому его поведение не понравилось.

Ну и я не вижу чего-то криминального в данном вопросе. Под ним 4 ответа и это более чем хороший результат...Ну а минусы это всего лишь показатель того, что с вопросом что-то не так.
В следующий раз автор задумается над тем как задавать вопросы и как общаться с сообществом.
Вот и все.

Там  4 плюса и 6 минусов. Значит были и защитники данного вопроса.
Значит не все потеряно..

## Касательно токсичности в общем:

Тема токсичности ruSO сообщества настолько же популярна как и тема её скатывания.

Эти темы регулярно подымаются и обсуждаются на мете и одна является противопоставлением другой. Если Вы полистаете и подробно почитаете мету, то увидите насколько часто тема токсичности подымалась в сообществе в том или ином виде.
Поэтому Ваш вопрос сейчас у большинства даже не вызывает никакого желания его обсуждать.

Все кто мог сказать что-то по этому поводу уже десятки раз высказывались на эту тему.
К сожалению, многие от нее уже устали.

Вы не сможете исправить поведение других людей. Но это не значит что ничего нельзя сделать.

### Делайте то, что в Ваших силах

**Видите плохо оформленный вопрос?**
Помогите с оформлением!

**Видите как кто-то не очень то заслуженно ставит минус вопросу**
Поставьте плюс, поддержите автора, объясните что хотят люди, которые ставят минус и почему они так поступают, объясните новому участнику правила сообщества.

**Видите как кто-то незаслуженно закрывает вопрос**
Голосуйте за переоткрытие
*(как только наберете соответствующую репутацию)*

**Видите случай выходящий за рамки Вашего понимания?**
Пишите на мету и обсуждайте с сообществом!

**Вам кажется что в сообществе не хватает доброжелательности?**
Показывайте всем на своем примере!

**Зайдите в очереди проверок и помогите с модерацией!**
Там сконцентрированы люди, которым бы не помещала помощь.
Как со стороны проверяющих, так и со стороны проверяемых.
Если сможете направить в нужное русло на этой стадии, то никакой пассивной агрессии и не будет!

**Общайтесь с новичками и помогайте им!**
Многие не знают правил сообщества, не понимают как нужно оформлять вопросы и что ждать от сообщества.
Помогите им!

**Общайтесь с противоположной стороной!**
Это не плохие люди и многие из них уже сделали для сообщества на порядки больше вашего и начинали свой путь в сообществе с желанием сделать что-то хорошее для него. Эти люди могли верой и правдой служить сообществу и часто в ответ не видели никакой благодарности и наоборот встречались с наглостью и хамством. Тут были очень квалифицированные специалисты, которые получали по 8К$ и больше и могли тратить сутки на то, чтобы из студента вытащить условия задачи или сообщение об ошибке. Это прикольно в первый раз, и во второй...но когда это постоянно происходит становится не смешно. И люди раздражаются... а потом уходят... И этим людям тоже нужна помощь в том, чтобы обратно поверить в сообщество. Им нужна помощь в том, чтобы найти общий язык с противоположной стороной, которую в свою очередь достала токсичность и которые уже готовы также покинуть сообщество из-за нее. 
Если Вы будете поляризовать сообщество - будет только хуже. 
Кому то нужно наводить мосты между этими полюсами.

### Все в ваших руках!

Дерзайте!

Answer (score 8):

Все достаточно просто. Поток вопросов небольшой, отвечающих мало, и у каждого отвечающего есть возможность просматривать и отвечать на все вопросы, которые прилетают по любимой метке. Сколько у нас активных отвечающих, например, по [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)? Трое? Четверо? На 10 вопросов в день?

Из-за нехватки вопросов отвечающим становится скучно и грустно. Они начинают воспринимать ruSO как работу, а вопросы - как *личные* просьбы о помощи. И очередной вопрос вида "я ленивый, сделайте за меня" при этом бесит до жути. Ведь они специалисты высокого уровня, им хочется отвечать на интересные вопросы, а им студенты задачки копипастят! Да что эти студенты о себе возомнили! Мы же тут базу знаний для специалистов строим, профессионалы для профессионалов, а она [превращается в консультационный пункт новичков!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/616/)

Сначала участники верят в лучшее, и пытаются наставить "халявщиков" на праведный путь. Превращают "малое благо в большее". Убеждают друг друга, что если потратить время пятерых специалистов и проголосовать за закрытие вместо просто "минусануть и пойти дальше" - то мир станет лучше.

Иногда ненависть прорывает, и появляются эпические предложения запретить тут простые вопросы. Ну или разбить SO на несколько разделов, где будет раздел с интересными вопросами, и "все остальное".

Потом побеждает скука, и тогда участники устраивают [междусобойчики в виде code golf](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370/). Которые внезапно можно устраивать не всем и не всегда.

Потом побеждает грусть и безразличие, и участник тихо уходит, освобождая место свежим отвечающим.

Comment: Вот это полезный, и при том _нейтральный_ ответ - без навязчивых попыток очернения другой группы участников, но с твердым определением позиции и фактом в ее основе. Сценарий логичен. Такую аргументацию и хочется видеть (+). Насчет ненависти и грусти конечно сомнительные моменты... всякий перевод рассуждений в область домыслов о психоэмоциональном у посторонних людей предлагаю исключать в пользу рассмотрения **явлений** как они есть: т.к. раздражение не всегда вызвано ненавистью, уход не всегда вызван грустью, и т.д. (мы не знаем что в душе у других творится, и видим только внешние проявления).

Comment: @yar85 стремление организовать, естественно, вызвано не ненавистью и не скукой. а появление отдельной причины закрытия для учебных заданий (при полном игнорировании опыта enSO, попыток и решений) вызвано исключительно ненавистью. Тот факт, что в стандартных причинах закрытия есть та, что полагается на оценку **намерений автора**, а не на качество вопроса - это уже отличный показатель, что некоторые участники хотят не качественных вопросов, а возможности судить/оценивать задающих. Тебе А, можно задавать вопросы, а тебе Б - нельзя, не заслужил, **плохо себя вел перед тем, как кнопку нажать!**.

Comment: @yar85 а вот ваш выпад в сторону avp и оценка моего мнения как "некрасивого поступка" - это, извините, за гранью приличия. Вы опять переходите на личности, да еще и пытаетесь натравить двух участников друг на друга. Пожалуйста, ведите себя в рамках принятого на мете.

Comment: @yar85 да, я считаю что вы соврали и умышленно выдаете желаемое за действительное, ради развязывания флейма и ради натравливание участников друг на друга. И да, я считаю что переход на мете на личности **неприемлем и является грубым нарушением правил**. Поставил тревогу, пусть дальше модераторы разгребают.

Comment: _«да, я считаю что вы соврали и умышленно выдаете желаемое за действительное»_ - принято и понято, спасибо за честность. Соотв., [контраргумент](https://i.imgur.com/WM6MVAb.png) для полноты картины.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что пользователи стаковерфлоу на русском не понимают одной элементарной вещи.

Все любители помочь ближнему своему искренне считают, что общаются в вакууме. В закрытом персональном чате. И их ответ никто, кроме автора вопроса, никогда не увидит.

Мысль о том, что ответ на заданный вопрос может пригодиться кому-то ещё, по какой-то причине *никогда* не приходит им в голову. А уж идея сайта, который может служить не только в качестве персонального чятика с автором вопроса, но и в качестве источника уже готовой информации которую можно найти поиском - и вовсе кажется им абсурдом.

Отсюда и требования "попыток" и негатив.
Просто потому что местным помогайкам никогда не придет в голову простая мысль, "О, а это хороший, годный вопрос! Отличный повод написать полезное решение, которое потом сможет пригодиться многим людям".

Эта зацикленность на авторе вопроса (причем доходящая либо до какого-то даже раболепия, либо как в данном случае - до презрения) с одной стороны, и полное пренебрежение теми, кто будет искать ответ на подобный вопрос в гугле, меня не устаёт поражать до глубины души уже много лет.

В данном случае, ответ на вопрос "регулярка для парсинга математического выражения" явно будет интересен довольно широкому кругу читателей. Для которых, по идее, и делался этот сайт. А уж какие мотивы и личные качества были у автора вопроса - *это через 2 дня уже никого не будет интересовать.*

Comment: Отличный ответ. По делу и без всяких опусов.

Comment: @yar85 не будет, разумеется. Отсюда и тональность. Я ещё 10 лет назад писал ровно о том же на старой еще общей мете ексченджа. Все соглашаются, но  ничего не меняется. Так что разницы нет н и к а к о й, с конструктивом писать, или без. Соответственно, никаких иллюзий я не питаю и ничего подвинуть никуда уже давно не хочу. просто иногда настроение немного побаламутить это тухлое загнивающее болото

Comment: 10+ лет это внушительный срок... может просто пришла пора сделать перерыв чтобы ослабить нервную перегрузку (раздражение может накапливаться и вытесняться). По частному опыту: когда мне стало неприятно и некомфортно находиться на ruSO, взял двухлетний "отпуск", и после него многое изменилось (дискомфорт конечно не пропал, но он стал меньше напрягать. Видимо, есть какой-то внутренний рубеж переключения с протеста на принятие ситуации, после прохождения которого эмоции исчезли полностью). _//Сорри если этот совет будет выглядеть обидно (не имею в виду "кыш, кыш!"), просто делюсь возм. решением._

Comment: @yar85 какой смешной переход на личности. Этим все и кончается, "ты просто нервный", а вокруг все хорошо прекрасная маркиза

Comment: Ну так я же не настаиваю, а лишь предлагаю вариант. И совсем нет причин так остро на него реагировать, переводя на личность - совет отдохнуть можно дать абсолютно _любому_ участнику, это никак не задевает и не принижает ничьей сверхценной личности (отдых периодически требуется всем, отдыхать нормально). Ну а если раздраженность ресурсом уже стала приятна и дорога́ - то ради бога, живите с ней счастливо.

Comment: @yar85 как бывший модератор, и как участник, сформулировавший текущий пункт про закрытие "домашек" в качестве меньшего зла - Ипатьев прав. Уровень вахтерства и желания поучать зашкаливает. Не раздражает, но со стороны попытки превратить каждого пролетающего ленивого студента в прилежного ученика, который будет делать ресерч вместо копипасты задания, смотрятся достаточно смешно :)

Comment: @yar85 ни Ипатьев, ни я не говорим "за всех". текст в ответе не более "за всех" чем текст в вашем ответе или в вопросе. Если Ипатьев "клевещет" - то и вы клевещите. По сути же - Ипатьев выражает мнение, точно так же, как и вы в соседнем ответе - а вы прямо переходите на личности.

Comment: @yar85 я всего лишь поддержал мнение другого участника - а в ответ " заведомо ложно говорящий за всех оппонентов", "право соглашаться с ответом конечно не оспариваю" **но** "у вас ЧСВ", и "вы клевещите". Такой стиль общения на мете неприемлем.

Comment: @yar85 ни я, ни другие участники не обязаны вам что-либо предоставлять, тем более в виде странных требований "мне и модератору". Модерация на SO работает без публичных разборок и махания скриншотами. Если вы считаете сообщение клеветой или еще чем-то недопустимым - ставьте на нем флаг, модераторы разберутся.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128592/discussion-between-pashapash-and-yar85).