# Каковы причины блокировки вопроса?

Tags: поддержка, причины-закрытия

Аргументируйте, пожалуйста, причину блокировки вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468498/

Comment: По-хорошему, никто не должен вам что-то аргументировать. Есть правила о том, [какие вопросы лучше не задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Вам неплохо было бы с ними ознакомиться.

Comment: Реальная причина в том, что вопросы на которые проблематично быстро ответить так, чтобы ответ был отмечен "плюсиками" многим тут теперь не нравятся и в свете борьбы за красоту сайта подлежат удалению с формальными обоснованиями.

Comment: @avp, вы правы, корявые, нечеткие вопросы на которые нельзя лаконично ответить без включения телепатии подлежат удалению. Но это не имеет ничего общего с "плюсиками".

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, связано ли с "плюсиками" или нет, это во всех случаях субъективное мнение (у меня сложилось такое).

Answer (score 3):

1. В вопросе нет четко сформулированного вопроса (извините за тавтологию).
2. В вопросе уже присутствует ответ (и даже не один, а несколько).
3. Вопрос не подразумевает четких критериев правильности ответа. Любой ответ может быть одновременно и верным и ошибочным. И именно этот факт и послужил основанием закрытия с причиной "вопрос-опросник".

**UPD:**

Возможно, вместо причины закрытия "вопрос-опросник" стоило использовать какую-то другую (см. ответ **@Nick Volynkin**) причину. В то же время, необходимость закрытия вопроса, на мой взгляд, очевидна (см. аргументы выше).

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, причина закрытия была выбрана неправильно. Вопрос-опросник это что-то вроде "Какая ваша любимая ОС", но причиной злоупотребляют, используя везде где только можно.

Что действительно ухудшает вопрос — то что он очень широк. Я бы нажал вот такую кнопку.

> Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Вы не приводите конкретных критериев выбора. Вопрос спровоцировал бы обмен мнениями, основанными на личном субъективном опыте и догадках относительно ваших задач.

---

И в меньшей степени проявляется эта проблема:

> В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

У вас там на самом деле три вопроса:

1. Как продолжать работу веб-приложения после закрытия сессии?
2. Как снимать с выполнения длительно выполняющийся поток по желанию пользователя?
3. Как ограничить количество длительно выполняемых потоков до 5?

Каждый из них заслуживает как минимум отдельного вопроса.

---

Подробнее об этом:

- [Причины закрытия — "Вопрос-Опросник" vs "Однозначно верный ответ"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1370/181472)
- [Что такое "вопрос-опросник"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1361/181472)

Comment: Использование причины вопрос-опросник оправдано. Автор предлагает несколько вариантов, спрашивая "какой лучше? может есть еще?", не указывая критериев выбора правильного ответа. Лично я не вижу отличий от вопроса "Какая ОС лучше?"

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: не согласен, дополнил ответ, прочитайте пожалуйста.

Comment: Если бы вопрос сводился к "_Есть несколько вариантов, какой выбрать?_" тогда речь действительно шла бы о не конкретном вопросе. А по-факту, есть вопрос вида "_Подскажите какой-нибудь способ, есть вот такие._". Именно первая часть вопроса и делает из него опросник. Переведу вопрос ТС в пример с ОС: "_Какую ОС выбрать. Нужна многозадачность и графический интерфейс. Думаю использовать Linux потому, что люблю пингвинов._"

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: думаю, что и ваш пример стоит закрывать как "Однозначно верхний ответ", последний пункт на первой странице.

Comment: В вопросе кроме, нечетких критериев правильности/ошибочности ответа, присутствует "призыв" приводить свои субъективно хорошие способы решения в дополнение к уже указанным в вопросе. Если бы вопрос не содержал вариантов решения, либо сводился только к "_какой вариант лучше_", тогда я бы полностью согласился с формулировкой "Однозначно верный ответ". А так -- это опросник.