# Давайте не будем сразу торопиться закрывать вопросы, которые могут иметь не одно решение?

Tags: предложение

> **Хотите задать вопрос сообществу Stack Overflow на русском?**
>
> Мы предпочитаем вопросы, на которые можно дать конкретные ответы, а не
>   те, которые порождают дискуссию.

Вопрос о том, что Земля плоская или шарообразная порождает дискуссии, но этот вопрос имеет ЧЕТКИЙ, ВАЖНЫЙ и ОЧЕНЬ ПОЛЕЗНЫЙ ответ! И так со многими вопросами, в том числе в программировании.

Я считаю, не нужно сразу торопиться закрывать вопросы, которые показались не односложными, не однозначными. Нужно дать время, вопрос вызреет и автор сам конкретизирует и упростит его. В начале надо автору дать совет, пожелание, конкретизировать (упростить) вопрос, а уже потом стремиться забанить, но не сразу. Это отталкивает задавать вопросы! Мешает любознательности, исследованиям, поиску новых решений ( и вопросов :) )

**Действительно, многие полезные, интересные, ценные вопросы имеют несколько решений и об этом свидетельствует практика англоязычного StackOverflow!!!**

Comment: Проблемы нет. Вопрос не будет удален сразу и безвозвратно. Когда его закрывают - всегда остается возможность отредактировать и открыть заново.

Comment: Я соглашусь с ТС: проблема дискуссионных топиков есть. Но, на мой взгляд, в рамках существующего подхода Вопрос-Ответ её не решить

Comment: "и об этом свидетельствует практик" - приведите несколько пруфов, для полноты заявления, плиз.

Comment: "но этот вопрос имеет четкий ответ!" - неверно. Этот вопрос имеет 2 четких ответа (в вашем примере)

Comment: На Stack Overflow вопросы, "которые порождают дискуссию" это "too subjective" (иначе практически все вопросы можно обсуждать) https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: соответствующая причина закрытия называется: *"primarily opinion-based"* [Что такое "вопрос-опросник"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1361/23044)

Comment: только из-за того, что ответ имеет несколько решений вопрос не закрывают, на многие вопросы можно дать несколько ответов, важно, чтобы они однозначно являлись решением вопроса. а для расширенной дискуссии есть чат.

Answer (score 7):

Вы просто не <s>умеете их готовить</s> понимаете назначение механизма закрытия.

---

> Я считаю, не нужно сразу торопиться закрывать вопросы, которые показались не односложными, не однозначными.

Допустим. Я не согласен, но допустим.

> Нужно дать время, вопрос вызреет и автор сам конкретизирует и упростит его.

Се-е-екундочку!

Всё верно ведь, закрытие именно для этого и нужно! Чтобы указать автору на то, что вопрос требует доработки, и пока эта доработка не произойдёт, запретить публикацию новых ответов на вопрос, поскольку хороших ответов он просто не привлечёт — значит, нет резона их разрешать вовсе. Обратите внимание, первые несколько дней плашка на вопросе гласит вовсе не *"закрыт"*, а *"требует правки"*.

А чтобы способствовать переоткрытию вопроса после принятия мер, после правки вопрос сам попадает в очередь на переоткрытие. В автоматическом режиме сложно сделать что-то более существенное и не сделать систему уязвимее к злоупотреблениям.

Интерфейс в основном не врёт и пытается помочь. Если ему это где-то не удаётся или удаётся хуже чем могло бы, начните обсуждение на Мете о *конкретных местах*.

> В начале надо автору дать совет, пожелание, конкретизировать (упростить) вопрос, а уже потом стремиться забанить, но не сразу.

Всё верно. Закрытие как раз и демонстрирует рекомендацию о том, как починить вопрос. Если вы считаете, что эти рекомендации бесполезны или сбивают с толку, то это **их** надо чинить. См. выше о Мете.

И закрытия ни в коем случае не приводят к банам. Во всяком случае, не напрямую.

---

Итого, из ваших же слов следует, что закрытие для подобных вопросов — очень подходящий инструмент.

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос о том, что Земля плоская или шарообразная порождает дискуссии, но этот вопрос имеет четкий ответ! И так со многими вопросами, в том числе в программировании.

Данный вопрос перестал быть дискуссионным где-то с 19 века точно, если не раньше. Не понимаю, к чему это здесь.

> Я считаю, не нужно сразу торопиться закрывать вопросы, которые показались не односложными, не однозначными.

Вопросы, несомненно, не стоит закрывать лишь потому, что они сложные или имеют несколько решений (так можно 99% вопросов снести).

Причина закрытия "основан на мнениях", на самом деле, для других вопросов - для тех, которые вообще спрашивают **не о решении конкретной проблемы**, а о субъективном мнении на предмет "что лучше", без определенных критериев. Их нужно закрывать, так как они приводят к бесполезным ответам, с которыми непонятно что делать в очереди проверок.

Грубо говоря, если кто-то задаст вопрос "*Какую технологию лучше всего использовать для разработки школьного сайта?*", на него будут давать бессмысленные ответы типа "*Используй PHP*", которые нужно по идее удалять, но рука не поднимается нажать кнопку (потому что автор это и просил).

---

Что касается вашего вопроса [Как в Андроид Студио под Windows подключить Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765331/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4-%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-windows-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-git), то его закрыли, видимо, просто по ошибке. Причина закрытия "основан на мнениях" к нему никак не подходит. Это нормальный практический вопрос, в первоначальной формулировке был плохо оформлен, но потом вроде нормально поправили. Нажал на переоткрытие.